# Pointers, pointers, pointers!

Tags: code-golf

### Introduction

In the error outputs of some languages such as Java, a **pointer** is shown to give the programmer an idea of exactly where the error went wrong.

Take [this example](http://ideone.com/jd94Vy) on Ideone:

```
Main.java:12: error: ';' expected
    Invalid Java!
                ^
```

Notice the caret shows where the invalid code is?

### Challenge

Your challenge is: given number **N** and string **S**, place a pointer on the **N**th character in **S**.

### Examples

**Input**: `2, "Lorem ipsum, dollar sit amet."`

**Output**:

```
Lorem ipsum, dollar sit amet.
 ^
```

### Rules

- Input is received via STDIN or function parameters
- Output is printed out to the console or `return`ed
- Trailing new lines, spaces etc are allowed in the output
- The pointer character **must** be a **^** caret and **must be on a new line.**
- This is code golf, so the shortest answer wins. Good luck!

Comment: I feel like this is an extremely simple problem, so I am not certain it will be received overly well. You might want to try [the sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/31625) once you have enough rep.

Comment: I think this could have been made a *bit* more interesting if the input had multiple lines, so that you had to insert a newline, spaces, and carat at the correct position(s). Honestly, the spec doesn't really say it *will* be a single line, but I think enforcing that now will invalidate a few answers unfairly, since there's no example that shows this.

Comment: @Geobits Can I add that now? People may need to change their answers.

Comment: Like I said, the cat's probably out of the bag on this one. Rule changes after valid answers are posted usually don't work out well. Live and learn ;)

Comment: Oh well. Thanks anyway! I'll make sure to use complete & solid rules before I post.

Comment: The Sandbox link in the other comment is a great idea, too.

Comment: @Geobits Yeah, I will use the Sandbox now I have enough reputation.

Comment: @SohamChowdhury I'll just pretend that was intentional ;) Do you want me to fix it?

Comment: While this may be very simple, you've certainly done well for a first challenge! You have +16/-0 votes, 1,300 views, and 28 answers (as of this writing) and you've made the Hot Network Questions list. Nice job!

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman and again the value of a question can be measured by the quality of the answers. Very good ones in this challenge.

Comment: So are the quotes and comma necessary?

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos The quotes around the string output aren't required.

Comment: @fridgefish I meant the *input*.

Comment: @AlexA. I agree. I'm surprised how well the question went. Thank you!

Comment: +1 for the carrot (even though it's been edited out now)

Comment: Can I get `S` as command-line argument and `N` in unary, using any digit I want?

Answer (score 39):

## C 33

If just a function is allowed, then even c can compete.

*(For the record, 2 bytes saved thx to @Cool Guy. Mt thx comment is unexpectedly evaporated.)*

*1 more char saved thx @Mig*

```
f(a,c){printf("%s\n%*c",a,c,94);}
```

Comment: C can always compete, it just can't always win. ;)

Comment: @AlexA. <shrug> looks like its winning to me ;-)

Comment: Save 1 char : `f(a,c){printf("%s\n%*c",a,c,94);}`

Comment: If I were a cynical person, I'd say that it's still about 4 times as long as the shortest answer in a golfing language. Which is about business as usual. ;) This is clever, though. I think I had seen the `*` option in the format string before, but had completely forgotten about it. Might come in handy for some of the ascii art challenges in the future.

Answer (score 38):

## Brainf*ck - 133 bytes

```
+++++>>+>>+++>>+++++++++<<<<<<[[->++++++++++<]>>]<++++<<++<<<<--<,>[->+<<->]>>>,<<[->>-<<]<<[->>>>++++++++++<<<<]>>+[,.]>.>[->.<]>>>.
```

Expects input as `[0-9]{2}.*` e.g. "02Hello world!!!" would produce

```
Hello world!!!
 ^
```

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf! This is a great first post, nice job! :D

Comment: The problem is, no-one knows if this is even valid code, let alone solves the problem :)

Comment: Yeah I think there is an off-by-one error here. The caret should be under the `e` in the example. At the cost of 1 byte this can be fixed by adding a `-` in front of `[->.<]`

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman you're right -- see the edit. I originally had it under the e as it is now, but I got confused by using two IDEs with different fonts.

Answer (score 25):

## IA-32 machine code, 24 bytes

Hexdump:

```
66 b8 5e 00 42 38 22 75 fb 66 c7 02 0d 0a 42 42
c6 02 20 e2 fa 89 02 c3
```

It's a function (using MS `fastcall` convention) which updates the string in-place:

```
__declspec(naked) void __fastcall carrot(int n, char* s)
```

Assembly code:

```
    mov ax, '^'; // ah = 0, al = '^'

mystrlen:
    inc edx;
    cmp [edx], ah;
    jne mystrlen;

    mov word ptr [edx], '\r\n'; // append a newline
    inc edx;

mymemset:
    inc edx;
    mov byte ptr [edx], ' ';
    loop mymemset;

    mov [edx], eax; // append a caret and terminate the string
    ret;
```

It uses `WORD`-sized (16-bit) data in a few places. This has a penalty (1-byte prefix) in 32-bit code, but makes the code smaller anyway - using 32-bit data would put two zero bytes into code!

At the end, it writes 4 bytes (`eax`) instead of 2 bytes (`ax`) - the code is smaller that way, and 2 extra bytes of junk go after string termination, so no one notices them.

Usage:

```
int main()
{
    char s[100] = "Lorem ipsum, euro sit amet.";
    carrot(2, s); // credit to Digital Trauma for the name
    puts(s);
}
```

Comment: The instruction `66 b8 5e 00` moves `0x5e` to `al`, not to `ah`, and zero to `ah` instead of `al`, so your comment in assembly code is misleading.

Comment: @Ruslan Thanks! Fixed. That was a remnant from a previous version.

Comment: Why is `naked` in there? And why is it the first thing I saw?

Comment: It's Microsoft that decided to put the `naked` in front: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5w10wxs.aspx

Answer (score 21):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth/commit/3313650c8fb6e8ba77f6479e269c5fd68526903a), 8

```
zp\^*tQd
```

This solution no longer works, since the commit after the one I've linked to as the language name changed `p` to have arity 1. There are several other ways of achieving a similar score in Pyth that still work today, like `zp+*dQ\^`.

If the string needs quotes, adding `v` to the beginning of the code works. If it has to be comma separated, it goes up to 10 bytes:

```
eQp\^*dthQ
```

Comment: I think this is the shortest one so far. Well done.

Comment: The algorithm seems wrong to me, I think `^` will always be under the first character. And by the way the input parameters are given in the wrong order to the online interpreter (so it fails executing).

Comment: @Jim This answer used an older version of pyth, where `p` had arity 1. This caused the first line of the output to be printed first and then the caret on the next line followed by the spaces. Now you could do `z+*dQ\^` for a shorter score but with a trailing newline, or add a `p` before the `+` to remove it. I'm unsure what to do here, since people upvoted this version of the answer, I think I will try to find the version it worked on.

Answer (score 17):

## T-SQL, 90

While a fairly simple question, it's always interesting to try these in languages that really don't tend to support them well or golf well for that matter.

This answer is almost guaranteed to be the longest one.

This creates an inline table function for SQL Server that takes @n and @ as parameters and returns the results as a column.  The carriage return is significant, otherwise I would need to use char(13).

```
CREATE FUNCTION G(@N INT,@ VARCHAR(MAX))RETURNS TABLE RETURN SELECT @+'
'+SPACE(@n-1)+'^'R
```

It's used in the following manner

```
SELECT R 
FROM (VALUES
    (1,'This is test 1'),
    (2,'This is test 2'),
    (3,'This is test 3'),
    (4,'This is test 4'),
    (5,'This is test 5')
    )T(n,S)
    CROSS APPLY G(n,S)
```

And returns

```
R
---------------
This is test 1
^
This is test 2
 ^
This is test 3
  ^
This is test 4
   ^
This is test 5
    ^
```

Comment: Very creative use of a language not really designed for golfing ;) +1

Answer (score 17):

### Python, 27

```py
lambda n,s:s+'\n%%%dc'%n%94
```

This uses two levels of string formatting.

And here's a **25 byte** solution partly stolen from feersum's answer (with the argument order reversed):

```py
lambda*p:'%s\n%%%dc'%p%94
```

Answer (score 12):

## Bash, 27

```
printf %s\\n%$[$1-1]s^ "$2"
```

#### Output

```
$ ./carrot.sh 2 "Lorem ipsum, dollar sit amet."
Lorem ipsum, dollar sit amet.
 ^$
```

Comment: Carrot? Also, what's the dollar at the end?

Comment: The Dollar seems to be the shell's prompt.

Comment: @Scimonster Carrot was my attempt at a joke - [see my edit to the question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/51471/revisions).  And yes, the `$` at the end is the shell prompt.  The question specifies that trailing newlines are allowed, but doesn't say they're necessary.

Answer (score 12):

## sed, 16

```
2y/1/ /;2s/ $/^/
```

This is something of a testcase of [this meta answer](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5344/11259).  Specifically I am requiring that the number **N** is input in unary. E.g. for the caret in position 2, the input for **N** would be `11`.  Also it is not strictly specified which order **S** and **N** should be, so here **S** goes first, followed by unary **N** on a new line, all through STDIN.

#### Output:

```
$ { echo "Lorem ipsum, dollar sit amet."; echo 11; } | sed '2y/1/ /;2s/ $/^/'
Lorem ipsum, dollar sit amet.
 ^
$
```

Comment: `2y/1/ /;2s/ $/^/`

Comment: @manatwork Good call!

Answer (score 11):

## Python, 29

```python
lambda n,s:s+'\n'+' '*~-n+'^'
```

Concatenates the string, a newline, `n-1` spaces, and a `^`.

Comment: If only `rjust` wasn't so long...

Comment: Ah, the tadpole operator.

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript (ES6): <strike>63</strike> <strike>62</strike> <strike>56</strike> <strike>52</strike> 32 bytes

Thanks to nderscore for greatly reducing the size of the code.

```
p=(a,b)=>b+`\n${' '.repeat(a)}^`
```

### Version that works across more browsers (47 bytes):

```
p=function(a,b){return b+`\n${' '.repeat(a)}^`}
```

Comment: 1. The question uses 1-based indexing, so you need `Array(a-1)`. 2. Anonymous function are allowed by default, so you don't need `point=`. 3. For the ES6 version, you can get rid of the `return` statement and the braces. Just use `(a,b)=>b+"\n"+Array(a-1).join(" ")+" ^"`.

Comment: 33 bytes: (replace `\n` with an actual newline) `p=(a,b)=>b+\`\n${' '.repeat(a-1)}^\``

Comment: @dennis The indexing works perfectly for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tdejc.png

Comment: @Dennis `Array(1).join(' ')` results in an empty string :)

Comment: @nderscore I can't find a way to use an actual newline without it causing a line break in the code snippet, and the indexing follows the given example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tdejc.png

Comment: As long as each line is prepended with 4 spaces, it will maintain the code formatting.

Comment: @nderscore My mistake. I didn't realize there was a space before the caret, so it should have been `Array(a).join(" ")+"^"`. The caret is still off for me. That might be an issue with my interpreter, but is `' '.repeat(1)` really supposed to return an empty string?

Comment: @Dennis No, that trick only works for `Array.join`.

Comment: @darkness3560 The caret is at the third character, just that the quote from implicitly returning the function pushes the first line one character to the right. You need `a-1` for a correct answer. Try logging the result instead of just returning it and you'll see. Also like already mentioned, adding an explicit newline instead of `\n` would shave one byte.

Answer (score 7):

## CJam, 9 bytes

```
q~N@(S*'^
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~N%40(S*'%5E&input=2%20%22Lorem%20ipsum%2C%20dollar%20sit%20amet.%22)

#### How it works

```
q~  e# Read the input from STDIN and interpret it.
    e# This pushes the integer and the string on the stack.
N@  e# Push a linefeed an rotate the integer on top of it.
(S* e# Subtract 1 and push a string consisting of that many spaces.
'^  e# Push a caret.
```

Answer (score 7):

## Python, 29

Here's a more fun way to do it in 29:

```py
lambda*p:'%s\n%*s'%(p+('^',))
```

Example usage:

```py
>>> f=lambda*p:'%s\n%*s'%(p+('^',))
>>> print f('lorem',5)
lorem
    ^
```

Answer (score 6):

## TI-BASIC, 10 (?) bytes

```
Disp Ans
Output(3,N,"^
```

Input is given in the variable N, as the question asks, but you can't use the letter var S as a string. In place of that, it takes string input from Ans, so to run the example in the OP: `2->N:"Lorem ipsum, dollar sit amet.":prgm<program name>`.

I'm aware that that probably doesn't count, though, as each colon-delimited segment is technically a separate statement; here's a **46-byte** program that takes input as `N "S"` (`2 "Lorem ipsum, dollar sit amet."`)

```
Input Str1
2+inString(Str1," 
//^there's a space after the quote
Disp sub(Str1,Ans,length(Str1)-Ans
Output(4,expr(sub(Str1,1,1)),"^
```

Both of these assume that the screen has been cleared before running.

Comment: You'd be better off taking input from Input for the number and Ans for the string.

Comment: The first one also doesn't work if the program name, assignment, and string combined are longer than 16 chars.

Comment: @ThomasKwa 26, actually, since I have a color calculator :P It technically does work, if you count overwriting part of the input as 'working'.

Comment: The first one does work if you add a ClrHome:Input N, because the current vote on meta for mixing I/O methods is at +7.

Answer (score 5):

## dc, 19

```
?pr256r^255/32*62+P
```

Input is from STDIN.  `dc` strings are macro definitions and contained in `[` `]`.  The string of spaces is generated by calculating the number that when expressed as a base 256 byte stream gives the string we need.  The calculation is `((n ^ 256) / 255) * 32)`.  This gives `n` spaces (ASCII character 32), but we need `n-1` followed by `^`, so we simply add 62 to the last base 256 digit.

#### Output

```
$ dc -e '?pr256r^255/32*62+P' <<< "2 [Lorem ipsum, dollar sit amet.]"
Lorem ipsum, dollar sit amet.
 ^$
```

Answer (score 4):

## C, <s>59</s> <s>57</s> 47 bytes

```
f(a,c){for(puts(a);--c;putchar(32));puts("^");}
```

Pretty straightforward. Ungolfed version:

```
f(char* a,int c){
    puts(a);        //Print the string first

    for(;--c;)      //Until number-1 is not 0
        putchar(32);//Print a space
    puts("^");      //Print a caret
}
```

Test it [here](http://rextester.com/ZHOEK53545)
Thanks to [@anatolyg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/25315/anatolyg) for saving 10 bytes!

Comment: It's more beautiful to move `puts(a)` and `putchar(32)` into the parentheses of the `for` loop - there are exactly 2 empty places there! Also, I don't think you need to declare the type of `a` and `c` - just use the implicit `int` for them - will work if you don't do `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: @anatolyg , Thanks! I did not think that omitting the types would work, but to my surprise, it did.

Answer (score 4):

## C# 55

A function, concept similar to my C answer, but this time return is shorter than output.

```
string f(string a,int b){return a+'\n'+"^".PadLeft(b);}
```

Answer (score 4):

## K, 21 bytes

```
{y,"\n",1_|"^",x#" "}
```

### Example:

```
ryan@DevPC-LX:~/golf/caret$ rlwrap k
K Console - Enter \ for help

  `0:{y,"\n",1_|"^",x#" "}[2;"Lorem ipsum, dollar sit amet."]
Lorem ipsum, dollar sit amet.
 ^
```

### Explanation (`x` is the number, `y` is the string):

```
{                   }   enclosing function
               x#" "    repeat the space `x` times
           "^",         prepend the caret
          |             reverse the string to put the caret at the end
        1_              drop the extra space
   "\n",                prepend a newline
 y,                     prepend the text
```

Answer (score 4):

### SAS, 35 bytes

```
%macro a(n,s);put &s/@&n."^";%mend;
```

That is the SAS equivalent of a naked function; to add the data step to call it (equivalent to C main function to call it) would be a bit more (9 more bytes - Ty Alex), but I think that's not necessary for this purpose.  How it would be called:

```
data;
%a(3,"My String");
run;
```

There is a macro-only implementation but it's much longer, even if you allow it to give a warning about invalid parameters on n=1.

If we could use pre-defined parameters, SAS would be quite short comparatively on this one, which is a rarity for a language most definitely not intended to be short.

---

If a dataset is allowed to be the source of input, which is how you would 'do it' in SAS (or by %let statements), but is probably not permitted, this is even shorter (**27 bytes**, which actually could be 25 if you guaranteed the dataset was constructed immediately prior to running this [as you could then just use `set;`]):

(pre-existing dataset)

```
data b;
  n=3;
  s="My String";
run;
```

(actual code)

```
data;set b;put s/@n"^";run;
```

Comment: Good to see SO's resident SAS expert here on PPCG. :)

Comment: I'm fairly sure some of the old timers who know DM scripting could best this score... And my cmdmac skills suck.

Comment: I always forget that DM even exists, and I don't even know what cmdmac is! Btw, when you're counting bytes for the whole data step, you don't need `data a;`, you can just do `data;` which will save 2 bytes. But as you said, it's not necessary for this purpose anyway.

Comment: Yeah, my SAS ingrained reflexes don't let me use that intuitively I guess :). Thanks.

Comment: Speaking of old timers, I think you could save a couple bytes by defying all SAS intuition and using an old-style macro. I can't recall whether they can accept parameters though.

Comment: That's what I mean by CMDMAC.

Comment: I can't figure out a way to golf this using old-style macros, because I can't figure out a way to make old-style macros use parameters.  Maybe they do (I see some few indications they may have, though almost all do not) but I can't get it to work.  Might have been broken in 9.4, who knows.

Comment: Yeah I was looking into that the other day and I also can't seem to find a way to get old-style macros to accept parameters. Oh well, 35 is a great golfing score for SAS.

Answer (score 3):

## Matlab/Octave, 41

```
@(n,s)sprintf('%s\n%s^',s,ones(1,n-1)+31)
```

This is an anonymous function that returns the string. This produces a warning, which can be suppressed by previously calling `warning off`.

Comment: Do you mean the editor warning, or does it actually print a warning for you? Also, I beat you by 16 characters ;-) But mine does print the `ans =` bit, so after fixing that, it's only 10 characters difference.

Comment: @Oebele it prints a warning, but the returned string is unaffected.

Answer (score 3):

## Python3, <s>38</s> 36 bytes

```
def f(s,i):return s+'\n'+' '*~-i+'^'

# OR 

def f(s,i):print(s+'\n'+' '*~-i+'^')
```

Test it [here](http://rextester.com/XVS32879)
Thanks to [@Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis) for saving 2 bytes!

Comment: `(i-1)` -> `~-i`

Comment: I'm weak with bit operations and math.... Thanks anyway! :-D

Answer (score 3):

## R, <s>49</s> <s>48</s> 46

As an unnamed function that outputs to STDOUT.  Thanks to @Flounderer for the improvement.

uses strwrap now to ident the caret to n-1.  cat uses a seperator of \n rather than empty string.

```R
function(n,s)cat(s,strwrap('^',,n-1),sep='\n')
```

Test run

```R
> f=function(n,s)cat(s,strwrap('^',,n-1),sep='\n')
> f(29,'The caret should point here v hopefully')
The caret should point here v hopefully
                            ^
>
```

Comment: function(n,x)cat(x,"\n",rep(" ",n-1),"^",sep="") is 48 characters

Comment: @Flounderer Thanks for that ... my original idea was similar to that, but I didn't do it as nicely

Comment: If I am allowed two initial spaces, this works: `function(n,x)cat(" ",x,"\n",rep("",n),"^")` and saves a few characters

Comment: @Flounderer I suspect not.  strwrap also has some possibilities but it would probably end up longer.

Comment: That's nice! I've never seen the `strwrap` function before. Is there a simple way of saying what it does? I can't figure it out from the documentation.

Comment: @Flounderer First time I used it or noticed it yesterday.  Simply put it is a simplistic paragraph formatter.  Given a long string it will chop it up into strings of no more than w width and indent/exdent as require.  New strings are returned in a vector

Answer (score 3):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), <sup><s>32</s></sup> 31 bytes

```forth
: b type cr 1- spaces 94 emit ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FckxDoAgDAXQq/wwi4mJDuoVvARoURIIpMXB01ed3vBC4XbZM/yoLvBoTyXsjMFCqttJMI@gHBtWnSAGW2HKiFXu3OEoKTmGfO0ytd7A6ws)

Input is given as `<number>  s" <string>" b`.

Note the required space after `s"`.

-1 byte from Bubbler.

Shorter than MAWP lol

Comment: `1 -` has a shortcut `1-`.

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, 27 bytes

```matlab
(n,s)->s*"\n"*" "^(n-1)*"^"
```

This creates an unnamed function that accepts an integer and string as input and returns a string. To call it, give it a name, e.g. `f=(n,s)->...`.

All that's happening here is we're appending a newline, `n-1` spaces, and the caret. String concatenation is performed using `*` and string repetition with `^`.

Ungolfed:

```matlab
function f(n, s)
    s * "\n" * " "^(n-1) * "^"
end
```

Example:

```matlab
julia> println(f(2, "Lorem ipsum, dollar sit amet."))
Lorem ipsum, dollar sit amet.
 ^
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP (CLI) - 42

```
<?=sprintf("%s\n%$argv[1]s",$argv[2],'^');
```

Call it from the command line:

```
php pointer.php 2 "Lorem ipsum, dollar sit amet."
```

Comment: I've only noticed now. But your answer is exactly like my 2nd option. I'm offering it to you: `<?printf("$S\n%{$P}s",'^');`. Replace the `\n` with a **real** newline. The total is 5 bytes. That only works on PBP4.1 and below.

Comment: Wow, so many mistakes in that comment... I meant that it is 26 bytes long and that only works on PHP4.1. And it is yours!

Answer (score 2):

My first shot at codegolf

## Java, <strike>133</strike> 65

```
String g(int i,String s){for(s+="\n";--i>0;)s+=" ";return s+"^";}
```

I'm sure it can be reduced even more.

Old code

```
public void go(int i,String s){System.out.println(s);IntStream.range(1,i).forEach(j->System.out.print(" "));System.out.println("^");}
```

Comment: Can you store `System.out` somwhere?

Comment: No need for `public`. And change `IntStream.range(1,i).forEach(j->System.out.print(" "));` to `for(;--i>0;)System.out.print(" ");`

Comment: @CoolGuy aha! sometimes simple is better

Comment: Can you move the `s+="\n"` inside the `for()` initialization to use the semicolon there?

Comment: @ThomasKwa 1 byte less

Answer (score 2):

## Matlab, 25

This one is extremely cheeky. Apparently displays prints non-printable characters as spaces. The following code defines a function named `ans`, that meets the specs.

```
@(N,S)[S 10 ones(N-1) 94]
```

so calling this function like this:

```
ans(2, 'Lorem ipsum, dollar sit amet.')
```

gives the output:

```
ans =

Lorem ipsum, dollar sit amet.
 ^
```

I always dislike the `ans =` part in Matlab answers. If this is a problem, I need to add 6 bytes... but I have always seen it like this in Matlab answers.
Note that running this code overwrites the variable `ans`, so you need to redefine the function if you want to use it a second time!

Comment: Very nice! I didn't know putting a string in a vector worked like that. My understanding was that since this is a function, the string it returns it the meaningful value, and MATLAB's repl environment just happens to print it out. i.e. if you do `x=ans(2, 'asdf');` you don't get an ans = thing.

Answer (score 2):

## Pascal: 57 characters

```pascal
procedure p(n:Byte;s:string);begin
Write(s,#10,'^':n)end;
```

Just to demonstrate Pascal's cute little output formatting. The rest is depressing.

Answer (score 2):

## Swift, 41

It is disappointing that Swift does not have operator `*` on `Array` or `String`.

```
{$1+reduce(0..<$0,"\n",{$0.0+" "})+"^"}
```

Comment: For Swift 2.0: `{$1+(0..<$0).reduce("\n"){$0.0+" "}+"^"}`

Answer (score 2):

## [MAWP v1.02](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), <strike>37</strike> 53 bytes

```
%|0~[;]25W3M;@~(%)~_1A[1A~25WWM~]~1A[1A84W;]85W7M2W;.
```

Takes input as `[S][a]`, with no spaces between S and n.
Since the online interpreter takes only one line of input, the string and number are printed together.

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/?code=%25%7C0%7E%5B%3B%5D25W3M%3B%40%7E(%25)%7E_1A%5B1A%7E25WWM%7E%5D%7E1A%5B1A84W%3B%5D85W7M2W%3B.&input=Hows%20it%20going13)

Comment: Spaces no longer compute as NaN! :)

Comment: Yay! I fixed the code to take in multi digit numbers

Comment: As for multiline input, i've been thinking about that and how it will work with the current input functions. Ill open an issue for further discussion

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 29 bytes <strike>31</strike>

```python
lambda N,S:S+'\n'+' '*~-N+'^'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/5fYRvzPycxNyklUcFPJ9gqWFs9Jk9dW11BXatO109bPU79f0FRZl6JRoUGiMzMKygt0dDU1IExNP8bcfnkF6XmKmQWFJfm6iik5OfkJBYpFGeWKCTmppboAQA)

A Plain Comprehensible snippet, used function lambda function and concatenation

Comment: `(N-1)` can be `~-N`. You can also use f-strings for [28 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/5fYRvzPycxNyklUcFPJ9gqWDtNKSavWl1BXatO1682Tul/QVFmXolGhQaIzMwrKC3R0NTUgTE0/xtx@eQXpeYqZBYUl@bqKKTk5@QkFikUZ5YoJOamlugBAA)

Comment: @JoKing Thank you for your opinion

Comment: If you are using a `def` function declaration, you have to include it in the byte count (right now this is neither a full program nor a function).

Comment: @JoKing Sorry, my mistake. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 16 bytes

```perl
$_.=$"x<>;s; $;^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lXs9WRanCxs662FpBxTru//@QjMxiBSBKVChJLS7hMvmXX1CSmZ9X/F/X11TPwNDgv24BAA)

---

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 16 bytes

```perl
$\=$"x(<>-1)."^"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lxlZFqULDxk7XUFNPKU7p//@QjMxiBSBKVChJLS7hMv6XX1CSmZ9X/F/X11TPwNDgv24BAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Integral](https://github.com/nph278/integral), <s>7</s> 6 Bytes

```
▼8gv^►
```

[Try it!](https://a-ee.github.io/integral/?code=Hzhndl4Q&input=%27Lorem%20ipsum%2C%20dollar%20sit%20amet.%27%0A5)

*-1 thanks to @petStorm*

Comment: Save a byte ([`▼8gv^►` (6 bytes)](https://a-ee.github.io/integral/?code=Hzhndl4Q&input=%27Lorem%20ipsum%2C%20dollar%20sit%20amet.%27%0A5)) by using the `v` instruction.

Answer (score 2):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 37 bytes (Side Length 4)

```
?},$;}<..0~\>(</,<}.>/>;/@\'$'65;\94\
```

```
    ? } , $
   ; } < . .
  0 ~ \ > ( <
 / , < } . > /
  > ; / @ \ '
   $ ' 6 5 ;
    \ 9 4 \
```

Input is of the form: "[number] [string]"
ex: `3 Hello World!`
would output:

```
Hello World!
  ^
```

In terms of pictures, I've split it up into:
Most of the program, and the End

[image]

Red: `?},$`

```
  `?}` gets the pointer num and moves the MP
  `,` skips the space
  `$` creates a jump to the for loop
```

Red / Orange `,<;`

```
  `,` gets the next byte from stdin
  `<` goes out of loop if byte is <= 0
  `;` prints the byte
```

Green `~0;56'$`

```
  `~0` when Hexagony reads an empty byte, it puts a -1 in memory, 
       I then flip that to 1 and append a 0 to get 10
       This saves 1 char over `*10` which I needed to save
  `;` prints the newline
  `56` appends a 56 to the 10 to get 1056
       taken modulo 256, it comes out to 32 which is ascii
       for space; this also saves 1 char over `*32`
  `'` moves the MP back to the pointer num
  `$` jumps into the space printing loop
```

Green / Blue `(<};'`

```
  `(` decrements by 1 before checking if 0 so that it
      prints pointer val - 1 spaces
  `<` loops if counter > 0
  `};'` moves to the memory value containing the space,
        prints it, then moves back
```

Purple `}'94`

```
  `}'` the `'` was already in the path, so I used } to move it forward
       so it would move back
  `94` puts ascii `^` into memory
```

[image]

Starting from where purple left off, I was lucky that the program basically worked itself out. It ends up not changing the 94 in memory until it prints it, and then eventually makes its way to a blank space that hadn't been used and so I put the stopping point there and it all worked out. Fun challenge!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/9@@VkfFutZGT8@gLsZOw0Zfx6ZWz07fzlrfIUZdRd3M1DrG0iTm/39jhZDU4pLMvHSF4JIiIKUIAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 23 bytes

```apl
⊣,(⎕UCS 10),'^',⍨' '⍴⍨⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RHXYt1NB71TQ11DlYwNNDUUY9T13nUu0JdQf1R7xYg41HXov/FQHXqKZlFJZUKafkVClmluQXFCvllqUUKxTmpqQWVCin56ToK@UBufm5qSUZmHpDnCRTMK1HIzssvV8gA4swShfLUvBJ1LqBdQOOKFdKA1iFxjAxwyZgisQ3@AwA)

Explanation:

```apl
⊣,(⎕UCS 10),'^',⍨' '⍴⍨⊢
⊣,(⎕UCS 10)              ⍝ original line + linefeed
            '^',⍨' '⍴⍨⊢  ⍝ generate the pointer

Explaining the generator by example:
               ('^',⍨' '⍴⍨⊢)
               {'^',⍨' '⍴⍨⍵}
               {(' '⍴⍨⍵),'^'}
               {(⍵⍴' '),'^'}
                (⍵⍴' ')          ⍝ generate ⍵ spaces
                        '^'      ⍝ append the pointer
```

Comment: I think you need to output the original line as well.

Comment: oh true that, let me fix it

Comment: alright, should work now

Comment: `{↑⍺('^',⍨⍵⍴'')}` or `↑⊣,⍥⊂'^',⍨''⍴⍨⊢` with the latter being `↑⊣⍮'^',⍨''⍴⍨⊢` in Extended.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 31

```
sub{"$_[0]
"." "x($_[1]-1)."^"}
```

Comment: You can save 2-3 characters.  Drop the final newline as it's not required, then change the first newline to a literal newline.  (Perl is okay with multi-line strings)

Comment: @Mr.Llama thanks, those are good.

Answer (score 1):

### F#, 31 characters

```
let p n s=s+"\n"+"^".PadLeft(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

## SpecBAS - 34

```
1 INPUT n,s$: PRINT s$'TAB n-1;"^"
```

Apostrophe in `PRINT` forces a new line, then just have to move the cursor to correct position.

Answer (score 1):

## GolfScript 11

```
n@~(' '*'^'
```

Test [here](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyIyIiAiTG9yZW0gaXBzdW0sIGRvbGxhciBzaXQgYW1ldC4iCgpuQH4oJyAnKideJwo%3D&run=true).

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript - 52 bytes

Here's mine, it's pretty simple.

```
function f(n,s){return s+"\n"+Array(n).join(" ")+"^"}
```

Usage:

```
$ console.log(f(7, "Any string at all"))

Any string at all
      ^
```

It points at the seventh character.

Comment: Nice save Scimonster O_O

Comment: You can write it like `alert((P=prompt)()+"\n"+Array(P()+1).join(" ")+"^")`. And you save 2 bytes. Also, you can make it into a stasksnippet to showcase the code running. That expects the string to come first, then the position

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 45

This is a pretty horribly golfed answer, but it's my first attempt at code golf.

```
<>=~/(.*), "(.*)"/;print"$2
"." "x($1-1)."^";
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! If you enjoy Perl, reading [Tips for golfing in Perl?](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5105) is a must. Using the `-p` switch (counted as 1 byte), you can eliminate `<>=~` and replace `print` with `$_=`. If you take a few liberties with the input format on top of that, you can shorten your code to `/\d+ /;$_=$'.$"x($&-1)."^"`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Ruby, <del>17</del> <del>23</del> 22

```
->s,n{s+$/+?\s*~-n+?^}
```

This is as short as I can go from something like this:

```
# Lambdas are like Procs, except with a fixed num of arguments
lambda do |sourceLine, offset|
    # The last expression is returned as the lambda's return value.
    # Multiplying a string by N will repeat it N times.
    sourceLine + "\n" + " " * (offset - 1) + "^"
end
```

Comment: And where are you outputting/returning the source code line to which the caret points?

Comment: The rules say: "Output is printed out to the console or returned". I am returning the output.

Comment: The accent was not on the action but on the subject: your proc neither receives nor returns the source code.

Comment: Oh, sorry! Edited the code.

Comment: You can save 1 char by replacing `?\n` with `$/`.

Answer (score 1):

## C, <del>60</del> 49

```
f(n,s){puts(s);while(n-=1)putch(' ');putch('^');}
```

First post, so I guess it's not that good.

Answer (score 1):

## Scala (<strike>49</strike> 42 bytes)

```
def p(i:Int,s:String)=s+"\n"+" "*(i-1)+"^"
```

---

```
scala> def p(i:Int,s:String)=s+"\n"+" "*(i-1)+"^"
p: (i: Int, s: String)String

scala> p(2, "Lorem ipsum, dollar sit amet.")
res0: String =
Lorem ipsum, dollar sit amet.
 ^
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 20

After seeing @Digital Trauma's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51493/29438), I wanted to port his answer to Perl to show an another example of accepting the input numbers as unary as a default. This is based on the [meta discussion](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5343/29438).

```
$i++&y/1/ /&s/ $/^/
```

`19` characters `+1` for `-p` flag.

Run with:

```
{ echo "Lorem ipsum, dollar sit amet."; echo 111; } | perl -pe'$i++?y/1/ /&&s/ $/^/:1'
```

Comment: The ternary operator seems pointless here as you only have instruction for the “then” branch: `$i++&y/1/ /&s/ $/^/`.

Comment: @manatwork good call! updated answer

Answer (score 1):

## J, 19

Including parentheses!

The verb:

```
(],:'^',~' '#~<:@[)
```

Use:

```
9 (],:'^',~' '#~<:@[) 'Invalid Java!'
Invalid Java!
        ^
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my first code golf, but here I go.

## Haskell, 36

```
f s n=s++'\n':replicate(n-1)' '++"^"
```

The regular version being

```
placeCaret :: String -> Integer -> String
placeCaret s n = s ++ '\n' : replicate (n - 1) ' ' ++ "^"
```

So, not really much change. Clearly, the replicate is wasting the most space here, but as far as I know there are no alternatives in Prelude. I played a bit with other things which could have been cool tricks, but they all ended up being the same length.

Example usage:

```
Prelude> putStrLn $ f ['a'..'z'] 7
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
      ^
```

putStrLn is needed so that the newline will be displayed as a newline instead of "\n" (in GHCi only).

I know I'm VERY late to this party, but whatever.

Answer (score 1):

### [Straw](http://github.com/tuxcrafting/straw), 13 bytes

```
<#<>
> ,}*>^>
```

[Try it online!](http://straw.tryitonline.net/#code=PCM8Pgo-ICx9Kj5ePg&input=MgpIZWxsbw)

`^` is the only non-alphanumeric character (with `\`) to not be assigned to a command, so no need for a string literal to push it.

Answer (score 1):

### Common Lisp, <del>40</del> 35

```
(format t"~A
~VT^"(read)(1-(read)))
```

-5 bytes thanks to *PrzemysławP*.

Comment: `(format t"~A<enter>~VT^"(read)(1-(read)))` saves 5 bytes

Comment: @PrzemysławP Thanks, I edited the answer; I was pretty busy, sorry for the delay

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 30 bytes

```
s!n=s++'\n':([1..n]>>" ")++"^"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
'^I<ú‚»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@68e52lzeNejhlmHdv//b8Tlk1@UmquQWVBcmqujkJKfk5NYpFCcWaKQmJtaogcA)

**Explantion**

```
'^       # push caret
  I<ú    # prepend with input-1 spaces
     ‚   # pair with second input
      »  # join by newline
```

Comment: [6 bytes](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fRz3u8K5Dy@z///fJL0rNVcgsKC7N1VFIyc/JSSxSKM4sUUjMTS3R4zICAA) by taking the inputs in reversed order.

Answer (score 1):

## C++ (with the standard library) - <s>159</s> 121 bytes (-38 by Riley)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;int main(int c,char**v){cout<<string(v[2])<<endl<<string(stoi(v[1])-1,' ')<<"^";}
```

Gets input from the command line args.
Example usage: `./a.out 8 "hello, world"`

This is my first ever code golf, so if you have any tips, that would be great!

Comment: 1. Unless specified, you can assume the input will be correctly formatted. That lets you skip the exit part. 2. You shouldn't need to assign p and s. I think you can just put `stoi(...)` and `string(...)` right in the `cout`. 3. I don't think you need the space in `char** v`. I hope this helps :)

Comment: @Riley Thanks! That helped.

Comment: You shouldn't need the space in `stoi` either.

Answer (score 1):

## Vim 9 bytes

```
jD@"a <esc>r^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@5/l4qCUqGCTWpxsVxT3/79Hak5OvkJ5flFOCpfpf90yAA)

Note that `<esc>` is a single byte, namely `0x1B`, but since that byte is unprintable, I added a flag and used `<esc>` instead. [This version](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@5/l4qCUqCBdFPf/v0dqTk6@Qnl@UU4KlykA) uses the unprintable.

Explanation:

```
j               " Move down one line
 D              " Delete everything on this line, and save it in the unnamed register
  @"            " 'n' times
    a <esc>     " Append a 'space'
           r^   " Replace this last space with caret
```

Answer (score 1):

### Underload, 23 bytes

```
(S(
)S()(( )S^)!!^(^)S)
```

Assumes `S` is a string on the stack. `N` should be given in unary. It should be a sequence of `:` in between the `)` and `!` on the second line. For example:

```
(S(
)S()(( )S^)::::!!^(^)S)
```

The `::::` represents N=4.

Comment: Hmm, is that really the tersest way to subtract 1 in Underload? I recognise the general shape, but it's disappointing if there isn't a shorter way.

Comment: @ais523 Switching to unary input for `n` works, because `:` is easily undone using `!`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-n`, 20 bytes

```perl
say<>;say$"x--$_,'^'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sdLGzhpIqihV6OqqxOuox6n//2/CFZKRWawARIkKJanFJf/yC0oy8/OK/@v6muoZGBr8180DAA)

Unlike a previous answer of the same byte count, this does not require the input to be in unary.

Answer (score 1):

## [Momema](https://github.com/ScratchMan544/momema), 50 bytes

```
1+*-8-1s00*-9-9*0s=+1*0-9 10c01+*1-1-9 32c=*1-9 94
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FckxDoAgDEDR3VN0Lta06mAHb@AlCDKQ2GBAz4@4/Zdv2aL51sQhbSSVGUlJkevuBJkUhAP3KyQdyxx2/EPX1ubhyCUapLu@NsKZr8sXqOkBb/GZPg)

### Explanation

```
1   +*-8-1  #  mem[1] = mem[-8] + (-1)   #  a = getnum() - 1
s   0       #  do {                      #  do {
0   *-9     #    mem[0] = mem[-9]        #    b = getchar()
-9  *0      #    mem[-9] = mem[0]        #    putchar(b)
s   =+1*0   #  } while (mem[0] + 1)      #  } while (b != -1)
-9  10      #  mem[-9] = 10              #  putchar('\n')
c   0       #  do {                      #  do {
1   +*1-1   #    mem[1] = mem[1] + (-1)  #    a = a - 1
-9  32      #    mem[-9] = 32            #    putchar(32)
c   =*1     #  } while (mem[1])          #  } while (b != 0)
-9  94      #  mem[-9] = 94              #  putchar(94)
```

Memory addresses `-8` and `-9` are memory-mapped for numeric and character IO respectively.

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 9 bytes

```
᠀
¿; ℠*\^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N////4YIGrkP7rRUetSzQion7/98nvyg1VyGzoLg0V0chJT8nJ7FIoTizRCExN7VEj8sIAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 32 bytes

```
|n,s|print!("{}
{:>2$}",s,"^",n)
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##nY5BCsIwFET3OcU3iCYQROuuSpddeQYhaIKBJi35vwi2OXtMewJx@WDezMQRKdsAXrsgJEwMgAySyHNQOA/RBdoIPiU21U21TVyh4neugswAkiXGirsI17YRtoZWsvfLRFNq2kJBjOg@RsFuj6TJPQApSrasWFEp4Lc@Gg9uwNErePZdpyOgI9De0IHLSwmuH7qwEStZcf5POx1/8VL@Ag)

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack) -A, 116 bytes

```
([{}]()<{({}<>)<>}(((((()()()()()){}()){}()){}()){})>){((){}<((((()()()()){}){}){})>)}{}((()()()()()){}){<>({}<>)}{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v9fI7q6NlZD06Zao7rWxk7Txq5WAww0YVCzuhaN0LTTrAYqAKpHVgmSgCA7zdrqWjQjNKtt7CA2AOX@//9v8V@pOL@0KDlVITk/JVUhI7UoVem/riMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 9 bytes

```
,:'^'{.~-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WT0HHSj1OvVqvTvd/anJGvoK6R2pOTr5CeH5RToq6QpqC@X8A)

```
        -   negate the number
  '^'{.~    take that many characters from the string "^"
,:          append 2 items
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) `-F`, 20 bytes

```sh
printf %s\\n%*c $@ ^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@cWqKg6/a/oCgzryRNQbU4JiZPVStZQcVBIe7///8ZqTk5@ToK5flFOSn/zQA)

Method stolen from the C answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
ṄṛṬị⁾^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATwAw/9qZWxsef//4bmE4bmb4bms4buL4oG@XiD///8iTG9yZW0gaXBzdW0sIGRvbGxhciBzaXQgYW1ldC4i/zI)

Same length, but different to, Erik's existing answer

### How it works

```
ṄṛṬị⁾^  - Main link. Takes S on the left and N on the right
Ṅ       - Print S with a newline
 ṛ      - Discard it and yield N
  Ṭ     - Yield a list with a 1 at the Nth index and 0s otherwise
   ị⁾^  - Index into "^ "
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `o`, <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
,‹\^꘍
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJvIiwiIiwiLOKAuVxcXuqYjSIsIiIsIkhlbGxvIFdvcmxkISEhXG4zIl0=)

Comment: You can omit the trailing `,` with the `o` flag.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP 4.1, <del>35</del> 31 bytes

This one was really simple, but still fun!

```
<?="$S
",str_pad('^',$P,' ',0);
```

You can pass the values over POST, GET, SESSIONS, ...

The key `S` must contain the string, while the key `P` must contain the character number where you want the `^`.

---

**Old answer (35 bytes):**

```
<?="$S
",str_repeat(' ',--$P),'^';
```

Answer (score 0):

## [rs](https://github.com/kirbyfan64/rs), 35 bytes

```
(\d+), "(.*?)"/\2\n( )^^(\1)^
 \^/^
```

<strike>Unfortunately, the online demo has a bug that I need to fix with newlines, so I can't put a demo link.</strike>

**EDIT:** I fixed the bug in the demo page. So...

[Live demo!](http://kirbyfan64.github.io/rs/index.html?script=(%5Cd%2B)%2C%20%22(.*%3F)%22%2F%5C2%5Cn(%20)%5E%5E(%5C1)%5E%0A%20%5C%5E%2F%5E&input=2%2C%20%22Lorem%20ipsum%2C%20dollar%20sit%20amet.%22)

This is pretty simple:

- Line 1 places the text, a newline, and a series of spaces repeated one more times than we want.
- Line 2 gets rid of the extra space.

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, <s>58</s> 53 bytes

```
a=" "function p(n,s)print(s,"\n"..a:rep(n-1).."^")end
```

Thanks to manatwork this just got shorter by 5 bytes. Looks like I need to refresh my Lua skills.

First version:

```
function p(n,s)print(s.."\n"..string.rep(" ",n-1).."^")end
```

Comment: That static method call is horribly long. `function p(n,s)x=" ";print(s.."\n"..x:rep(n-1).."^")end`

Comment: Actually you can remove one more character. As “Trailing new lines, spaces etc are allowed in the output”, replace the first `..` with `,`. This way a trailing tab will appear in the first line, but is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 50 bytes

Code

`function f(n,s){return s+'\n'+s.substr(0,n-1)+'^'}`

Output

```
console.log(f(2, "hello"));
hello
h^
```

This approach takes advantage of the fact that you do not specify an empty string preceding the caret, only a caret pointing to the index in the input string and anything following that. If you happen to have a caret in your input string and an error there then it might get a little bit confusing :)

For example

```
console.log(f(3, "he^lo"));
he^lo
he^
```

or

```
console.log(f(3, "he^"));
he^
he^
```

Answer (score 0):

## Batch, 56 Bytes

```
@set/p=
@for /l %%a in (2,1,%1)do @cd|set/p=.<BS> 
@echo ^^
```

This code contains two points of interest. First, it takes input from both StdIn and command line arguments. The string is read from StdIn while the index of the caret is taken as a parameter. Second, Batch doesn't play nice when it come to outputting a single space character (`U+0020`) so a bit of a work around is required: `cd|set/p=.<BS>` In this line `<BS>` stands in for the backspace character (`U+0008`) and the last character is a space. This is accounted for in the byte count.

Answer (score 0):

## SAS, 22

```
macro a put &s/@&n'^'%
```

Usage:

```
%let s="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
%let n=2;
data;a;run;
```

Output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
 ^
```

If running in 'batch' mode, the run is not required so the code in needed to produce the function and run it (just not setting the inputs) would be **30 bytes**

```
macro a put &s/@&n'^'% data;a;
```

So, it may be cheating... this style macro(function) definition in SAS does not have parameters, so the inputs are defined separately, in Usage as two %let statements.  Parsing from STDIN would substantially lengthen the solution and only works when running SAS in 'batch' mode, which is not necessarily commonplace.

Answer (score 0):

## [Turtlèd](https://github.com/Destructible-Watermelon/Turtl-d/), 17 bytes

```
r!-[*.-l_]' d?:'^
```

### explanation

```
r!-               move right, take input into string variable, decrement string pointer
   [*    ]        while current char is not *
     .-           write pointed char from string, decrement pointer
       l_         move left, write * if the pointer is on the last char of string
          ' d     write space, move down
             ?:'^ Take input into register, move forward by the amount in register, write ^
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 8 bytes

```
z+*dtQ\^
```

Takes inputs separated by a newline (i.e. `2\nLorem ipsum`).
[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=z%2B%2adtQ%5C%5E&input=2%0ALorem+ipsum%2C+dollar+sit+amet.&debug=0)

Explanation:

```
z           The second input, implicitly printed with trailing newline
  *d__      The space character, __ times
    tQ        where __ is the first input -1
 +    \^    Append a literal carat character and printed
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](//github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
Ṅ⁶ṁ”^⁹¦
```

[Try it online!](//jelly.tryitonline.net#code=4bmE4oG24bmB4oCdXuKBucKm&args=TG9yZW0gaXBzdW0sIGRvbGxhciBzaXQgYW1ldC4+Mg)

That <s>`dollar`</s>`dolor` makes me laugh!!

Thanks to @Dennis for -1.

Answer (score 0):

## Vim, 7 keystrokes (buffer input/output, excluding input keystrokes)

`o<Esc>` + input number + `i <Esc>r^`

### Explanation

- `o<Esc>` creates a new line
- `#i <Esc>` creates `#` spaces
- `r^` replaces the last space by `^`

*Note:* This answers does not write the output to stdout (`:w !tee`, + 6 keystrokes) - so maybe it will be considered invalid.

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 26 bytes

```
INPUT N,S$?S$?" "*(N-1);"^
```

1-indexed arrow adds 4 bytes...

Comment: Note that you only want N-1 spaces before the caret.

Answer (score 0):

## C++14, 45 bytes

As unnamed lambda modifying its input, assuming `s` is similar to `std::string` (has `operator+=`):

```cpp
[](int n,auto&s){for(s+=10;--n;s+=32);s+=94;}
```

Usage:

```cpp
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

auto f =
[](int n,auto&s){for(s+=10;--n;s+=32);s+=94;}
;

int main() {
 std::string s = "abcdefghijk";
 f(2,s);
 std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish/wiki) (Golfish), 14 bytes

```
`^IMR` aTiEHot
```

[Try it here](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/?code=%60%5EIMR%60%20aTiEHot&input=15%0ALorem%20ipsum%2C%20dollar%20sit%20amet.).

**Explanation**

```
`^             # push caret
  I            # read input as number
   M           # subtract 1
    R`         # pop N, and Repeatedly push a space, N times
       a       # push 10 (ASCII newline)
        T      # set teleport pad
         i     # input character
          EH   # if EOF, output stack and halt
            o  # otherwise, output the character just read
             t # teleport back to pad
```

Comment: Why is this non-competing?

Comment: I think it used features which were added to the language after this question was asked.

Comment: In that case the annotation is [no longer necessary](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12877/46076) and I've removed it. The reason I asked is that "non-competing" has been historically misused to mean "this answer doesn't actually meet the challenge requirements and should be deleted".

Answer (score 0):

## tcl, 47

```
gets stdin s
puts $s\n[format %[gets stdin]s ^]
```

[demo](http://rextester.com/MLDA77010)

Answer (score 0):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 6 bytes

```
ïÀá r^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@394/eGGwwsViuL@//dIzcnJVyjPL8pJ@W8KAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 25 bytes

```
VV"^ "R3-M#
&@v[v.Rv]v<&@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/8/LEwpTkEpyFjXV5lLzaEsukwvqCy2zEbN4f///x6pOTn5iv@NAQ)

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby 2.7, 24 bytes

```
x=->{_1+'
'+" "*~-_2+?^}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>29</s> 27 bytes

```powershell
$args[1]
'^'|% *ft $args[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/a@SZlv9XyWxKL042jCWSz1OvUZVQSutRAEiZBD7v5aLS00lTcFEQckHqD5XIbOguDRXRyElPycnsUihOLNEITE3tURP6T8A)

-2 bytes thanks to Mazzy!

Comment: ? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/a@SZlv9XyWxKL042jCWSz1OvUZVQSutRAEiZBD7v5aLS00lTcFEQckHqD5XIbOguDRXRyElPycnsUihOLNEITE3tURP6T8A "PowerShell Core – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

-1 byte if we can take the string input as a singleton array.

```
·p^ùV
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=t3Be%2bVY&input=IkxvcmVtIGlwc3VtLCBkb2xsYXIgc2l0IGFtZXQuIgoy)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
,'^ú¦,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fRz3u8K5Dy3T@//fJL0rNVcgsKC7NVUjJz8kvUijOLFFIzE0t0eMyAgA)

```
,       # output with trailing newline...
        # implicit input
     ,  # output with trailing newline...
 '^     # "^"...
   ú    # with...
        # implicit input...
    ¦   # minus 1...
   ú    # spaces in front
```

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 38 bytes

```haskell
n!s=s++'\n':g n
g 1="^"
g n=' ':g(n-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchBCoAgEADAe6/YJLCwAjsG/sBb1wiEpCTdxLX3m6eBuQ091vtSsCVFQvAd@XoBNhdIxQ5WRcWhXo@THEowDlX88paTxm5pmX6TDeAifWGE8/XeJCCXwQSbZ1Z@)

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 35 bytes

```
func[n s][prin[s lf pad/left"^^"n]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFNCoAgEAbQfaf4cB0FLTtDq7aDguQMCP7h6Pntvc5hvRzIbnJjySwfFail1mMhRRI0H87EMoxzpli7BBfMUztnxKYz7wg1Jd@hccBnHodZPw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 bytes

```
P'^)p
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=P%27%5E%29p&i=2,%22Lorem+ipsum,+dollar+sit+amet.%22)

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 14 bytes

```apl
{↑⍺((-⍵)↑'^')}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbhOpHbRMf9e7S0NB91LtVE8hRj1PXrP1fDJRST8ksKqlUSMuvUMgqzS0oVsgvSy1SKM5JTS2oVEjJT9dRyAdy83NTSzIy84A8T6BgXolCdl5@uUIGEGeWKJSn5pWocz3qmwo0rlghTcHQAIljhMwxRWIb/AcA)

A port of @FrownyFrog [J answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214932/75681)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `N`, 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
⁻ṣ'^+,
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0kp9S7IKlpSVpuharHjXufrhzsXqcts6S4qTkYqjwgv2mXD75Ram5CpkFxaW5Ogop-Tk5iUUKxZklCom5qSV6EGUA)

##### Explanation

```
⁻ṣ'^+,  # Implicit input
⁻ṣ      # First input decremented spaces
  '^+   # With a "^" appended
     ,  # Paired with the second input
        # Implicit output joined by newlines
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 32 bytes

Speaking of which, the Java answer of this problem needed a little upgrade :)

```java
a->b->b+"\n"+" ".repeat(a-1)+"^"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVLLToNAFN33K66zKQSYBDYmNNW0O42uXFqb3MKUUIeHM0OjMV268xP05/ojeEuBpj7qDYS5wzl3zjmZFa7RW8WPdVktZBpBJFFruMU0h9fBACDNjVBLjARMaAOoprC0aBfQHlG/OQZNW9CdUWmeQGK1i8UBrA0aOmgCEsY1ehcLehw2y5nDgHElSoHGQs@3HTZn9WhHabW1zHWRxiDWKBsZJSrMfLc7sWmDvhXPpYiMiO1jXUroShoYg@RLaz/B5sl@FTRSCfqijch4URleEsnI3LK6cVw8VSi1tZ9jX7Ltxxs5CNn2852@ttP@6E3/4iCjjNt47h8AVaI7kY03gMBlN4USGaSlrjIX4kJKVKBTyj4ThjOCuvSeRs1ymBPyb1PM@7fYCfbuqvAV3aLQD0IQShUqhOFo2EffkVtX/rm7Ew5XOfUUwzVRz5qdQzWufoDIybfqjVHGm/oL)

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 79 bytes

```go
import."strings"
func f(s string,n int)string{return s+`
`+Repeat(" ",n-1)+"^"}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY5LCsIwFEXnWcXjjRL6AR25AIeC4gKkoSYl2HxIXkbFlTgpgotwKe7Gajq63Ds45z6eg5_fQfY3OSiw0jhmbPCRALUlfGXSze5zLFuLiaJxQ0Kms-tB8wRlqR0YR6KUKSrK0UGqOtZVZxWUJI6AtWs2osIL3lfs_k_5SbmAiQEsyva0IGh0XHM8-KgsmJCyreHqx1FGSIZAWrV8qWErBFtZ81zyCw)