# Yarr! A map to the hidden treasure!

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

#### Introduction

"Yarr!! We had a laddie who called himself a "programmer" make a map t' our hidden treasure! But 'tis written wit' weird numbers 'n letters! "E5, N2, E3"... what does it even mean? Madness! Can't even scribe a proper treasure map, t' useless cretin. Fix it fer us! We'll gift ye a share o' t' treasure!"

#### Challenge Description

A group of pirates are having trouble reading a treasure map. Can you write a program to convert it into a more... piratey form?

As input, you'll receive the original treasure map. It's a list of comma separated strings, each string which consists of a *letter portion* (which tells the pirates which direction they need to walk in), and a *number portion* (which tells the pirates how many steps to take in that direction). For instance, the following treasure map:

```
E2,N4,E5,S2,W1,S3
```

would mean, "walk two steps to the east, walk four steps to the north, walk five steps to the east, walk two steps to the south, walk one step to the west, then walk three steps to the south."

As output, you'll output the map in a graphical form, using the characters `>`, `^`, `v`, and `<` as pointers. Here's the output for the above input:

```
  >>>>>v
  ^    v
  ^   v<
  ^   v
>>^   X
```

Notice that we've replaced the last step to the south with an `X` instead. This is because the last step is where the treasure is, and as we all know, pirates must have an X on their treasure maps, otherwise they won't know how to read it.

By the way, the map won't ever cross itself, so you don't need to worry about dealing with overlaps. Also, you are allowed to have a trailing new line at the end of the output.

#### Sample Inputs and Outputs

```
S5,W2
```

```
 v
 v
 v
 v
 v
X<
```

```
N1,E1,S1,E1,N1,E1,S2
```

```
>v>v
^>^X
```

```
N1
```

```
X
```

```
N6,E6,S6,W5,N5,E4,S4,W3,N3,E2,S2,W1,N2
```

```
>>>>>>v
^>>>>vv
^^>>vvv
^^^Xvvv
^^^^<vv
^^^<<<v
^^<<<<<
```

```
E21,S2
```

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>v
                     X
```

```
N12,E11,S12,W2,N4
```

```
>>>>>>>>>>>v
^          v
^          v
^          v
^          v
^          v
^          v
^          v
^          v
^        X v
^        ^ v
^        ^ v
^        ^<<
```

Comment: Are we allowed to have trailing spaces on each line? Is the number always going to be less than ten?

Comment: @vihan You are not allowed to have trailing spaces on each line. The number is not always going to be less than ten.

Comment: @Sp3000 The number of steps can be more than one digit. I added a new test case for more than one digit steps.

Comment: @Sp3000 Leading spaces before lines are allowed (for some of the inputs, some of the lines need to be "padded" with spaces). Leading spaces after lines are not allowed. Leading spaces after or before the whole grid are allowed.

Comment: I really think the `X` should mark the step *after* the last move, like all other moves are counted. Imagine the last step is N3: you walk three steps to the north and dig, but there is nothing here, you had to walk 2 steps instead. I don't mind if you keep the existing rule, because it adds a little corner case to handle. But remember what happened to that laddie.

Comment: @coredump Or maybe we want to mislead the pirates, so that we can take the treasure for ourselves ;) 

No, you're correct, the pirates are digging one step too soon. Given there are already three answers, I'll keep the rule as it is to avoid invalidating existing solutions.

Comment: Is there any limit to how long a certain direction will be?

Comment: @BassetHound There's no limit, but you don't need to handle integer overflow or anything like that.

Comment: What kind of pirates can't follow a compass? I don't think I'll be sailing with them anytime soon.

Comment: @jpmc26 Well, these pirates don't know much of the alphabet... they spent the last few years at C :)

Comment: Can we store the output in a global variable after the function is called? (to avoid having to return) Sorry if there is a standard rule for that or something, I'm new at this...

Comment: The fourth example is just trolling the pirates...

Comment: @UndefinedFunction No, you need to return a value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Ruby, <del>213 209 198 186</del> 178

```ruby
M={};x=0,m=q=0
gets.scan(/.(\d+)/){?1.upto($1){m,y=x
x[d=$&.ord%10%7-2]+=1|($u=M[y]||={})[m]=d
m<q&&q=m}}
$u[m]=2
puts M.sort.map{|_,b|(q..b.max[0]).map{|k|">vX <^"[b[k]||3]}*""}
```

Pass input via stdin.

This uses a `y -> x -> char` dictionary to construct the map, where both `x` and `y` can be negative. Once the input has been parsed, the global minimum of the x coordinate is extracted. For each row, it then iterates over a range going from the global minimum to the maximum index for the current line, and prints the correct character for that index.

To stay with the theme, the expressions to turn `NESW` into the proper indices were shamelessly pirated from [Sp3000](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/21487/sp3000)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54308/84).

Original version that used a `[x,y] -> char` dictionary:

```
M={};x=0,0
gets.scan(/.(\d+)/){(?1..$1).map{x[d=$&.ord%10%7-2]+=1|M[$y=x+[]]=d}}
M[$y]=2
a,*q=M.minmax.flatten
M.map{|(x,y),v|($*[y-M.map{|a,|a[1]}.min]||=?\s.*q[2]-a)[x-a]=">vX<^"[v]}
puts$*.map &:rstrip
```

Answer (score 20):

## Python 2, <s>249</s> <s>248</s> <s>244</s> <s>239</s> 237 bytes

```py
D={}
m=X=Y=0
for s in input().split(","):d=ord(s[0])%10%7;exec"a,b=X,Y;E=D[Y]=D.get(Y,{});E[X]='<^>v'[d];m=min(m,X);%c+=d-2|1;"%(88+d%2)*int(s[1:])
D[b][a]="X"
for Y in sorted(D):print"".join(D[Y].get(n," ")for n in range(m,max(D[Y])+1))
```

Input like `"E2,N4,E5,S2,W1,S3"`.

`NSEW` is mapped to `[1, 3, 2, 0]` by `d=ord(c)%10%7`. Whether to change `y` or `x` is then decided by `d%2`, and whether to increment or decrement is decided by `d-2|1`. The first and third expressions were found by brute force.

Other than that, it's a simple usage of a nested dictionary of the form `{y: {x: char}}`.

*(Thanks to @joriki for help with mapping)*

Comment: `(d + 1 & 2) - 1`

Comment: @joriki Ah that's a nice expression - thanks!

Comment: [Here's some code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/cfd5a5cdc756c3919861) I wrote (in a different context) for finding simple expressions for integer functions. I didn't use it for this, but just thought that it might be interesting for you. (The relevant code starts where it says "This is the code that I used to optimize the encoding".)

Comment: @joriki Brute forcing's a great idea - just turned up `1|d%-3` (which is the negation, but I just realised that's okay too)!

Answer (score 14):

## Javascript (ES6), 260

This was an interesting one...

Thanks @ETHproductions, @edc65, and @vihan for the help!

```js
s=>{z=o=""
m=[]
q=x=y=2e3
s.split`,`.map(v=>z+=v[0].repeat(+v.slice(1)))
for(i=0;d=z[i];q=x<q?x:q)(m[y]=m[y]||[])[x]=z[++i]?d=="N"&&--y?"^":d=="S"&&++y?"v":d=="W"&&--x?"<":++x?">":o:"X"
m.map(a=>a.map((b,j)=>o+=" ".repeat(-p-1+(p=j))+b,p=q-1,o+=`
`))
return o}
```

This defines an anonymous function, so to call it add `f=` to the beginning to give it a name.

To test: `console.log(f("E2,N4,E5,S2,W1,S3"))`

#### Explanation:

```js
s=>{ //define function w/ parameter s
z=o=""      //z=modified input, o=final output
m=[]        //map of characters
q=x=y=2e3   //q=minimum value of x; x+y=coordinates. These start high to leave room to go backwards
s.split`,`.map(v=>z+=v[0].repeat(+v.slice(1)))    //change "N3,E4" -> "NNNEEEE", and put in z
for(i=0;d=z[i];q=x<q?x:q)   //for each direction d in z, while updating q:
    (m[y]=m[y]||[])[x]=     //in the right place on the map, put:
        z[++i]?                 //if last character of z, "X"
            d=="N"&&--y?"^":    
            d=="S"&&++y?"v":    //otherwise get the right character and change x+y accordingly
            d=="W"&&--x?"<":
            ++x?">":o
        :"X"
m.map(a=>a.map((b,j)=>o+=" ".repeat(-p-1+(p=j))+b,p=q-1,o+=`
`)) //dump map to o, with correct padding
return o}   //return
```

Comment: That's an nice way to separate statements! It's certainly much more readable than putting everything on one line and separating them with semicolons. If I may offer my suggestion: you could save a byte by moving your `i++` from the `for` loop to the last place it's used, in this case `c=i++>r-2?"X":c`.

Comment: Also, since you're using ES6, I would suggest using `v[0].repeat(+v.slice(1))` in place of `Array(v.slice(1)- -1).join(v[0])`, and `" ".repeat(j-p-1)` in place of `Array(j-p).join(" ")`, saving 11 bytes overall. I think you could also place `F='forEach'` at the beginning of the function, then change each `.forEach` from there on to `[F]`, saving another 4.

Comment: @ETHproductions Thanks! It's down to 347!

Comment: Update: moving the F="forEach" declaration to the first place it is used saved another 2.

Comment: Try using .map instead of .forEach. It's so short you should not even shorten it to F

Comment: @edc65 Nice. Down to 317! Think it's about as golfed as it's going to get...

Comment: @UndefinedFunction you might want to use shorthands for the `if`s, it might help if you decrement variables at the same time also

Comment: @vihan Down to 263! I changed the ifs to ternary, but couldn't figure out how to shorten it by incrementing or decrementing variables at the same time. If you could point out how, that would be nice. Thanks!

Comment: If my understanding is correct, does `q=x=y=2e3` mean that the output would be incorrect if I did, say, `W9999`?

Comment: @Sp3000 easily solved at no cost ... 2e5 ... 2e9 ? The output string is limited anyway

Comment: @Sp3000 Correct, the program wouldn't work correctly in that case. However, as edc65 mentioned in theory this could be replaced with 9e9 at no cost. (I used 2e3 to make it run faster, although up to 9e5 seems to run reasonably quickly on my computer)

Answer (score 7):

## PHP, <s>431</s> 417 bytes

```
$g=explode(',',$argv[1]);$x=$y=$a=$b=$c=$d=$e=$f=0;
foreach($g as$i=>$h){list($k,$l,$m)=
    ['N'=>[-1,0,'^'],'E'=>[0,1,'>'],'S'=>[1,0,'v'],'W'=>[0,-1,'<']][$h[0]];
    for($s=substr($h,1);$s--;){$z[$f=$y][$e=$x]=$m;$y+=$k;$x+=$l;}
    if($i==count($g)-1){$x=$e;$y=$f;}
    $a=min($a,$x);$b=max($b,$x);$c=min($c,$y);$d=max($d,$y);
}$z[$y][$x]='X';for($y=$c;$y<=$d;$y++)
{$o='';for($x=$a;$x<=$b;$x++)$o.=$z[$y][$x]?:' ';echo rtrim($o)."\n";}
```

Put it into a file (`treasure.php`), remove the indentation, join the lines (it is wrapped here for readability), put the `<?php` marker at the beginning of the file (not displayed here as it is technically not a part of the program).

Example of execution:

```
$ php -d error_reporting=0 treasure.php E2,N4,E5,S2,W1,S3
  >>>>>v
  ^    v
  ^   v<
  ^   v
>>^   X
$
```

The option `-d error_reporting=0` is needed to suppress notices about values not found at specified indices in `$z`.

**Update:**

While I was preparing the [ungolfed version of the code](https://github.com/axiac/code-golf/blob/master/yarr-a-map-to-the-hidden-treasure.php) for posting I discovered it contained two unneeded assignments (12 bytes) and a whitespace that can be removed(`as$i`); also, by replacing a `while` with a `for` loop and squeezing an assignment into it (not possible using the `while` loop) I saved another byte.

Comment: I would love to see an ungolfed version.

Comment: @LarsEbert I updated the answer with a link to the ungolfed code. I checked your solution now (didn't do it before); we have basically used the same algorithm. Yours handles the last step better than mine. I can strip 25 more bytes if I implement `$count --;`.

Comment: `$argn` save 3 Bytes `chop` save 1 Byte `"X"` -> `X` use constants save more bytes

Comment: @JörgHülsermann I don't get the `$argn` hint. I am aware of the `"X"->X` trick but I probably forgot about it when I wrote this solution. I write PHP code since 2002 but until today I didn't notice that PHP provides the [`chop()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chop.php) function. Thank you for this hint.

Answer (score 7):

## Perl, <strike>702</strike> <strike>613</strike> <strike>546</strike> <strike>474</strike> <strike>439</strike> <strike>338</strike> 260 bytes

Thanks to Dom Hastings for his help and his supergolfed version.
The code uses a 2D array.

Version by Dom Hastings:

```perl
$x=$y=$a=$b=99;map{/^./;$a=($c=$x)<$a?$x:$a,$A=$x>$A?$x:$A,$b=($C=$y)<$b?$y:$b,$B=$y>$B?$y:$B,$q[$c][$C]={split'','W<E>N^Sv'}->{$&},$x+={W,-1,E,1}->{$&},$y+={N,-1,S,1}->{$&}for 1..$'}split',',pop;$q[$c][$C]=X;for$y($b..$B){print$q[$_][$y]||$"for$a..$A;print$/}
```

My lesser golfed version of 338 bytes (for reference):

```perl
@m=split(',',pop);$x=$y=$a=$b=99;map{($d,$s)=/^(.)(.+)$/;for(1..$s){$c=$x;$C=$y;if($x<$a){$a=$x}if($x>$A){$A=$x}if($y<$b){$b=$y}if($y>$B){$B=$y}if($d eq"W"){$r="<";$x--}if($d eq"E"){$r=">";$x++}if($d eq"N"){$r="^";$y--}if($d eq"S"){$r=v;$y++}$q[$c][$C]=$r}}@m;$q[$c][$C]=X;for$y($b..$B){for$x($a..$A){$t=$q[$x][$y];print$t?$t:$"}print$/}
```

Test

```perl
$ perl piratemap_golf.pl E4,N3,W6,S10,W1,S1,E5,N1,W2,N6,E6,N5,W10,S1,E2
v<<<<<<<<<<
>Xv<<<<<< ^
  v     ^ ^
  v     ^ ^
  v >>>>^ ^
  v >>>>>>^
  v ^
  v ^
  v ^
  v ^
  v ^
 v< ^<<
 >>>>>^
```

Comment: If you aren't using `use strict;`, you don't need all the `my`s, which will save you at least a few bytes. Also `==` is shorter than `eq` since the latter requires spaces.

Comment: Thanks Alex A. for the tips. That shaved some bytes off. A replacement with == didn't work, but the space after 'eq' was indeed removable. Also the initialization of the number variables to 0 wasn't needed either.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you're only calling `$m` once, so rather than storing the command line argument as a variable, you can call it directly in `split`, i.e. `@m=split(',',$ARGV[0])`.

Comment: Thanks. In hindsight that was an obvious one that slipped in because of habbit. I now also removed the initialization of the array with the spaces, and instead default the undefined values to space when I print.

Comment: Hey @LukStorms, glad to see more Perl golfers! A few things to help save some bytes! Your `$d` and `$s` variables can be grabbed using regex to save you some bytes `($d,$s)=/^(.)(.+)$/`, and all `foreach`s can be `for` (as they're the same. You might also be able to save some chars replacing some of these with `map{`...`}@x` since you can ignore the parens around the iterated item (this works well if you have to contain other loops). If you're using `$ARGV[0]` you can replace that with pop, but if you use the script as in `perl script.pl <<< "text"` you can use `<>` instead!

Comment: If you want to keep the script using args, you can use `pop` to save a couple. Instead of `use Swtich` and the `switch`/`case` statements, you could do individual checks which might save you bytes. Something like `$y-="N"eq$d` will work as well (since true `1` and false is `''`). Often, you can have words as barewords, so `$y-=N eq$d` will work! There are some magic variables you can use to save bytes, `$/` is `'\n'` and `$"` is `' '`, but sometimes a literal newline might help save a char too. Another (dirty!) trick is multiple assigns to save a few more, as in `$a=0;$b=0;` can be `$a=$b=0`.

Comment: Just a few more, I promise. I hope this is the kinda info you're after! Missing off parens on function calls is a pretty standard change, so `substr($_,0,1)` can be `substr$_,0,1`. Postfix for loops and if checks can be useful too as in `for(@c){...}` vs. `...for@c` but you can't use `;` in the code, you'd have to comma separate instead (which doesn't always work when you're calling functions). There are so many great tips also at http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5105/tips-for-golfing-in-perl. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Dom for all those usefull tips. Can't believe how many bytes could still be shaved off like that. And I still have to look into that map and the postfix loop, but even then it trimmed down from 546 to 474 bytes!

Comment: I got rid of 101 bytes by assuming that pirates don't like to walk to far in north or west direction.  So now the code doesn't have to go 2 times through the moves array.

Comment: @LukStorms I worked on golfing this a bit more as I was enjoying the golf action! I got it down to 262 still using your main routines/approach. I wanted to share with you to review and see if there were any helpful snippets that weren't included in the Perl tips thread or anything: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/956afef36c14efec0e85
Happy to remove this if it's not appropriate!

Comment: Amazing. I thought I reached the limit of what could be done via the 2D array. And I had to ungolf your code just to grasp the tricks you used. Well done.  I changed the post accordingly.

Comment: @Dom. Your version in the post has 2 less bytes now. Using a FOR instead of a MAP at the end turned out to be smaller in this case.

Comment: Awesome! I hope some of those techniques were useful! I'm glad to be able to share! I probably should have provided more explanation with each of them, sorry about that... I do hope it was interesting though! Good spot on `for` vs. `map` too!

Answer (score 5):

### Python 2, 394 bytes

Run the program then paste into standard input as e.g. `"E2,N4,E5,S2,W1,S3"`

```py
m=input().split(',')
def f(x,y,h,o,s=[]):
 for c in m:
  for _ in range(int(c[1:])):
   a,b,l={'E':(1,0,'>'),'W':(-1,0,'<'),'N':(0,1,'^'),'S':(0,-1,'v')}[c[0]]
   if o:o[h-y][x]=l
   s+=[(x,y)];x+=a;y+=b
 if o:o[h-y+b][x-a]='X'
 return s
p,q=zip(*f(*[0]*4))
w,h=max(p)-min(p),max(q)-min(q)
o=[[' ']*-~w for _ in range(h+1)]
f(-min(p),-min(q),h,o)
print'\n'.join(["".join(l).rstrip()for l in o])
```

This is not very optimized. First it runs through the input to record the path. Then it does some math to determine the right starting position and size of `o`. Then it runs through again and sets the appropriate entries of `o` as one of `>v<^X`. The main cleverness is in reusing the same function for both these traversals.

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 496 <del>514</del> <del>528</del>

I tried my luck in PHP, the result is rather long, I still want to post it, just for fun.

```
function a($c){global$a,$b;$a[$b[1]][$b[0]]=$c;}$c=explode(',',$argv[1]);$a=[];$b=[0,0];foreach($c as$d=>$e){$f=substr($e,1);if($d==count($c)-1)$f--;for($i=0;$i++<$f;){if($e[0]==N){a('^');$b[1]--;}elseif($e[0]==E){a('>');$b[0]++;}elseif($e[0]==S){a(v);$b[1]++;}else{a('<');$b[0]--;}}}a(X);$d=$e=$f=$g=0;foreach($a as$y=>$h){$f=min($f,$y);$g=max($g,$y);foreach($h as$x=>$i){$d=min($d,$x);$e=max($e,$x);}}for($y=$f;$y<=$g;$y++){for($x=$d;$x<=$e;$x++)echo isset($a[$y][$x])?$a[$y][$x]:' ';echo "
";}
```

### Ungolfed

```
<?php

    function setInMap($char) {
        global $map, $position;
        $map[$position[1]][$position[0]] = $char;
    }

    $instructions = explode(',', $argv[1]);

    $map = [];

    $position = [0, 0];

    foreach($instructions as $index => $instruction) {
        $count = substr($instruction, 1);
        if($index === count($instructions) - 1) {
            $count--;
        }
        for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            if($instruction[0] === 'N') {
                setInMap('^');
                $position[1]--;
            } elseif($instruction[0] === 'E') {
                setInMap('>');
                $position[0]++;
            } elseif($instruction[0] === 'S') {
                setInMap('v');
                $position[1]++;
            } else($instruction[0] === 'W') {
                setInMap('<');
                $position[0]--;
            }
        }
    }
    setInMap('X');

    $minX = $maxX = $minY = $maxY = 0;
    foreach($map as $y => $row) {
        $minY = min($minY, $y);
        $maxY = max($maxY, $y);
        foreach($row as $x => $cell) {
            $minX = min($minX, $x);
            $maxX = max($maxX, $x);
        }
    }
    for($y = $minY; $y <= $maxY; $y++) {
        for($x = $minX; $x <= $maxX; $x++) {
            if(isset($map[$y][$x])) {
                echo $map[$y][$x];
            } else {
                echo ' ';
            }
        }
        echo "\n";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Can be reduced a lot. For instance, you can just write `for(;$i++<$f;)`, try to remove unnecessary brackets, use undefined constants (`N`) instead of strings (`'N'`),  …

Comment: Instead of `if`s, try using trenary operators or logical ands. Also, it will help if you use PHP4.1 and use a GET array with the points.

Answer (score 4):

## XQuery 3.0, 498

```
declare variable $v external;let $m:=<v>{tokenize($v,',')!(for $j in(1 to xs:int(substring(.,2)))return<c>{translate(substring(.,1,1),'NESW','^>v<')}</c>)}</v>/c!(let $p:=./preceding-sibling::c return<p x="{count($p[.='>'])-count($p[.='<'])}" y="{count($p[.='v'])-count($p[.='^'])}">{if(./following::*)then .else'X'}</p>)for $y in(min(xs:int($m/@y))to max(xs:int($m/@y)))return string-join(for $x in(min(xs:int($m/@x))to max(xs:int($m/@x)))let $d:=$m[@x=$x and @y=$y]return if($d)then$d else' ','')
```

XQuery isn't often even slightly competitive, so this was fun.

### Ungolfed

```
declare variable $v external;
let $map := <vector>{ tokenize($v,',') ! 
        (for $j in (1 to xs:int(substring(.,2)))
            return <step>{ translate(substring(.,1,1),'NESW','^>v<') }</step> ) 
         }</vector>/step !
            (let $path_so_far := ./preceding-sibling::step
            return <point 
                x="{ count($path_so_far[.='>']) - count($path_so_far[.='<']) }" 
                y="{ count($path_so_far[.='v']) - count($path_so_far[.='^']) }">
                {if(./following::*) then string(.) else 'X'}
            </point>)
for $y in (min(xs:int($map/@y)) to max(xs:int($map/@y)))
return string-join(
    for $x in (min(xs:int($map/@x)) to max(xs:int($map/@x)))
    let $d := $map[@x=$x and @y=$y]
    return if($d) then string($d) else ' '
    ,'')
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 244 <s>249 274</s>

Leading spaces and newlines added for clarity and not counted, **except** the newline near the end in the join call, that is significant and counted.

Test running the snippet (being ECMAScript 6, Firefox and Safari 9 only)

```js
F=m=>(
  x=y=0,p=[],
  m.replace(/\w(\d+)/g,(d,z)=>{
    for(d='NWSE'.search(d[0]);
        z--&&(p=~x?~y?p:[y=0,...p]:p.map(r=>' '+r,x=0));
        p[u=y]=(w=r.slice(0,x))+'^<v>'[d]+(v=r.slice(x+1)),
        d&1?x+=d-2:y+=d-1)
      for(r=p[y]||'';!r[x];)r+=' ';
  }),
  p[u]=w+'X'+v,
  p.join`
`
)

// TEST

out=x=>O.innerHTML+=x.replace(/</g,'&lt;')+'\n'

;['S5,W2','N1,E1,S1,E1,N1,E1,S2','N1','N6,E6,S6,W5,N5,E4,S4,W3,N3,E2,S2,W1,N2','E21,S2','N12,E11,S12,W2,N4']
.forEach(a=>out(a+'\n'+F(a)+'\n'))
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

## C, 557

```
main(_,a,minX,maxX,minY,maxY,x,y,v,dir,dist)char**a;char*v;{char o[998][999];for(y=0;y-998;++y){for(x=0;x-998;++x)o[y][x]=32;o[y][998]=0;}y=x=minY=minX=maxY=maxX=499;v=a[1];while(*v){dir=*v++;dist=atoi(v);while(*v&&*v!=44)v++;v+=!!*v;if(dir==78){while(dist--)o[y--][x]=94;if(y<minY)minY=y;y+=!*v;}if(dir==69){while(dist--)o[y][x++]=62;if(x>maxX)maxX=x;x-=!*v;}if(dir==83){while(dist--)o[y++][x]=86;if(y>maxY)maxY=y;y-=!*v;}if(dir==87){while(dist--)o[y][x--]=60;if(x<minX)minX=x;x+=!*v;}}o[y][x]=88;for(y=minY;y<=maxY;++y){o[y][maxX+1]=0;puts(o[y]+minX);}}
```

Ungolfed version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_WIDTH 998
#define MAX_HEIGHT 998

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int minX,maxX,minY,maxY;
    int x,y;
    char output[MAX_HEIGHT][MAX_WIDTH+1];
    char *v;
    
    for (y=0; y<MAX_HEIGHT; ++y) {
        for (x=0; x<MAX_WIDTH; ++x) 
            output[y][x] = ' ';
        output[y][MAX_WIDTH] = 0;
    }

    x = minX = maxX = MAX_WIDTH/2;
    y = minY = maxY = MAX_HEIGHT/2;

    v = argv[1];
    while (*v) {
        char dir; int dist;
        dir = *(v++);
        dist = atoi(v);
        while (*v && *v != ',') v++;
        if (*v) v++;

        switch (dir) {
            case 'N':case 'n':
                while (dist--) output[y--][x] = '^';
                if (y < minY) minY = y;
                if (!*v) y++;
                break;
            case 'E':case 'e':
                while (dist--) output[y][x++] = '>';
                if (x > maxX) maxX = x;
                if (!*v) x--;
                break;
            case 'S':case 's':
                while (dist--) output[y++][x] = 'v';
                if (y > maxY) maxY = y;
                if (!*v) y--;
                break;
            case 'W':case 'w':
                while (dist--) output[y][x--] = '<';
                if (x < minX) minX = x;
                if (!*v) x++;
                break;
        }
    }

    output[y][x] = 'x';
    for (y = minY; y <= maxY; ++y) {
        output[y][maxX+1] = 0;
        puts(output[y]+minX);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Dynamic memory allocation isn't much harder, but malloc is far too long an identifier to be used in code golf. I feel like there should be some kind of PCG.h header legally auto-included for golfing in c, just to shorted some identifiers.

Comment: [391 bytes](https://tio.run/##NZBNj4IwEIbv@yvQvVA6JIqI1HH05FEvHjgQDgTKR7KKQbfbxvjb2cJmL006fed5OlP4dVEMw2cpq/YmnZNzldeHfLpdajKuP/7ribOJiXr2@mnaL@mWvs90ajMfhoSIUWPR5L3TpfaS2UNkeM3bmyshhwpqaEBBDyUbU56Xg6fwVXW9i8b3kZ1gFYAQG4aGNNUkqaGKQiFwzCjK02WGtqUnijcH7VMJJ76EaGGJIEnv5EFvJWhOM09tF@zVk6c4x5LyZ9e6iqHi9Hj2xeN@cxXMYT5VZjaNbeUmvp9lJEKsyezqg9nWaCYUvq0xEocTRMGosoISKtL7yvoqsB@ZfCNjzRPOLSWOsCGzbyylscP9Ud7jMlNtX@NpIkPWsKMG79/Px7hp28olY/gehuEcwTGCSwTJGs5rOIZwCSFZwXkFxwAuASRLOAe/ "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>61</s> 60 bytes

```
“ESWN”iⱮo)µịØ.,U;N$¤Wẋɗ/€Ẏḣ1;Ɗ+\ṖZṂ€ạƊ‘ŒṬ€a"Œṙ-0¦$Sị“>v<^X ”
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9RwxzX4HC/Rw1zMx9tXJeveWjrw93dh2fo6YRa@6kcWhL@cFf3yen6j5rWPNzV93DHYkPrY13aMQ93Tot6uLMJLLrwWNejhhlHJz3cuQbIT1QCsWbqGhxaphIMNAlovF2ZTVyEAtCC/w93LgZSOg93LLIOA@pqWnO4PZLLGqhEIT2zLLVYITex4NA2oArrw@1cD3dvOdwOVJL1qHHfoW2Htv3/H2yqE27E5Weo42qoEwwmoWyQIJefmY6rmU6wmU64qY6fqY6riU6wiU64sY6fsY6rEVCNTjhQvRGXqxFUgxFQK8gcoISRjp8JAA)

A monadic link taking as its argument the directions as a list of lists, each of which has the compass direction character as its first member and the number of moves as an integer as its second. Returns a list of Jelly strings representing the map.

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, 359

```
c=args[0].split(',').collect{[it[0],it[1..-1]as int]}
m=[[]]
x=y=0
d=["N":["^",0,1],"S":["v",0,-1],"E":[">",1,0],"W":["<",-1,0]]
c.each{z->(1..z[1]).each{if(x<0){m*.add(0," ");x=0};if(y<0){m.add(0,[]);y=0};m[y]=m[y]?:[];m[y][x]=d[z[0]][0];if(c.last()==z&&it==z[1])m[y][x]='X';y+=d[z[0]][2];x+=d[z[0]][1]}}
m.reverse().each{println it.collect{it?:" "}.join()}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp - 603

```
(lambda(s)(do((x 0)i(y 0)j(p 0)r(q 0)(g(mapcar(lambda(x)`(,(aref x 0),(parse-integer x :start 1)))(split-sequence:split-sequence #\, s))(cdr g))c)((not g)(setf x 0 y 0)(dolist(e(stable-sort(sort r #'<= :key #'car)#'< :key #'cadr))(dotimes(_(-(cadr e)p y))(terpri)(incf y)(setf x 0))(dotimes(_(-(car e)q x))(princ" ")(incf x))(princ(caddr e))(incf x)))(case(caar g)(#\N(setf i 0 j -1 c #\^))(#\E(setf i 1 j 0 c #\>))(#\W(setf i -1 j 0 c #\<))(#\S(setf i 0 j 1 c #\v)))(dotimes(_(-(cadar g)(if(cdr g)0 1)))(push`(,x,y,c)r)(incf x i)(incf y j))(setf q(min q x)p(min p y))(unless(cdr g)(push`(,x,y #\X)r))))
```

Array-free implementation: prints from top to bottom, from left to right.

- Parse and expands directions into a trace of `(x y char)` elements:

  The simple "N3" input produces `((0 0 #\^) (0 -1 #\^) (0 -2 #\X))`
- Also, compute the minimal `x` and `y`
- Sort the resulting trace by `y` first and then by `x`
- Iterate over the sorted list while moving cursor

  1. Add newlines and spaces to move current cursor at right position
  2. When at position `x - minx`, `y - miny`, print the desired character

#### Examples

```
(loop for input in  '("N6,E6,S6,W5,N5,E4,S4,W3,N3,E2,S2,W1,N2" 
                      "N1,E1,S1,E1,N1,E1,S2" 
                      "N12,E11,S12,W2,N4")
      do (fresh-line)
         (terpri)
      (funcall *fun* input))
```

Result:

```
>>>>>>v
^>>>>vv
^^>>vvv
^^^Xvvv
^^^^<vv
^^^<<<v
^^<<<<<

>v>v
^>^X

>>>>>>>>>>>v
^          v
^          v
^          v
^          v
^          v
^          v
^          v
^          v
^        X v
^        ^ v
^        ^ v
^        ^<<
```

Answer (score 1):

## CoffeeScript, <s>303</s>  285 bytes

```coffee
Y=(s)->o=[];t=l=x=y=0;q='';q+=s[0]for[1..s[1..]]for s in s.split ',';q=q[..-2];(i='NWSE'.search c;(o[y]?=[])[x]='^<v>'[i];j=(i&2)-1;x+=j*(i&1);y+=j*(!(i&1));y<t&&t=y;x<l&&l=x)for c in q;(o[y]?=[])[x]='X';((o[y][x]||' 'for x in[l...o[y].length]).join ''for y in[t...o.length]).join '\n'
```

```html
<script src="http://coffeescript.org/extras/coffee-script.js"></script>
<script type="text/coffeescript">
Y=(s)->o=[];t=l=x=y=0;q='';q+=s[0]for[1..s[1..]]for s in s.split ',';q=q[..-2];(i='NWSE'.search c;(o[y]?=[])[x]='^<v>'[i];j=(i&2)-1;x+=j*(i&1);y+=j*(!(i&1));y<t&&t=y;x<l&&l=x)for c in q;(o[y]?=[])[x]='X';((o[y][x]||' 'for x in[l...o[y].length]).join ''for y in[t...o.length]).join '\n'

#------------------
document.write '<pre>'
z=[
  'E2,N4,E5,S2,W1,S3'
  'S5,W2'
  'N1,E1,S1,E1,N1,E1,S2'
  'N1'
  'N6,E6,S6,W5,N5,E4,S4,W3,N3,E2,S2,W1,N2'
  'E21,S2'
  'N12,E11,S12,W2,N4'
]
for w in z
  document.write "\n\n#{w}\n"
  document.write Y(w).replace /</g,'&lt;'
  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 32 bytes

```
ＷＳ«≔⌕ENW§ι⁰θ✳⊗θ×§>^<vθΣι»Ｍ✳⁺⊗θ⁴X
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc3BasJAFIXhtecphlndS1OoMWajCIIpuHAoTCFdCZoMeiFOajJJC6XPPlVKd92f7z/V@dBV7aGJ8eMsjVO09e9DsKETfyJm9YXJuu/l5OlZfE26MKVO1Dpsfe0@SRL1xJyoKy8webmZQBvpXBWk9bRph2PjarreF69ycT39Ob3aL0d9d4myw4WE@Vb4xq4d3b@Fh4wZvwf6TXOMJkeRw@Yo5zBzFBlshnIGM0ORwqYopzAp4mMz/gA)

Input taken as a multiline string.

Link is to verbose version of code.

Golfed from 43 bytes with [Neil's help.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56410590#56410590)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2), 390 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 48.75 bytes

```
⌐⌊›?Ǎf`NESW`kd√:£Ŀ:ṅ¥`^>v<`ĿfW∩vǔṫ⁽‹ẇwJ:tt\X1"pwJ⟑÷ø∧
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyI9IiwiIiwi4oyQ4oyK4oC6P8eNZmBORVNXYGtk4oiaOsKjxL864bmFwqVgXj52PGDEv2ZX4oipdseU4bmr4oG94oC54bqHd0o6dHRcXFgxXCJwd0rin5HDt8O44oinIiwiIiwiTjEyLEUxMSxTMTIsVzIsTjQiXQ==)

Bitstring:

```
000110000111010100000001000100000101011110110001100110111110111101111011001110011001001000011101100001111110011101110101110100100100110111110011000000010110101101110001011010011010000010011111100110010101010011010000110000010100000110001000100010100110010101010000110101110111100001000011001100000001110101110111000000101111101011000110101100100110111100111111000101110011110111110101001011
```

```
⌐⌊›?Ǎf`NESW`kd√:£Ŀ:ṅ¥`^>v<`ĿfW∩vǔṫ⁽‹ẇwJ:tt\X1"pwJ⟑÷ø∧­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
⌐⌊›                                                    # ‎⁡split by comma, get number part, increment
   ?Ǎf                                                 # ‎⁢get directions and flatten
      `NESW`                                           # ‎⁣Directions
            kd√                                        # ‎⁤"02468"
               :£                                      # ‎⁢⁡duplicate and push to register
                 Ŀ                                     # ‎⁢⁢transliterate directions to corresponding canvas numbers
                  :ṅ¥                                  # ‎⁢⁣duplicate, join by nothing, push register
                     `^>v<`Ŀ                           # ‎⁢⁤Transliterate each direction to corresponding arrow text
                            fW∩                        # ‎⁣⁡flatten, wrap the stack and transpose
                               vǔ                      # ‎⁣⁢‎⁣⁤rotate each sublist to order [text, length, direction] for canvas
                                 ṫ⁽‹ẇwJ                # ‎⁣⁣decrement the middle of the last triplet 
                                       :tt             # ‎⁣⁤get the very last direction
                                          \X1"         # ‎⁤⁡["X", 1]
                                              pwJ      # ‎⁤⁢prepend it to the direction and put it back (Draws the X) 
                                                 ⟑÷ø∧  # ‎⁤⁣draw each triplet to the canvas
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>37</s> 35 (or <s>42</s> 38) [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

**38 bytes:** Input as comma-separated string, as mentioned in the challenge description:

```
',¡εć"NESW"skxs"^>v<"è)}øR`ā¤Ê+ŠΛ1'X0Λ
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fXefQwnNbj7Qr@bkGhysVZ1cUK8XZldkoHV6hWXt4R1DCkcZDSw53aR9dcG62oXqEwbnZ///7GRrpuBoa6gQD6XAjHT8TAA)

**35 bytes:** Input as a list of pairs of direction-character and distant-integer, by removing the first three bytes `',¡`:
[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3NYj7Up@rsHhSsXZFcVKcXZlNkqHV2jWHt4RlHCk8dCSw13aRxecm22oHmFwbvb//9HRSn5KOoZGsTrRSq5AhiGIEQwTCVfSAdNAJSaxsQA)

**Explanation (of the strict I/O program):**

```python
',¡           '# Split the (implicit) input-string on commas
   ε           # Map over each string:
    ć          #  Extract its head; push distant and direction-char separately
     "NESW"sk  #  Get the 0-based index of the character in "NESW"
             x #  Double it (without popping)
     s         #  Swap so the index is at the top again
      "^>v<"è  #  Convert the index to the correct output character
     )         #  Wrap all three values into a list
    }ø         # After the map: zip/transpose the list of triplets; swapping rows/columns
      R        # Reverse the list of triplets
       `       # Pop and push all three lists separately to the stack
        ā      # Push a list in the range [1,length]
         ¤     # Push its last item (without popping the list)
          Ê    # Check for each that it's NOT equal to this last item
           +   # Add the values at the same positions
               # (so 1 is added to all distances, except the last one)
        Š      # Triple-swap the three lists on the stack
         Λ     # Canvas builtin with these three arguments
               # (which is output immediately)
1'X0Λ         '# And another Canvas builtin with arguments 1,"X",0
               # (which is done on top of the other Canvas and also output)
```

The Canvas builtin `Λ` takes three arguments:

1. Length(s): which are the modified distances (+1 for every distance except the last one, since the Canvas builtin draws with overlapping corners)
2. The characters we want to display
3. The directions to draw in, which is in this case is \$0\$=North; \$2\$=South; \$4\$=South; \$6\$=West.

For example: input `E2,N4,E5,S2,W1,S3` will for `` ',¡εć"NESW"skxs"^>v<"è)}øR`ā¤Ê+Š `` result in the three lists:

1. Lengths: `[3,5,6,3,2,3]`
2. Characters: `[">","^",">","v","<","v"]`
3. Directions: `[2,0,2,4,6,4]`

And will print them as:

```python
  >>>>>v
  ^    v
  ^   v<
  ^   v 
>>^   v
```

After which the `1'X0Λ` will overwrite the final `v` with `X`.

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine for an in-depth explanation of the Canvas builtin.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175520/52210)