# 2D Path Drawing

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

(This is not a duplicate of [Follow the path](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/68282/follow-the-path), as this challenge have invalid path detection and use `><^v` in the output.)

## Task

So your task is to take in the description of the path and draw it out in a "Befunge(or a lot of other 2D esolangs)-like" format, and detect if it is invalid. Note that if the path is invalid, you shall not output anything except a printable custom character which cannot be one of `><^v` or space.

- The path would be invalid if the path is crossed.
- Or, if you moved off the top or left edge.

You begins at the top-left corner.

- `>n` moves you right n characters. Your trail is `>`.
- `^n` moves you up n characters. Your trail is `^`.
- `<n` moves you left n characters. Your trail is `<`.
- `vn` moves you down n characters. Your trail is `v`.

## Test Cases

```
Input: >3v3

Output:
>>>v
   v
   v

Input: v4>1^2>3

Output:
v
v
v>>>
v^
>^

Input: >5<3

Output:
!

(Or any character you want, except ><^v and space.)

Input: [NONE]

Output: [NONE]

Input: >4v2<2^2

Output:
>>>>v
  ^ v
  ^<<

Input: >4v2<2^3

Output:
!

(Or any character you want, except ><^v and space.)

Input:
>3v3<6

Output:
!

(Or any character you want, except ><^v and space.)
```

## Rules

- Standard loopholes are forbidden.
- Least bytes wins.
- This was written in a hurry.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Well, `>4v2<2^3` crosses itself and is thus... invalid, so I outputted a `!` (or custom character). I didn't get what you mean?

Comment: Just noticed I read above rather than below, sorry!

Comment: Can we input an array/list of `(direction, number)` tuples/arrays/lists?

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate Yes.

Comment: May i `throw` an exception instead of return `!`?

Comment: @tsh Uh... Oh, yeah! I guess you could output any nonsense here, except incomplete path... Wait a minute. I'm going to say you can output anything instead of returning `!` or other "one characters", but you must output the same thing for any invalid input.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate Ummmm... 1. Input seperator 2. The treasure mark 3. Invalid detection

Comment: (Maybe I should ask the question as invalid detection and not drawing the path?)

Comment: @HighlyRadioactive I'm pretty sure requiring different IO, removing the last-character-must-be-X requirement and requiring input validation doesn't make this less of a duplicate, as the only reason the answers can't ported from that question trivially is the input validation requirement, and that is [boring](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16596)

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate Invalid input is actually the point of this challenge, as it's not simply the kind of "wrong input"; The detection is nicely done in the only answer of this question.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate And the "you must not output anything except your invalid msg" needs effort; You have to either do the detection before the drawing process or use clever methods like the only answer.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate If that still didn't keep it from duplicating, are there anything that could be add or modified or deleted to make it non-trivially different from that challenge? Deleting the drawing part, I guess?

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 46 bytes

```
≔⁰ηＦ⪪Ｓ²ＦＩ§ι¹«≧⁺℅ＫＫη✳⊗⌕>^<§ι⁰§ι⁰≧⁺∨‹ⅈ⁰‹ⅉ⁰η¿η«⎚!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY4xa8MwEIVn@1conp5AAdd0awiEhEIgoaZZ2iWg2Ip9VMhGkkOh5LerttWhFDrc8O6O73tVK23VSR3CxjlqDHLBWv6UXjvLcOo1eexNP/iTt2QacMEKztlXmswPW@k8Nn5vavUJEuyBx2NylH3kvVLTepR6cIK92JqM1CiV@gDnUZQk5Uj22JFVlafOYNcNF61qPJOpka3Pq0ywX458dPC/m5FzT/@z4qCcw9tUPh9nTu8x/ZS4p3RlaOfuW62kxUSMxbJFNn2EsH68FaviXITlTX8D) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⁰η
```

Assume everything is OK.

```
Ｆ⪪Ｓ²
```

Loop over the instructions.

```
ＦＩ§ι¹«
```

Loop over the number of steps.

```
≧⁺℅ＫＫη
```

Check whether the path has crossed.

```
✳⊗⌕>^<§ι⁰§ι⁰
```

Output each character in the appropriate direction.

```
≧⁺∨‹ⅈ⁰‹ⅉ⁰η
```

Check whether the path has moved off the top or left edge.

```
¿η«⎚!
```

If something went wrong, replace the output with a `!`.

Comment: I like how you make use of the feature that you can "clean" the output. Neat!