# Insist on an answer

Tags: code-golf, interactive

At runtime, keep prompting for *a line of input* until the user inputs something (other than an empty newline), i.e. does not just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>OK</kbd>. Output or result is neither required nor prohibited.

#### Pseudo-code 1

```
myform = new form("GUI")
myform.mytxt = new editfield("")
myform.ok = new button("OK")
repeat
  waitfor(myform.ok,"click")
until myform.mytxt.content <> ""
```

#### Pseudo-code 2

```
LET TEXT = ""
WHILE TEXT = "" DO
  TEXT = PROMPT("")
ENDWHILE
```

#### Example 1

Program runs and immediately pops up a form with a single text field and an <kbd>OK</kbd> button.
User clicks the <kbd>OK</kbd> button.
Nothing happens.
User pastes "hello world" into the text field and clicks the <kbd>OK</kbd> button.
Program terminates.

#### Example 2

Function is called and immediately displays a blank line and a blinking cursor.
User presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Cursor moves down one line.
User presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Cursor moves down one line.
User presses <kbd>P</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>C</kbd><kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
Function returns.

Comment: is it allowed to count space-only lines as empty?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 No.

Comment: Is it necessary to wait for the full line once the user starts to input data?

Comment: Ok, from a comment in @CodyGray's deleted answer it seems like it's not allowed.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Yes, correct; *a line of input*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## TI-BASIC, 2 bytes

```
:Prompt X
```

TI-BASIC does this automatically. Once input is given, it will quit.

Here is a GIF:

[image]

Watch the count on the <kbd>enter</kbd> key in the Key Press History. Created with **TI-SmartView CE** and [ezgif.com](https://ezgif.com/).

Comment: Hmm.. this is 2 bytes?

Comment: TI-BASIC is [token based](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/one-byte-tokens).

Comment: And it will not take Enter for an answer? Is there anywhere to test this online?

Comment: @Adám It won't take enter for an answer. As far as I am aware, there isn't any place you can go to online without already having a TI ROM image. I can post a .gif when I get home, though.

Comment: Great answer, I would have posted it if I had the fastest gun in the west ;)

Comment: @Adám It's illegal to test TI-BASIC online without owning a ROM yourself.

Answer (score 16):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 18 bytes

```python
while''==input():0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@1@ekZmTqq5ua5uZV1BaoqFpZfC/oCgzr0QDytdUUFYIzsgvVyhKzU3MzMvMS1cAy@j95@LiSkxK5kpJTQMA)

Comment: So, you'll keep adding another language every 9 minutes?

Answer (score 16):

## JavaScript, <s>37</s> <s>22</s> 17 bytes

```
while(!prompt());
```

```js
while(!prompt());
```

### Explanation

The `while` keyword starts the `while` loop. In the condition of the loop, `!prompt()` asks for input and checks whether it is given or not. If it isn't given, the body of the loop is executed, which in our case is empty, then the interpreter goes back to the loop condition. The same process happens over and over again until the user gives the input.

Comment: `while(""==prompt(""));`

Comment: @Adám Wow. I was just thinking about how to make the solution smaller, and you came up with an answer thanks!

Comment: It seemed obvious. However, my browser console refuses to execute without a trailing `;`, while your initial expression worked fine without `;`. Any idea why?

Comment: No, Chrome. So if any JavaScript engine can handle omission of the current expression's `;`, you can save that byte :-)

Comment: @Adám Just figured out the real cause of the error produced after the removal of semicolon from the source code. The reason why that happens is that while loop expects a statement (or a group of statements) as the loop body after the loop condition. Adding the semicolon makes it think that the loop body is over. However, removing the semicolon causes it to expect the next statement as the loop body. But in our case, no new statements comes after the loop condition. So, it throws an error. I hope it is clear now. I am terrible at explaining stuff!! :p

Comment: You know, if you change ```prompt`` ``` to `prompt()` it'll work in non-ES6 browsers as well ;-)

Comment: @ETHproductions Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

## sed, 4

```
/./q
```

Waits for a line of input that has 1 or more characters, then quits.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/sed#@6@vp1/4/z8XV15@nm5qbkFJJRcA).  But it works better on a live shell:

```
sed '/./q'
```

Answer (score 9):

## HTML5, <s>33</s> 22 bytes

```
<form><input required>
```

```html
<form><input required>
```

### Explanation

The `required` attribute on the `<input>` causes the browser to inform the user "this field is required"-sort-of-message, if they do not enter a value. However, when they enter a value, the value is sent to the URL of the `action` attribute of the `<form>` (which in our case is the current file itself, since we haven't specified any value explicitly).

This was tested on the latest version of Google Chrome (version 55.0). May work in other browsers and versions.

Comment: `action=/` might work on some browsers.

Comment: You could probably ditch the `action` attribute altogether.

Comment: @Arjun The `action=y.p` isn't necessary, as most User Agents will submit to the same location if no `action` is specificed

Comment: @Arjun I've tried `<form><input required>` on the latest Google Chrome version and works as intended. And if you're skeptical, just use `action=#`. That saves 2 bytes.

Comment: @Arjun That is a terrible idea for code golfing. I can't say about **every** browser, since I don't own any Android 1.0, 1.6, 2.0, 2.1, 3.0, 3.1, 4.x.x, 5.x, 6.x, ..., iPhone 2 - 7, every single release of Google Chrome, Firefox 3.0+ and on and on and on and on... In fact, not all HTML5 browsers implement the `required` attribute! Also, `#` is a path available since HTML 1.0, if I'm correct. And adding no `action` to your form is the same as `action="."`, which is the file itself.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Realized my mistake, hence implemented what you said. Thanks!

Comment: @Shaggy Thanks! I implemented it!

Comment: @MayorMonty Thanks! Implemented!

Answer (score 9):

## Java, 55 bytes

```java
void f()throws Exception{while(System.in.read()==10);}}
```

If I remember correctly (it's been a while since I've been active on PPCG), my program can just be a function.

This is system specific; it only works on systems where the end-of-line character is a single newline. If the end-of-line character is instead a carriage return, replace the `10` with `13`. On Windows, this doesn't work, as end-of-line on windows is `\r\n`.

This makes use of the fact that I can read directly from `System.in`.

Comment: Welcome back, if only for this answer! :D

Comment: Welcome back @Justin!

Comment: Not planning on being active;  just dropping by for a question here and there

Comment: To avoid the "doesn't work on Windows" problem, can't you just test the first character and see if it is `\r`, as opposed to testing the entire string, and then running into problems with there being 2 EOL characters?

Comment: @CodyGray No. I'm reading 1 char at a time; that's all that `System.in` let's you do directly (well, you chan read an array of chars at a time). My loop body (empty) is run for every char in the input

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ɠṆ¿
```

Not much to look at on TIO, I'm afraid.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@39ywcOdbYf2///PxcWVmJTMlZKaBgA)

#### How it works

This is a niladic program, meaning that it takes no input arguments. The implicit argument and return value are both **0** in this case.

`¿` (while) is a quick that pops two links from the link stack: a condition (`Ṇ`) and a body.

`Ṇ` is a monadic atom: flat logical NOT. If the previous return value is falsy (here, **0** or an empty string), it returns **1** and the body is called.

`ɠ` is a niladic atom; it reads a raw line from STDIN and returns the result.

Once `ɠ` reads a non-empty line, `Ṇ` returns **0** and we break out of the loop.

Comment: That fast, eh? Ah, well.

Answer (score 8):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 3 bytes

```
W!w
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=W%21w&input=%0A%0A%0Aabc%0Adef&debug=0)

Translated to Python:

```python
while Pnot(input()):
 pass
```

Answer (score 6):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tio-transpilers), 26 bytes

```
+[>,----------[[-]<[-]>]<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brainfuck#@68dbaejCwfR0bqxNkBsF2sT@/8/FxdXYlIyV0pqGgA)

Comment: That TIO link is all nice and well, but it is a bit hard to tell what happens when run… ;-)

Comment: @Adám you can append `,.` to the end to verify.

Answer (score 5):

## C, <s>52 bytes</s>, <s>33 bytes</s>, 29 bytes

-19 bytes thanks to Justin

-4 bytes thanks to Christoph

```
main(){while(getchar()==10);}
```

10 is equal to '\n' - In case this isn't obvious.

Comment: You can golf it by 1 char by using a `;` instead of the `{}` for the while loop

Comment: Although not standards compliant, you can remove the `#include<stdio.h>` if you switch to `while(getchar()==10)`: [`int main(){while(getchar()==10);}`](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@5@ZV6KQm5iZp6FZXZ6RmZOqkZ5akpyRWKShaWtraKBpXfv/PxcXV2JSMldKahoA).

Comment: @Justin `main(){while(getchar()==10);}` is enough no need for default int.

Comment: `main(){scanf("%s");}` would also work, if space-only lines can count as empty.

Comment: Won't this quit if user enters a blank line? Requirement is to check they enter some other characters first.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker nope. A blank line is simply a newline character, so this loops in that case

Comment: @Justin - It quits as soon as I type something *other* than enter? That seems non-conforming with Example 2 from the question, where the function returns after typing multiple characters and user hits return.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker You are right. That didn't seem clear to me the first time I read the question, but now I see what you are saying. In that case, there are many non-conforming answers to this question.

Answer (score 5):

## Perl 5, 8+1 (-p or -n flag) bytes

```
/./&&die
```

Takes input from stdin and dies as soon as the regex matches anything except a newline.

Answer (score 5):

## R, <s>27</s> <s>24</s> <s>23</s> 22 bytes

```
while(!sum(scan()^0))t
```

Takes input from stdin, and repeat as long as input is of length 0. Cut off some bytes due to Jarko Dubbeldam and MickyT. Replaced the `{}` with `t` to save another byte.

Comment: I think you can omit the `,''`, since neither input (string or numeric) nor way of terminating was specified in the challenge.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam: good catch! I didn't realize errors were a valid termination.

Comment: would `while(!sum(scan()^0)){}` work as well?

Comment: @MickyT Seems to work. Apparently even Inf^0 is 1. Nice catch with the `sum()`. Too bad the `^0` is need to handle `0` as input.

Comment: @MickyT That's a great find with the use of `sum`, thanks! I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 5):

### Bash, 51 bytes (39 without "#!/bin/bash")

It's my first time participating in PPCG, so dont be to rude ;D

```
#!/bin/bash
read a
while [ -z "$a" ]
do
read a
done
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!, if you're planning on using Bash as a golfing language you might find [This Post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/15279/tips-for-golfing-in-bash) Interesting, it has a bunch of tips for making bash programs as small as humanly possible, there's also a [More General](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/tips-for-golfing-in-all-languages) Version you might want to skim through too.

Comment: @ConnorLSW Wow, thanks, that Post will help me a lot. I'll try to edit my Answer with this new tips ASAP.

Comment: you do not need `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Well, also the first time for me :) But you could perhaps use recursion: `[ -z \`line\` ] && $0` or if the deprecated `line` is not on your system: `[ -z \`head -n1\` ] && $0`. That should either be 20 or 24 bytes.

Comment: Got rid of the `-z` too: `[ \`head -n1\` ] || $0` (21 bytes) or `[ \`line\` ] || $0` (17 bytes).

Comment: For a pure Bash solution, there's `while [ ! "$a" ];do read a;done` or something similar with recursion.

Comment: @Yeti All of these need double quotes or they will fail if the input contains whitespace. You should be able to get rid of the spaces surrounding `||` though.

Comment: One tip- you don't need the first `read a`, since bash variables that are not set are empty by default.

Answer (score 4):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 66 bytes

```cs
class C{static void Main(){for(;System.Console.ReadLine()!="";);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cs-core#@5@ck1hcrOBcXVySWJKZrFCWn5mi4JuYmaehWZ2WX6RhHVxZXJKaq@ecn1ecn5OqF5SamOKTmZeqoaloq6RkrWldW/v/PwA)

-6 bytes thanks to raznagul.

Comment: You can save 6 bytes by writing `System.Console.ReadLIne` directly and drop the `using`-Statement.

Comment: A `while` loop would be the same number of bytes, but methinks a more idiomatic way of writing the code than a `for` loop.

Comment: you can save 24 bytes by writing it as a lambda in the form () => {}

Comment: or alternatively, 7 by making it an instance method

Answer (score 4):

## [Java](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>128</s> 126 bytes

2 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen.

```java
import java.util.*;class a{public static void main(String[]a){for(Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);s.nextLine().isEmpty(););}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#LcexDsIgEADQna9gBAd@gDi6uTEahyul5gwcDXdtbZp@Ozo4vbyOZa5N9BtWcItgdhcfMzBrOOZlyBg1C8iPteKoCyCZIA3p9XiCPabaTIhAlJrmK6VN/2fCzpKKQ7KeHaWP3JGSsQ75VmbZjfXWn2fvSikYohrT9AU)

Comment: You can golf it by two bytes: Change the `while` to a `for` and put the `Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);` inside it. And change the `.equals("")` to `.isEmpty()`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can remove the import if you inline the use of the scanner; pretty sure leaking a scanner works just fine: `while(new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine().isEmpty());`

Answer (score 4):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <strike>8</strike> 11 bytes

```
NF{exit}
```

Wait for input. If the number of fields in input is more than 0, exit.

**EDIT:**

I've just realized that this doesn't work for input containing whitespace characters only. IFS needs to be set to empty string using `-F ""` command line option. Therefore +3 bytes.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/awk#@@/nVp1akVlS@/8/F5fCv/yCksz8vOL/um4KSkoA)

Comment: Actually, you could replace `NF` with `1`.  Then you don't need to set `IFS`. And *grumble* you beat me to and `AWK` solution.

Comment: @RobertBenson I tried replacing `NF` with `1`. In that case the program exits given _any_ input, including empty newline.

Comment: I missed that part of the spec.

Answer (score 4):

### QBasic 4.5, 15 bytes

```
INPUT a$:IF a$=""THEN RUN
```

Asks for input, then checks if any was given. If not, `RUN` restarts the program.

Comment: Didn't know about the `RUN`. +1. (That rhymes too; RUN and PLUS ONE :) )

Comment: Two things: `IF""=a$` saves a byte; but I think to be fully correct you need to use `LINE INPUT`, because a regular `INPUT` statement won't accept input containing a comma.

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 13 bytes

```
gets until/./
```

I wish `gets` took a Regexp argument.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 18 bytes

```
while(!readline())
```

Comment: Does it check that the line of text is not empty?

Comment: Yes, as soon as the line is not empty `readline()` returns something else than an empty string. Non empty strings evaluate to `true` in php - atleast most of them do. "0" seems to be an exception as I just read in the docs. Well I guess my answer is wrong now.

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, <strike>15</strike> 12 bytes (11 + -n flag)

-3 bytes thanks to manatwork

```
1/0if$/ne$_
```

Explanation:

The -n flag places a read loop around the program, turning it into:

```
LINE:
while (<>) {
    1/0 if $/ ne $_  # Spaces added for clarity.
}
```

Where "<>" reads a line from stdin to the variable $_. If the line contained more than the ending newline (ne is string inequality, $/ is the input record separator which defaults to newline), a division by zero is performed which causes the program to output an error message and terminate.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG. Can you explain your code?

Comment: As [3aw5TZetdf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3906/3aw5tzetdf) suggests in [his tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5110) in [Tips for golfing in Perl?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5105/tips-for-golfing-in-perl), “Use `$/` instead of `"\n"`”. And if you reverse the compered terms, you will not need the space.

Comment: @user68838 Are you the OP? Did you create a new account to edit this?

Comment: Nice one! You should be able to drop this to 9 (7 code + `-nl`, or just 7 bytes as Perl + `-nl`) bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/99Q3yAzTSX@/38uGDD8l19QkpmfV/xfNy8HAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, <s>26</s> 20 bytes

```
For[,Input[]==Null,]
```

Comment: Shave off six bytes with `For[,Input[]==Null,]`. Works just as well.

Answer (score 3):

## SpecBAS - 34 bytes

```
1 DO : INPUT a$: LOOP UNTIL a$<>""
```

Just loops until non-empty string is entered.

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, <s>19</s> 17 bytes

```
f=do""<-getLine;f
```

Defines a function `f` that if it reads the empty line calls itself again. When reading a non-empty line an exception is raised and the recursion is stopped.

Edit: @Laikoni replaced the parameter with a pattern match and saved 2 bytes. Thanks!

Comment: Didn't think Haskell IO code could be as short as this!

Comment: 17 bytes: `f=do""<-getLine;f`

Comment: @Laikoni: nice catch. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## Java, <s>66</s> <s>64</s> 60 bytes

```
int a(){return!System.console().readLine().isEmpty()?0:a();}
```

My first Java answer, would love some tips!

Comment: You can probably remove the space between `return` and `!`. `.equals("")` == `.isEmpty()`. You can return int instead of String. OTOH, return void but either `while(System...)` or `if(System...)a();`

Comment: you can do `int a(){..?0:a();}`, saves 3 bytes

Comment: @Khaled.K actually 4!

Comment: To @Justin and Khaled.K, thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 3):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/L3viathan/Aceto), <s>9</s> <s>5</s> 4 bytes

`r`ead a value, negate it (`!`; implicitly casting to a boolean), and mirror horizontally if the value is truthy (`|`).

```
!
r|
```

Comment: Wait, Aceto runs **up**‽ And they say APL is strange for running from right to left…

Comment: @Adám Aceto runs along a 2D Hilbert curve.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 4 bytes

```
Ｗ¬Ｓω
```

### Explanation

```
Ｗ      While
  ¬Ｓ   Logical not of string input
     ω  Print ""
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
[IõÊ#
```

Explanation:

```
[     Start infinite loop
 I    One line of input
   Ê  Not equal to
  õ   Empty string
    # Break if true
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@x/teXjr4S7l//@5uLgSk5K5UlLTAA)

Comment: These are 5 Unicode code points, not 5 bytes; they are 7 bytes in UTF-8, 10 bytes in UTF-16 or 20 bytes in UTF-32.

Comment: @MatteoItalia [05AB1E uses its own encoding](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/code-page.md), therefore each of these characters are 1 byte.

Comment: Uh, sorry, I stand corrected!

Answer (score 2):

## PowerShell, 20 Bytes

```
for(;!(read-host)){}
```

runs a for loop,

`read-host` prompts for input

if read-host returns nothing it evals to false, so we invert that `!(...)` and use that as the loop end check.

much shorter than any `do{$a=read-host}while($a-eq"")` type solution involving variables.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 4 bytes

```
`jn~
```

This needs to be executed with the MATL interpreter running in Octave (not in Matlab). The reason is that in Matlab, unlike in Octave, the underlying function `input('','s')` (unevaluated input) interprets an input consisting of only spaces as empty input.

Gif or it didn't happen:

[image]

#### Explanation

```
`     % Do...while loop
  j   %   Take input as a string
  n   %   Number of elements
  ~   %   Negate. Gives true if number of elements was zero, and false otherwise
      % End loop (implicit). If top of the stack is true: next iteration. Else: Exit
```

Comment: _"Gif or it didn't happen"_ That's the best part!

Answer (score 2):

## Swift, 22 bytes

```
while readLine()==""{}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 5 bytes

```
{l!}g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@1@do1ib/v8/FwgkJiUDAA)
(TIO doesn't really show the proper behaviour)

**Explanation**

```
{      e# Do:
 l     e#  Read next line of input
  !    e#  Boolean negate (empty strings are falsy)
   }g  e# Pop the top of stack, if truthy, repeat.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure, 32 bytes

```
(some seq(repeatedly read-line))
```

`some` returns the first true value of (seq x).

`seq` gives a sequence for a collection (e.g. a String) or `nil` if the collection is empty.

`nil` counts as false for `some`, so it will ignore any empty input, completing when a non-empty string is entered.

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org/), <s>20</s> 16 Bytes

```
until[""<>ask""]
```

### Explanation:

```
until   does the code that's inside the [blocks] until it's true
<>      checks empty string "" isn't returned by rest of code
ask ""  prompts with "" (empty msg), returns user input
```

Thanks to @endo64 for the code

-4 bytes thanks to @sqlab

Comment: Save 4 bytes by omitting the spaces

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 8 bytes (7 + '-n' flag)

```ruby
~/./&&a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#@1@nr6evppb4/z8XF1dIanHJv/yCksz8vOL/unkA)

Answer (score 2):

### ZX81 BASIC, 20 bytes

```
10 INPUT A$
20 IF NOT LEN A$ THEN RUN
```

Because ZX81 BASIC is tokenised, `NOT LEN A$` is a byte shorter then `A$<>""`. Program lines count 5 bytes each including the line number.

Comment: Why can't you use line numbers 1 and 2?

Comment: @Adám Line numbers are stored internally as 16-bit integers, so they don't affect the byte count.

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + line, 16 bytes

```
[ "`line`" ]||$0
```

Backticks are short for `$()`, to execute a command. `line` reads a line. If line is empty, then `[` will return false, and thus `$0` will be executed - the 0th argument which refers to itself. If there is any non-zero string, `[` will return true and because of lazy evaluation `$0` won't be executed (`||` is a logical OR).

#### *Notes*

Instead of `line` you can also use `head -n1`, which is more common (but also longer).

In all cases I tested for empty lines, which behaves accordingly. And the following special inputs that may break the behavior (but did not ;) ):

- `-x`
- `aoeu aoeu aoeu`
- `!`

The only thing that breaks it is escaping the newline with `\`, or using a  character. But how to handle these special characters is not mentioned in the original question.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to PPCG! This seems like an entirely reasonable answer. Sometimes I like to use multiple headers for posts which have multiple answers like this, e.g. "# bash + line, 16 bytes" … "# pure Bash, 19 bytes", but that's optional. Note that if you have dependencies on an external program or library (like `line` in this case), it helps to mention that in the header. (Also, I think the last solution might break if the user types something like `-x`? Not sure on that one.)

Comment: Thank you, I updated the answer accordingly. The last solution, somehow it didn't work at all. But now I updated it so that it works. I tested all of them and listed which input I tested for. There exist no special parameters that would break anything to my knowledge.

Comment: I'd rather you post each answer separately so people (including me) can vote for specific answers.

Comment: They're now separated, however I'm sure you'll upvote all of them anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

## Pure Bash, 19 bytes

A pure Bash solution using recursion in which a line is read into the variable `$a` (19 bytes):

```
read a;[ "$a" ]||$0
```

#### *Notes*

In all cases I tested for empty lines, which behaves accordingly. And the following special inputs that may break the behavior (but did not ;) ):

- `-x`
- `aoeu aoeu aoeu`
- `!`

The only thing that breaks it is escaping the newline with `\`, or using a  character. But how to handle these special characters is not mentioned in the original question.

Comment: Do you need the spaces between the brackets?

Answer (score 2):

## x86 Assembler (NASM - Linux), 227 bytes

```
SECTION .bss
i: resb 5

SECTION .text
global  _start

_start:
    mov     edx, 5
    mov     ecx, i
    mov     ebx, 0
    mov     eax, 3
    int     80h
    cmp byte [ecx], 0xa
    je _start
    mov     eax, 1
    int     80h
```

Comment: Well done! Nice first answer

Comment: Umm, is this really 227 bytes? Usually we count assembler variants based on the size of the compiled outcome.

Answer (score 2):

## x86 machine code on DOS, 13 bytes

```
00000000  43 b4 01 cd 21 3c 0d 75  f7 4b 74 f4 c3           |C...!<.u.Kt..|
0000000d
```

Commented assembly:

```
    org 100h

section .text

    ; notice: on virtually every DOS bx starts at 0 at program start
    ; see http://www.fysnet.net/yourhelp.htm
start:
    inc bx      ; bx counts the number of read characters; increment it
    mov ah,1
    int 21h     ; read a character into al
    cmp al,0dh  ; check if it's a newline
    jne start   ; repeat if it's not
    dec bx      ; got a newline; decrement the counter
    jz start    ; if the counter became 0, it means that we only read the
                ; newline; restart (with bx being 0, as on startup)
    ret         ; otherwise quit
```

Answer (score 2):

### VBScript, 26 bytes

```
while InputBox("")="" 
wend
```

This one is sort of fun because the only way to stop the programs asking for an answer is either giving one or killing 'wscript.exe' in the task manager.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 10 bytes

Doesn't seem to work in TIO, works for me in Dyalog APL 18.0

```apl
{0=≢⍞:∇0}0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v9rA9lHnoke986wedbQb1Br8/w8A)

Comment: `{⍞}⍣≢''` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

## [*Acc!!*](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!), 33 bytes

```
N
Count i while _/10*(10/_) {
N
}
```

(Don't) [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOTkr6/9@Pyzm/NK9EIVOhPCMzJ1UhXt/QQEvD0EA/XlOhmsuPq/b/fy4urkQuAA)

#### Explanation

`N` reads a character into the accumulator. If it is 10 (newline), we want to halt, otherwise keep looping. The loop condition `_/10*(10/_)` accomplishes this: `_/10` is 0 if `_` is less than 10, and `10/_` is 0 if `_` is greater than 10. The only way their product can be truthy (nonzero) is if `_` is exactly 10.

If the input is guaranteed to be printable ASCII (and not contain, for example, the tab character), the loop condition could be `10/_` for -7 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## QBasic, 34 bytes

```
INPUT A$
WHILE A$=""
INPUT A$
WEND
```

I think nothing can be more self-explanatory than that. To test, go to [this website](http://yohan.es/swbasic/) and copy-paste the following code in their text-editor :

```
10 INPUT A$
20 WHILE A$=""
30 INPUT A$
40 WEND
```

The reason why line numbers are required is that their website only supports unstructured BASIC.

Comment: Why the final `END`?

Comment: @Adám The final END is required to terminate the program when the interpreter comes out of the while loop (WEND is to terminate While Loop)

Comment: So what happens if there is no more program to execute, even though END hasn't been reached?

Comment: @Adám According to the standard,  a program must have an END statement as the last statement. However, many interpreters don't require it. But I will keep it just for the sake of compatibility.

Comment: This [has been discussed on Meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7833/43319), concluding that a language is defined by its implementation, not its documentation.

Comment: As long as you're relying on implementation-specific behavior (which, BTW, I think is absurd), you can eliminate the first line of code, too. It works on the "Simple Basic Interpreter" website you linked to!

Comment: A safer way would be to rewrite it as a `DO` loop that tests the condition at the *bottom* of the loop, instead of the top. For example: `DO`|`INPUT A$`|`LOOP WHILE A% = ""` (where | means a new line). That would be 30 bytes, still more than the 25-byte "unsafe" method I proposed, but it would at least be correct code. If you left out the spaces around the equals sign(s), you could golf it down even further, but I'm not sure if that's legal, since any QBasic interpreter will add those spaces back in automatically.

Answer (score 1):

### C#, 36 bytes

```
_=>while(System.Console.Read()==13);
```

Compiles to a `Action<int>`.

Or if a full program is required, **62 bytes**.

```
class P{static void Main(){while(System.Console.Read()==13);}}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 35 bytes

```
@set s=
@set/ps=
@if "%s%"=="" %0
```

Rather unfortunately, Batch doesn't clear the variable if you don't enter anything.

Comment: I guess this crashes if `%s%` == `"`

Comment: @SteveFest Indeed, but it still stops insisting on an answer... you can probably crash-resist it by using `%s:"=""%`.

Comment: It would make a error message without the replace... Which is unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

### Kotlin, <s>38</s> <s>35</s> 29 bytes

-3 bytes by negating `any()` rather than calling `isEmpty()`
-6 bytes thanks to [Adám](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43319/ad%C3%A1m) pointing out the function doesn't need to be named to be called

```
{while(!readLine()!!.any());}
```

called like so:

```
{while(!readLine()!!.any());}()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/kotlin#RcyxDoJQDEDRvV/Rt7UL7GhM3N34gipFmmAlzSOEEL79gZPzvTn97PgRc5LmHiHrtc1h/r4xbmVbBhuVUqh0D3MlTqkSX4n5shOX6Tzz6PTvjHWN7fBdMPSnnhKaT3OuYC8AIM8XdNof)

Comment: Something wrong with your TIO link.

Comment: You just have to click the click here link to remove the message about TIO v2

Comment: In that case you could just link to https://tio.run/nexus, but why not fill in the necessary fields on https://tio.run/nexus/kotlin and get the full URL (hint: press Esc, S)?

Comment: @Adám Updated the link to use tio.run/nexus, never used TIO before :)

Comment: Nice. I think you only have to count the 29 char brace, as the function [does not need to be named in order to be called](https://tio.run/nexus/kotlin#RcyxDoJQDEDRvV/Rt7UL7GhM3N34gipFmmAlzSOEEL79gZPzvTn97PgRc5LmHiHrtc1h/r4xbmVbBhuVUqh0D3MlTqkSX4n5shOX6Tzz6PTvjHWN7fBdMPSnnhKaT3OuYC8AIM8XdNof "Kotlin – TIO Nexus").

Answer (score 1):

### [Lithp](https://github.com/andrakis/node-lithp), 90 bytes

```
((import readline)(readline "?" #A::((f A)))(def f #A::(if(== "" A)((readline "?"(get f/1)
```

[Try it online!](https://andrakis.github.io/ide2/index.html?code=KChpbXBvcnQgcmVhZGxpbmUpKHJlYWRsaW5lICI/IiAjQTo6KChmIEEpKSkoZGVmIGYgI0E6OihpZig9PSAiIiBBKSgocmVhZGxpbmUgIj8iKGdldCBmLzEp) (Also works on command line in node)

A side effect of the current parser is that not all trailing `)` brackets are required. The very last one is, but the rest can be omitted saving quite a few bytes.

The `readline` module works in browser and via command line, and uses a callback. We exploit this to call `readline` before defining `f`, and save many bytes not needed all the closing brackets to invoke `f` after it's defined.

Answer (score 1):

## [AHK](https://autohotkey.com/), 19 bytes

```
While !a
InputBox,a
```

Not very interesting, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), <s>7</s> 5 bytes

```
≈A|_?
```

Saved 2 bytes because empty string is falsy.

Explanation:

```
≈ |     WHILE <condition>
 A      A$ gets set by _? below. Empty string is false, so it stays in the WHILE
   _?   Ask the user for input, implicitly assign to A$
```

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 19 bytes

```
while gets==?\n;end
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 21 bytes

```
while(readLine==""){}
```

Scala can run code as a script without the need for a class/main method so this is a complete program.

`readLine` is deprecated since Scala 2.11 but it's still available in 2.12

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 20 bytes

```
While[Input[]==Null]
```

Answer (score 1):

### REXX, 24 bytes

```
do until n>''
  pull n
end
```

Answer (score 1):

## Tcl, 26

```
while {![gets stdin t]} {}
```

[demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_tcl_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMaDctQm15Ul9Lemc)

Answer (score 1):

### Excel VBA 25 bytes

```
while Inputbox(0)="":wend
```

You can run it via immediate window. It's  a simple while loop with inputbox.

Answer (score 1):

## Pure Bash, 21 bytes

A pure Bash solution using shift and recursion with parameter (21 bytes):

```
shift||(read a;$0 $a)
```

`shift` shifts the arguments (and defaults to shifting 1). Which fails if there is no argument, upon which it will try to execute itself again with the next read line as the first argument.

Note that double quotes are here not needed if the line contains spaces, because it does not matter if it's just one word or multiple.

#### *Notes*

In all cases I tested for empty lines, which behaves accordingly. And the following special inputs that may break the behavior (but did not ;) ):

- `-x`
- `aoeu aoeu aoeu`
- `!`

The only thing that breaks it is escaping the newline with `\`, or using a  character. But how to handle these special characters is not mentioned in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash + line, 16 bytes

Another approach using recursion with parameter (16 bytes), using `shift`:

```
shift||$0 `line`
```

`shift` shifts the arguments (and defaults to shifting 1). Which fails if there is no argument, upon which it will try to execute itself again with the next read line as the first argument.

#### *Notes*

Instead of `line` you can also use `head -n1`, which is more common (but also longer).

In all cases I tested for empty lines, which behaves accordingly. And the following special inputs that may break the behavior (but did not ;) ):

- `-x`
- `aoeu aoeu aoeu`
- `!`

The only thing that breaks it is escaping the newline with `\`, or using a  character. But how to handle these special characters is not mentioned in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 2 bytes

```
W!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pyke#@x@u@P8/FwgYAQA)

See the debug output to show it's actually reading input

```
W  - do v
 ! -  not(input())
   - while ^
```

Answer (score 1):

**Javascript, 17 bytes**

```
for(;!prompt(););
```

A for alternative to the while answer already here

Answer (score 1):

## C, 83 bytes

```c
e(char*t){*t>32?1+e(t+1):0;}
f(){size_t l;char*t;getline(&t,&l,stdin)+1&&e(t)&&f();}
```

The above answer will read full lines, and check if the read line has content beside spaces\tabs.

**shorter non-conforming version, 23 bytes**

```c
f(){getchar()-10?:f();}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 79 bytes

```java
boolean f(){System.console().readLine().replaceAll("\\t| ","").isEmpty()&&f();}
```

The above answer will read full lines, and check if the read line has content beside spaces\tabs.

**shorter non-conforming version, 38 bytes**

```java
void f(){if(System.in.read()==10)f();}
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, 31 Bytes

p[99];main(){for(;!*gets(p););}

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/c-tcc#U87MS84pTUlVsCkuScnM18uw@18QbWkZa52bmJmnoVmdll@kYa2olZ5aUqxRoGmtaV37/z8XEGTmFZSWAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 26 bytes

```python
a=""
while not a:a=input()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9FWSYmrPCMzJ1UhL79EIdEq0TYzr6C0REPz/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## Batch 31 bytes

```bat
@Set $=&Set/p$=&Set $ 2>nul||%0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APOL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/APOL), 7 bytes

`w(!(i))`

This simply repeats until i returns a non-empty string.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 4 bytes

```
T#q0
```

[Replit!](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/pip) (Leave command-line arguments blank; when prompted to enter your program, type `T#q0` followed by a newline and Ctrl-D.)

#### Explanation

```
T     Loop till
 #     length of
  q    read a line of stdin
      is truthy (nonzero):
   0   No-op
```

The shorter `Tq0` doesn't work because an input like `0` will still be falsey and fail to terminate the loop.