# Java is to JavaScript as Car is to Carpet

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem, pattern-matching

<sub>Title <s>stolen</s> inspired by [Greg Hewgill's answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/245068) to [What's the difference between JavaScript and Java?](//stackoverflow.com/q/245062)</sub>

## Introduction

Java and JavaScript are commonly used languages among programmers, and are currently the [most popular](//stackoverflow.com/tags) tags on Stack Overflow. Yet aside from similar names, the two have almost nothing in common.

In honor of one of programming's most infamous debates, and [inspired by my recent frustrations in tag searching](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/297703), I propose the following:

## Challenge

Write a program which takes in a string as input. Return `car` if the string begins with "Java" and *does not* include "JavaScript". Otherwise, return `carpet`.

## Example Input and Output

#### car:

```
java
javafx
javabeans
java-stream
java-script
java-8
java.util.scanner
java-avascript
JAVA-SCRIPTING
javacarpet
```

#### carpet:

```
javascript
javascript-events
facebook-javascript-sdk
javajavascript
jquery
python
rx-java
java-api-for-javascript
not-java
JAVASCRIPTING
```

## Notes

- Input matching should be case insensitive
- Only possibilities for output should be `car` or `carpet`
- Imaginary bonus points if your answer uses Java, JavaScript, or Regex
- Alternate Title: *Java is to JavaScript as ham is to hamster*

Comment: The new [tag:pattern-matching] tag needs a wiki. Please contribute if you can

Comment: Depending on the order things are done in, `javacarpet` might catch bugs that the existing test cases don't.

Comment: If you get `imaginary bonus points if your answer uses Java, Javascript, or Regex`, does that make such solution's bytecount complex? ;)

Comment: `Alternate Title: Java is to JavaScript as ham is to hamster` Actually, the "ham" in "hamster" _is_ cognate to the food "ham". The food "ham" is pig meat, and the term "hamster" is derived from the related animal, the guinea pig, whose meat replaced pigs meat on long sea voyages as the animals were easier to raise on a ship.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

## Java/JavaScript Polyglot, <s>108</s> <s>107</s> 106 bytes

```
//\u000As->s.matches("(?i)(?!.*javascript)java.*"/*
a=>/(?!.*javascript)^java/i.test(a/**/)?"car":"carpet"
```

### Run as Java

```java
//\u000As->s.matches("(?i)(?!.*javascript)java.*"/*
a=>/(?!.*javascript)^java/i.test(a/**/)?"car":"carpet"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJda8IwFH33V2QFoS0mFfYydCoy2HCwMebYyz4g1lSjbZLl3ooy/O2uX6jtfGhvzsm5J/fmZsU3nGoj1Gq@Pph0FsuQhDEHIE9cKvLbIqRiATlmYaPlnCTZnjtFK9Xi44twuwCvkBKyyvxYijJmUapClFqx@2pxWyZ0yjAkERkcguAz7Xa7Y6BDYAnHcCnAddyR9NzRFfNzNwitNOgVxr4T@C0@GAbN3e98HUiGAtDlge8H3sgJuXV6@d8IdA79or5j0bkSyKAqmxAnd3A65yja1vFMcAV1igJawZMmWRTVIG/quLwkCLlSwjakx75O/OP4fUynd6@Tl7fJ80Ndf@m4kqNiIxSe1RzxUMy0XtMzDczX9dyLnj@psLsTNjtcanXCdkv/XyDlRtJIW3rJUWlspOQ9Nlvc91tFzFyqB1dMrlfOzzuOb7oDFAnTKTKTqTBynfZ1F3qkDe2szELeIRHjxsQ7N0eeV76IfSv/9oc/)

Note: don't trust the highlight as it's incorrect. The real Java, properly interpreted looks like below because `\u000A` is interpreted in the very first step of the compilation as `\n`, de facto ending the comment that started with the line comment (`//`).

```java
//
s->s.matches("(?i)(?!.*javascript)java.*"/*
a=>/(?!.*javascript)^java/i.test(a/**/)?"car":"carpet"
```

### Run as JavaScript

```javascript
//\u000As->s.matches("(?i)(?!.*javascript)java.*"/*
a=>/(?!.*javascript)^java/i.test(a/**/)?"car":"carpet"
```

Credits to @CowsQuak for the JS version.

```js
let f=

//\u000As->s.matches("(?i)(?!.*javascript)java.*"/*
a=>/(?!.*javascript)^java/i.test(a/**/)?"car":"carpet"

var a=["java","javafx","javabeans","java-stream","java-script","java-8","java.util.scanner","javascript","java-avascript","javascript-events","facebook-javascript-sdk","javajavascript","jquery","python","rx-java","java-api-for-javascript","not-java"];

for(var s of a) console.log(s.padStart(a.reduce((x,y)=>x.length>y.length?x:y).length) + "=>" + f(s));
```

How many imaginary bonus points for this answer?

-1 byte thanks to [@Nevay](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132272/java-is-to-javascript-as-car-is-to-carpet?noredirect=1#comment324764_132279) in the Java answer.

Comment: This isn't competitive in JavaScript or Java. I'm not even convinced it's a serious contender, which is a requirement for all submissions.

Comment: @Dennis Thank you for your information. However I consider this as a polyglot entry. Is there any rule against polyglot entries when they aren't explicitly requested? I tried to golf this as much as possible. For instance, I tried to put both regexes together, but I couldn't get anything shorter than this (because of the two different albeit similar regexes, and their delimiter). It's also impossible to have the same variable definition because JavaScript doesn't allow a new line between `a` and `=>`. I tried to stay in the spirit of golfing. If I did something wrong, please tell me?

Comment: @Dennis IMHO "Java/JavaScript polyglot" counts as its own language, in which case this is very competitive.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I'm not saying this isn't a well-golfed polyglot submission, but it's debatable if there should be polyglot submissions to non-polyglot challenges in the first place. They came up as part of the [Can serious contenders do more than the challenge asks for?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10835/12012) discussion, but I don't think there's a clear consensus on this particular topic. Personally, [I'm not in favor.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10835/can-serious-contenders-do-more-than-the-challenge-asks-for/10846#comment35326_10846)

Comment: @Dennis Thank you for your insights, I now understand what you meant. Should this answer be tagged as "non-competitive", according to you? On the other hand, while I'm not speaking for all polyglot answers (this is my first ever), this one has the special meaning that the challenge speaks about both Java and JavaScript, and that the "imaginary bonus points" were explicitly awarded for Java, JavaScript and regex answers before I wrote this answer. Java and regex can be combined, JavaScript and regex can be combined, why not all together? Anyways, I don't mind marking this as non-competitive.

Comment: We don't mark answers anymore; for this particular reason, we never did. I'm not saying this answer isn't a serious contender (it isn't in *my personal opinion*), but if it weren't, it would have to be removed.

Answer (score 18):

## JavaScript, <s>50</s> 49 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @ValueInk by rearranging the regex*

```js
a=>/javascript|^(?!java)/i.test(a)?"car":"carpet"
```

#### Test snippet

```js
let f=

a=>/javascript|^(?!java)/i.test(a)?"carpet":"car"

var a=["java","javafx","javabeans","java-stream","java-script","java-8","java.util.scanner","java-avascript","javascript","javascript-events","facebook-javascript-sdk","javajavascript","jquery","python","rx-java","java-api-for-javascript","not-java"];

for(var s of a) console.log(s.padStart(a.reduce((x,y)=>x.length>y.length?x:y).length) + "=>" + f(s));
```

Comment: I was going to steal your regex but that would have made my answer longer :o nice answer though

Comment: Now we just need a java answer.

Comment: We have a Java answer, but... I came to the roughly same regex...

Comment: alternatively: `/^java(?!script)/i`

Comment: @Andrea Nope: fails on `"javajavascript"`.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire ah, damn, that one seems unfair

Comment: If you switch the ternary around, `/javascript|^(?!java)/i` has been working for me and is 1 byte shorter.

Comment: @ValueInk Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 15):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>92</s> <s>82</s> <s>72</s> <s>58</s> 57 bytes

```java
s->s.matches("(?i)(?!.*javascript)java.*")?"car":"carpet"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJNawIxEL37K9KAsCsmFHopWhUptFhoKbX0UnqIMavR3STNzEql@Nu3@4W6Ww@byXv75mUmk43YCWadMpvlNnPpItaSyFgAkGehDfntEFKzgALzsLN6SZL8XzBHr83q84sIv4KwlBKyyf14ijrmUWokamv4Q725qxL6VRiTiIwyYGPgiUC5VhDQYKLDYHLFe4ULSK8dhqVhj4YTKoWng2J1Cmk2LI871oAKEMioroIQWuTR/jmKfpp4oYSBJsUAvRJJmywraZG3TVz1DFIYo3xLemzmxD9NP6Zsfv82e32fvTw29ZeOqzimdsrgWc2RkGph7ZadaWC5beZe9PxOld@fsNvj2poT9j/s/wUy4TSLrGeXHI3FVkrRY7vFw7BTxtylfj/l5AbV/MLj@OZ7QJVwmyJ3uQqjgHZvrmFAutDNyyzlfRJx4Vy8DwoUhtWLOHSK75D9AQ)

1 byte saved thanks to [@Nevay](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132272/java-is-to-javascript-as-car-is-to-carpet?noredirect=1#comment324764_132279)!

Comment: You can omit the caret as String#matches attempts to match the entire string.

Answer (score 11):

## C (only calling puts), 131 bytes

```c
f(int*s){char r[]="carpet";~*s&'AVAJ'||(r[3]=0);for(;*s&255;*(int*)&s+=1)~*s&'AVAJ'||~s[1]&'IRCS'||~s[2]&'TP'||(r[3]='p');puts(r);}
```

It does have its problems, but it passes all of the testcases provided :)

```c
g(int* s)
{
  char r[] = "carpet";
  ~*s&'AVAJ' || (r[3]=0);
  for(;*s & 255; *(int*)&s +=1)
    ~*s&'AVAJ' || ~s[1]&'IRCS' || ~s[2]&'TP' || (r[3]='p');
  puts(r);
}
```

> Imaginary bonus points if your answer uses Java, Javascript, or Regex

well... no thanks

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 68 bytes

```python
k=input().lower();print'car'+'pet'*(k[:4]!='java'or'javascript'in k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9s2M6@gtERDUy8nvzy1SEPTuqAoM69EPTmxSF1bvSC1RF1LIzvayiRW0VY9K7EsUT2/CEwXJxdlFpSoZ@YpZGv@/68UADZPCQA)

-11 bytes thanks to [notjagan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/63641/notjagan)
-2 bytes thanks to [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/Dennis)

Comment: [11 bytes shorter](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHbSj05sUhdW70gtURdSyNbLye/PLVIQzPayiRW0VY9K7EsUT2/CEwXJxdlFpSoZ@YpwFVp/i8oyswr0UjTyMwrKC0BCmhyESHyPwDsEC4voKlgIhhsNAA).

Comment: [Slightly different 81 byte solution](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYSj05sUg9M02hWC8nvzy1SEMz2sok1tZWPSuxLFE9MS8FzChOLsosKFHPyy9RyMxDKE3NKU4F6S9ILVH/X1CUmVeikaaRmVdQWqKhqanJRYTI/wCwm7i8gJaAiWCwTQA)

Comment: @Justin That too. Nice.

Comment: If you switch to Python 2, you can save 2 bytes with a full program.

Comment: @Dennis Nice, thanks.

Comment: Possibly a Pythonic meta question, but since `;` saves no bytes over `\n`, should one use `\n` for readability or it visually better "golfed" if it's on one line?

Comment: @LukeSawczak It makes no difference to golfability so I choose `\n` for readability. It doesn't matter but sometimes `;` is more golfy when indents exist.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino That's true. Just noticing that you used `;` here.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Oh I didn't even realize that :P I was using Java right before that and in Java `;` is required so I since I have to use it anyway the newline is unnecessary :P That's why I used it.

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 21 bytes

```
lD'¦‚å≠sη'îáå*„¾„ƒ´#è
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATsAxP8wNWFiMWX//2xEJ8Km4oCaw6XiiaBzzrcnw67DocOlKuKAnsK@4oCexpLCtCPDqP//amF2YXNjcmlwdA)

Comment: `lD“¦‚“åi“¾„“ë“îá“åi…carë`  3 bytes more and 1 hour late :(. Nice job.

Answer (score 4):

## C#, <s>80</s> 78 bytes

```c#
s=>(s=s.ToLower()).StartsWith("java")&!s.Contains("javascript")?"car":"carpet"
```

Comment: I think the most readable language here is C#

Comment: @sepehr You mean you see sharp with C#. (Do I get a bonus for dumb comments)

Answer (score 4):

## <s>EXCEL</s> Google Sheets, <s>89</s> 86 Bytes

Saved 3 bytes thanks to Taylor Scott

```excel
=LEFT("carpet",6-3*ISERR(SEARCH("javascript",A1))+3*ISERR(IF(SEARCH("java",A1)=1,1,1/0
```

Takes an input on A1

#### Explanation

```excel
=LEFT("carpet",6-3*ISERR(SEARCH("javascript",A1))+3*ISERR(IF(SEARCH("java",A1)=1,1,1/0)))

 SEARCH("javascript",A1)        #Case-Insensitive Find, returns error if not found  
 ISERR(                         #Returns string true if error, False if not
 3*ISERR(                       #Forces TRUE/False as integer, multiplies by 3
 IF(SEARCH("java",A1)=1,1,1/0)  #If java found, returns integer. if 1, java begins string
                                #so returns 1, which will be turned into 0 by iserr.
                                #Else returns 1/0, which will be turned into 1 by iserr.
 LEFT(                          #Returns digits from the left, based upon count.
```

Comment: I believe that you can replace the `Search`es with `Find`s for -2 bytes and that that could be further translated to a google sheets formula for -3 bytes by not closing the last three parens

Comment: Find is case sensitive, search is case insensitive.  But those last 3 bytes are a good idea!

Comment: Why the swap from Excel to Google Sheets?

Comment: Removing the last 3 parens saves 3 bytes.  Excel would just throw an error and put them in for you anyways.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 27 bytes

```
,“Ẋṣ“®Ẓȷ»ŒlwÐ€/Ḅn2‘×3“¢Ẹị»ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/nUcOch7u6Hu5cDGQcWvdw16QT2w/tPjopp/zwhEdNa/Qf7mjJM3rUMOPwdGOQgkUPd@14uLv70O6HOxb/f7h7y@F2oKLI//@zEssSuUBEWgWYSkpNzCsGs3SLS4pSE3Oh7OSizIISCNsCTOmVlmTm6BUnJ@blpRZBJIAYqs7LMcxRN9g5yDMgxNPPHSyLZAKEqZtalppXUsyVlpicmpSfn62LJFWckg1WiayxsDS1qJKroLIkIz@Pq6hCF@5y3cSCTN20/CIkA7jy8ksgCkAugTsEAA)

Answer (score 3):

## Common Lisp, <s>131</s> 125 bytes

```
(lambda(s)(format()"car~@[pet~]"(or(<(length s)4)(not(#1=string-equal"java"(subseq s 0 4)))(search"javascript"s :test'#1#))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZHBTsMwDIZfxeqE5hwyMTQkhAAxcUDjgBAgLhMHt3O3si7p4nTqLn31kbJ2dIckv5XPjv0nyTMpDphbW0BqHVSQGRhi9EM7iuDvSKtWxExGWq3FO6bNKUpcVvguumnFqPRZPpKEjGHXXYZ1ol@mX1P98fQ@e/ucvT63REKu4K7WWeFjoHnHxjeNpJRwbO1a9y5lsW7p8/RtyW4fRLH3K2uCcJXuDampyHQwQJ9lGes7qGn1v1O1sBjoDXnwENVX1wT6AWqqL6JgIQZDaRMvCEW1GKoozFU/zsNo9XeE1uEd5myWfgWiJgrDUzgY3wdbM7PUvC0pP34CShkLb0HgEiZKKRQml6z67gjcehY/HIwHAVCHqtl@AQ)

Size reduced thanks to the [#n=](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dho.htm) “trick” of Common Lisp.

**Explanation**

```
(lambda (s)                 ; anonymous function
  (format                   ; use of format string to produce the result
    ()                      ; the result is a string
    "car~@[pet~]"           ; print "car", then print "pet" when:
    (or (< (length s) 4)    ; the string is less then 4 characters or
        (not (string-equal "java" (subseq s 0 4)))     ; does not start with java or
        (search "javascript" s :test 'string-equal)))) ; contains javascript
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina),  <s>44</s>  37 bytes

```
Ai`^(?!.*javascript)java
.+
pet
^
car
```

*Thanks to @MartinEnder for golfing off 7 bytes!*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5BD4IwDIXv/RceTFAzzt4M8UDwYIwaj4SCJU50m9sg8OtnGAZ3ab@0r69Pk@UC3TJKC5fwIo92i3j9xA5NpbmyqxEh3oAiCzlUqJ3zo7HUvW8loTCemLGa8P1jbzDx1re4tfwVmwqFID0t5kdwSG4Ju@zP2emaHVP4RwiQUUfCGqixolLKhgUrc2@8Mjz8tKQHUIN9SAG6Z3NyhoqzWurAAIS0k2BMMgf5Ag)

Answer (score 3):

## vim, 58 bytes

```
gUU:s/.*JAVASCRIPT.*/Q/g
:s/^JAVA.*/car
:s/[A-Z].*/carpet
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/Pz001KpYX0/LyzHMMdg5yDMgRE9LP1A/nQsoGgcSBHKTE4tA3GhH3ahYCLcgteT//6zEskTdxIJM3bT8Il0Qpzi5KLOgBAA)

Comment: I think using the `g` command might be a little shorter, something like `:g/\cjavascript/d` `:g!/^\cjava/d` `icarpet␛:s/pet..*`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 42+1 = 43 bytes

Uses the `-p` flag.

```ruby
$_="car#{"pet"if~/javascript|^(?!java)/i}"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9NT8MwDIbv@RUm9LBJSytuCGmbph2mcUAIEEemNKRa2OYEJ51W8fHTCWuKSi/xE72284TqsomODAYYZTnM4ArmkBVwA2j24wlkm1xt7cFNgMN0BjxmmylXki4/uNOBm@q7eJNH6RUZFz5fRvOL9jouzBePsUXWHtUplVJL9ImED6Tl4Y/TcMfXqeR1MPvcK4moqQv6R9jt4nkhHpcP6/un9d0qpWehsw37Nxmg0EeNwbNKKl1auxODyL/uUudw8L3W1DDXhK1FRifRf0JIZ0RlabCAoQ1dQyvVO/1YF4xFH4X7BQ)

Answer (score 2):

## C (tcc), <s>144</s> 136 bytes

```c
a;f(s){char*t=s;for(;*t;a=!strncmp(s,"java",4))*t=tolower(*t++);for(t=s;*t;)s=strncmp(t++,"javascript",10)&&s;puts(a*s?"car":"carpet");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZFBTwMhEIXv/RWVQwPbpdHEg5FsTOPB1IMxarxPkU3XdgFhWts0/e0r201TisuBhG/eG@aB5Chl04AoqWd7uQCXYeFFaRwVGQoorjw6LWtLfU6@YQMkv2UsaNCszK9yNMPxmB31rS9YmC9OllDqTF66yiLJb67ZaOSFXaOnkPkHIsGR@3a3CgkTh6bSOKyh0pQN9oNhWCXtrmUiPpbbBMwVaJ8wHuZQUP@j3TAJvUvAZI3VauIlaK1cKj5HOheep59T/v74Nnv9mL08nQrHqKQ9xQ16R@ggVxulMY5SglRzY5Y8EvmvZeLub/uzVm4XAbvDhdERcFve87wcbMXDn/LertpgamrDX2Q/NH8)

**Unrolled:**

```c
a;
f(s)
{
    char *t = s;
    for (; *t; a = !strncmp(s, "java", 4))
        *t = tolower(*t++);
    for (t=s; *t;)
        s = strncmp(t++, "javascript", 10) && s;
    puts(a*s ? "car"  :"carpet");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 69 bytes

```python
f=input().lower().find
print'car'+'pet'*(f('java')!=~f('javascript'))
```

Currently 1 byte longer than the shortest Python 2 solution.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVCxbsMgFNz5Cjo90wgPnapUHqIOUTpUVVt1x/ih0DhAAafO0l93MVitB3gn3XHcPXeNR2vuJmU9DVQbCgDkU1xEvtSYR4vChIx4iB7FecHSaxcLvs@jHqLu6yCFMegLkc6ie9p97Pjb4@vh5f3wvM@sFN5hcViZFcjxgiYGooTE1toTX1GhO2Xl@uHXgP5KXO5D/Mj/SnDhNE/9VgbE2FgEc6j/TKl8HVyvY8W2aRluiLShvTi3ndjS8EBxRDlvaFJNZitW9/YbfZpKm444r02E1Ao2kIrBbaUqmP8BdtP8LLhEAMam2ekX)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 76 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from range `[A1]` and outputs is `car`/`carpet` status to the VBE immediate window

Does not use RegExp

```vba
?"car"IIf(InStr(1,[A1],"Java",1)*(InStr(1,[A1],"JavaScript",1)=0),"","pet")
```

Comment: Nice use of vba! I thought a macro would have been shorter. Now I have proof.

Answer (score 1):

## [JAISBaL](https://github.com/SocraticPhoenix/JAISBaL), 36 [bytes](https://github.com/SocraticPhoenix/JAISBaL/wiki/JAISBaL-Character-Encoding)

```
℠℘(?!.*javascript)^java.*}͵Ucar½Upet
```

Verbose/explanation:

```
# \# enable verbose parsing #\
tolower                           \# [0] convert the top value of the stack to lowercase #\
split (?!.*javascript)^java.*}    \# [1] split the top value of the stack by (?!.*javascript)^java.*} #\
arraylength                       \# [2] push the length of the array onto the stack #\
print3 car                        \# [3] print car #\
!if                               \# [4] if the top value on the stack is falsy, skip the next statement #\
print3 pet                        \# [5] print pet #\
```

JAISBaL was my first attempt at designing a golfing language, so it's rather quirky... there's no matches or contains, regex or otherwise, so instead we have to split and check the resulting array length... because JAISBaL has a split-by-regex... but no other regex support.... because reasons.

Regex <s>stolen</s> borrowed from [@Cows Quack's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/132276/56085).

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 84 bytes

```
="car"&IF(AND(ISERR(SEARCH("javascript",A1)),IFERROR(SEARCH("java",A1),2)=1),,"pet")
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 95 bytes

```python
g=lambda s:(lambda r:'car' if r[:4]=='java' and 'javascript' not in r else 'carpet')(s.lower())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rdU9T8MwEAbgnV9xm@PBWWBAkTJUDBAGhACxIAYncVqnqW3Obml/faDhI6TqQn2ZvPjR@c6v43ZhYc1538/zTq7KWoLPku8VZqySyEA3gC/ZxWues1ZuJANpahiWvkLtAgNjA2gDCKrzCva7nAqMJz7t7LvChPPeoTYhmSdsoRnnEP@d/Yo3RVFQmKM4HJNcbLbx5lQslTQ@Ep2KwgdUchVlHopfl4RQvKTuY7oOukt9JY1ReCJ@UOOYjpNrHcXb2fNMPF49FPdPxd01hbiv8SemnKyPBKM@Kgq1USb46Mk0slKltUvxh/b18t/utMaWdNbt21rhjvKGu@GNpxRxK0ieyMPMOC0aiyKioaP4@U8iKXKawkkI@w8)

Yeah, it could be shorter but I wanted to try using a nested lambda!

Comment: Always good to experiment :) Note that you can save bytes around operators like `and`, `or`, `if`, `else`

Answer (score 1):

### [Perl](http://www.perl.org), **42 bytes**

I believe the answer by stevieb has an incorrect output (tried that one myself - it returns car for 'javajavascript'). This should work:

```
say/^java/i&&!/javascript/i?'car':'carpet'
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Bracmat](https://github.com/BartJongejan/Bracmat), 66 bytes

```
(f=.pet:?b&@(low$!arg:(? javascript ?|java ?&:?b|?))&str$(car !b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU/BbsIwDP2VgKouOSTnCQlliAOCw4TYtLuTJVCgSZa4DCT@vWvTCXqxn/Xes59VBF0Dti21cxEMzqQq3@jZ/xYTiPsZleQIF0g6VgGJvPcDkWWnukvGyoSxoBoimSjG2hpCQelc@AYLm/1M7A2@sDbb@mKvuSkDLmXEuxUG6n88nMn4lUz7LhqsziJpcM7E6UA9A20WXwv@sdytt5/r91VmuzTdG@PUT8jNxThMxII2yvsTH1Hp@5SVY@NPY@KNhBsevCPxyh9vcAgVtz6OFhDncRD0oR6Z/gA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 134 bytes

```go
import."strings"
func f(s string)string{T,o:=ToLower,"car"
if Contains(T(s),"javascript")||!HasPrefix(T(s),"java"){o+="pet"}
return o}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jZHPSgMxEMbxOk8RA8IGNz2XQoVS_FMRKXXxVLDpNqmxbbIm2drS9upLeCmCL-FzeNGnMbupZREEL_mGmck3v2ReXsd6-56xdMLGHM2YVABylmnjaljMHH7LnaD1z-efnHVGqrHFIHKVIhFZFDIkyCqJdaOZ6Cv9xE2MU2YwSIHaWjlvbaMksiTGD2zObGpk5jBZrw8vmO0aLuSiUsZkpY-bOOMOb8BwlxuF9CbQfB18lNML2oigFYCfgxpNdCb5dGSjQWEAxSEWpQw5U7aMqMfkbLaLS4QQ10up5U5OazZlSnETCntUuGzdtuhNu9fpJp3r87Lq53rCAQF__gaouIeQ8jlXzoJgKR9qPaGVkh1Nys7qxcecmyVkS3evFZgF3b-KskxSoU3FAJR2oaGg3EN6Muj6vbipijClFLVbPeQVE_D30V1sC2rDlN998Yer0C0ifGT7ru-aJ8gHCsfIxsWyCYFNxbGvdp7d0-Qv2-Jn_mW7W-52G_Qb)

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), <s>53</s> <s>49</s> 44 bytes

```
{32|}%"java"/(,\{6<"script"=+}/"carpet".3<if
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v1rP0tDG2EhLu1ZVKSuxLFFJX0MnptrMRgmiQMlWu1ZfKTmxqCC1REnP2CYz7f9/L6Cy4OQirYISAA)

This was my second GolfScript submission so after writing a couple more I was able to revisit this and shave a couple bytes.

Previously, this mapped over a list, then summed it, then added it to a base value. Now, it just loops over the list, adding to the base value on each iteration.

Here's an explanation of how the code works:

```python
{32|}%           # Convert the string to lowercase

"java"/          # Split on "java".
(,               # Extract the first item, and push its length
                 # (0 iff string starts with java).
\                # Swap so the rest of the list is on top of the stack.

{6<"script"=+}/  # Check if any start with "script":
{            }/  #   Loop over each item:
 6<              #     Take the first 6 characters.
   "script"=     #     Are they equal to "script"? (0 or 1)
            +    #     Add this to the top of the stack.

# After this loop, the stack will be 0 iff the string started
# with "java" and does not contain "javascript".

"carpet".3<     # Push "carpet" and its first 3 characters.
if              # If the value is 0, "car", otherwise "carpet".
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 88 bytes

```lua
s=io.read():lower()print(s:sub(1,4)=='java'and not s:find'javascript'and'car'or'carpet')
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704pzRxwYKlpSVpuhY3I4ptM_P1ilITUzQ0C4oy80o0iq1y8stTizQ0rYpLkzQMdUw0bW3VsxLLEtUT81IU8vJLFIqt0jLzUsBixclFmQUlIBn15MQi9fwiEFWQWqKuCTEfas2CJSDFEDYA)

Comment: Fails for input `Javascript`, but moving the call to `:lower()` to just after `io.read()` seems to fix it. Also, you can save 3 bytes by removing the whole concatenation of `'car'` and just doing `and'car'or'carpet'`.

Comment: Just FYI this is still wrong after your edit, the `:lower()` needs to be moved to just after `io.read()` so cases like `JAVASCRIPTING -> carpet`  work correctly

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 82 bytes

regex

```
If[#~StringMatchQ~RegularExpression@"(?i)(?!.*javascript)^java.*","Car","Carpet"]&
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, <s>98</s> <s>84</s> 62 Bytes

```
sub a{"car".($_[0]=~/javascript/i||$_[0]!~/^java/i?'pet':'');}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@4NEkhsVopObFISU9DJT7aINa2Tj8rsSyxOLkos6BEP7OmBiyqWKcfBxLWz7RXL0gtUbdSV9e0rv1fUJSZV6KQqKEEklMAExCNSprW/wE)

Thanks to bytepusher

Comment: Welcome to the site! I don't know any perl, but it looks like there is a lot of whitespace you could remove. Also, if you're looking for more ways to shorten it, there's a bunch of tips [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5105/31716).

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Thank you, I think the entire logic can be changed to make it even shorter, but I haven't figured it out

Comment: Just some hints (without changing your solution too much):
You can replace the `return $b;` with just `$b;`. Perl always returns the last evaluated statement. Since we don't care about warnings, you can even drop the ';' to `$b}`. You don't need the brackets around the if. If you use `||` instead of `or`, you can save a whitespace after the regex.

Comment: You can also remove the () around the first lc, but need a space after if then. If you use `!~` instead of `! =~` the second condition can be `lc$_[0]!~`. ` -> `sub a{$b="car";$b.="pet"if lc$_[0]=~/javascript/||lc$_[0]!~/^java/;$b}`. Using the ternary ops brings it down one more
`sub a{$b="car";$b.="pet"if lc$_[0]=~/javascript/||lc$_[0]!~/^java/;$b}`

Comment: Not to forget - no need for lc when you have the regex ignore case switch,
down another 2 :) `$_[0] =~//i||$_[0]!~//i`. And finally, why a variable?
`sub a{"car".($_[0]=~/javascript/i||$_[0]!~/^java/i?'pet':'');}`
should do fine :). And now: perl will be nice and let you use $_[0] w/o specifying it (though not with `!~`): `sub a{"car".(/javascript/i||!/^java/i?'pet':'')}` -> 48 :)

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 91 bytes

```
@set/ps=
@set t=%s:~0,4%
@if "%t:java=%%s:javascript=%"=="%s%" (echo car)else echo carpet
```

Takes input on STDIN. Batch doesn't have a case insensitive comparison operator but it does have case insensitive string replacement so I can assign a temporary to the first four characters and then case insensitively replace java, which should then result in the empty string. Meanwhile I case insensitively replace javascript in the original string, which should leave it unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, 96 bytes

```lua
function(x)return x:lower():match"^java"and not x:lower():match"javascript"and"car"or"carpet"end
```

Answer (score 0):

## Dart VM, <s>104 bytes</s> 102 bytes

```
main(p){p=p[0].toLowerCase();print("car${p.indexOf('java')==0&&p.indexOf('javascript')<0?'':'pet'}");}
```

**Explanation**:

Degolfed:

```
main(p)
{
    p = p[0].toLowerCase();
    print("car${p.indexOf('java') == 0 && p.indexOf('javascript') < 0 ? '' : 'pet'}");
}
```

We have our usual main function

We replace `p` with `p[0].toLowerCase();` so that we don't have to declare a new variable (`var` plus a space would be 4 extra bytes)

We then proceed to do the actual printing

We print `car` unconditionally and we use inline statements for checking whether to print `pet` after it or not. If it has the string 'java' at index 0 and does not have 'javascript' in it, we do nothing (we actually append an empty string but it does not have any effect) and otherwise we append `pet`.

Answer (score 0):

## Rust, 97 bytes

```
let s=if Regex::new(r"^javascript|^!java$").unwrap().is_match("javascript"){"carpet"}else{"car"};
```

I'm pretty sure that there is a shorter solution but it's my first try :)

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 81 bytes

```powershell
$a={param($s)$s.StartsWith('java')-and(!s.contains('javascript'))?'car':'carpet'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxBCsIwEEX33qIQmGRhDyCIh@jC9ScNJKUmw8ygSPHs0eDm895bfG6vJJrTvvfucD0Ygod3GpzOi0FM78Wypw1PUDijrn7SObZqKFX/XaMUNgrhRhFCl7GcjD7jkaLmn9JpML8tt0q9fwE)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 38 + 1 = 39 bytes

```perl
$_=car.pet x!(/^java/i*!/javascript/i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3jY5sUivILVEoUJRQz8uK7EsUT9TS1EfxChOLsosKNHP1Pz/H8RNy0mt4EKI/8svKMnMzyv@r@trqmdgaPBftyAHAA)

Answer (score -1):

## [Perl](https://www.perl.org/), 36 bytes

```perl
say/^java(?!script)/i?"car":"carpet"
```

Run it as such:

```perl
perl -nE 'say/^java(?!script)/i?"car":"carpet"' java.txt
```