# Triangle a number!

Tags: code-golf, number, array

We are used to the term "squaring" *n* to mean calculating *n<sup>2</sup>*. We are also used to the term "cubing" *n* to mean *n<sup>3</sup>*. That being said, why couldn't we also triangle a number?

## How to triangle a number?

- First off, let's pick a number, `53716`.
- Position it in a parallelogram, whose side length equals the number of digits of the number, and has two sides positioned diagonally, as shown below.

  ```
      53716
     53716
    53716
   53716
  53716
  ```
- Now, we want to ∆ it, right? To do so, crop the sides that do not fit into a right-angled triangle:

  ```
      5
     53
    537
   5371
  53716
  ```
- Take the sums of each row, for this example resulting in `[5, 8, 15, 16, 22]`:

  ```
      5  -> 5
     53  -> 8
    537  -> 15
   5371  -> 16
  53716  -> 22
  ```
- Sum the list `[5, 8, 15, 16, 22]`, resulting in `66`. This is the triangle of this number!

## Specs & Rules

- The input will be a non-negative integer *n* (*n ≥ 0, n ∈ Z*).
- You may take input and provide output by [any allowed mean](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).
- Input may be formatted as an integer, a string representation of the integer, or a list of digits.
- [Default loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) disallowed.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!

## More Test Cases

```
Input -> Output

0 -> 0
1 -> 1
12 -> 4
123 -> 10
999 -> 54 
100000 -> 6
654321 -> 91
```

---

[*Inspiration.*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136564/square-a-number-my-way) Explanations are encouraged!

Comment: are you sure that `645321 -> 91` ?

Comment: @Rod Sorry, you are right. I wrote `645321` instead of `654321`.

Comment: Can I take input as a list of digits?

Comment: @totallyhuman Yes, see the second spec.

Comment: Interesting challenge.  Glad you were inspired by mine!

Answer (score 17):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 13 bytes

```hs
sum.scanl1(+)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P822uDRXrzg5MS/HUENb839uYmaegq1CQVFmXomCikKaQrSZjqmOiY6xjpGOYex/AA)

Takes input as list of digits. Calculates the cumulative sums then sums them.

Answer (score 12):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), <s>65, 50,</s> 36 bytes

```
([])({<{}>{<({}[()])>[]}{}<([])>}{})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/XyM6VlOj2qa61q7aRqO6NlpDM1bTLjq2trrWBiRlB2Ro/v9vqGCkYAwA)

After lots of revising, I'm now very proud of this answer. I like the algorithm, and how nicely it can be expressed in brain-flak.

Most of the byte count comes from handling 0's in the input. In fact, if we could assume there were no 0's in the input, it would be a beautifully short 20-byte answer:

```
({{<({}[()])>[]}{}})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X6O62kajujZaQzNW0y46tra6tlbz/39DBSMFYwA)

But unfortunately, brain-flak is notorious for bad handling of edge cases.

## Explanation

First, an observation of mine:

If the input is *n* digits long, the first digit will appear in the triangle *n* times, the second digit will appear *n-1* times, and so on onto the last digit, which will appear once. We can take advantage of this, since it's really easy to calculate how many digits of input are left in brain-flak, namely

```
[]
```

So here's how the code works.

```
# Push the size of the input (to account for 0's)
([])

# Push...
(

    # While True
    {

        # Pop the stack height (evaluates to 0)
        <{}>

        # For each digit *D*...

        # While true
        {

            # Decrement the counter (the current digit we're evaluating), 
            # but evaluate to 0
            <({}[()])>

            # Evaluate the number of digits left in the input
            []

        # Endwhile
        }

        # This whole block evaluates to D * len(remaining_digits), but 
        # without affecting the stack

        # Since we looped D times, D is now 0 and there is one less digit.
        # Pop D (now 0)
        {}

        # Push the stack height (again, evaluating it as 0)
        <([])>

    # End while
    }

    # Pop a 0 off (handles edge case of 0)
    {}

# end push
)
```

Comment: My tip [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127942/56656) can save you [two bytes](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X0MjOlazOrq6NrbaRqO6NlpDM1bTLjq2troWJAGkNP//N1QwUjAGAA "Brain-Flak – Try It Online")

Answer (score 12):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>4̷</s> 2 bytes

Thanks @H.PWiz for `-2` bytes!

```
Σ∫
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9ziRx2r////H22qY6xjrmOoYxYLAA)

#### "Ungolfed"/Explained

```
Σ    -- sum all
 ∫   -- prefix sums
```

Answer (score 11):

## Pyth - <s>6</s> 4 bytes

```
ss._
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ss._&input=5%2C3%2C7%2C1%2C6&debug=0).

Nice 6 byte one that doesn't use prefix builtin:

```
s*V_Sl
```

Comment: Nice!  The best I could come up with is twice as long: `s.e*bhk_`

Answer (score 10):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 3 bytes

```
Yss
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P7K4@P//aFMdBWMdBXMdBUMdBbNYAA)

Takes the input as a list of digits.

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 25 bytes

*Takes input as list of digits*

```hs
f[]=0
f x=sum x+f(init x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/Py061taAK02hwra4NFehQjtNIzMvs0ShQvN/bmJmnm1BUWZeiUpatKmOsY65jqGOWex/AA)

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 41 bytes

*Takes input as string representation*

```hs
f[]=0
f x=sum(map(read.(:[]))x)+f(init x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/Py061taAK02hwra4NFcjN7FAoyg1MUVPwyo6VlOzQlM7TSMzL7NEoULzf25iZp5tQVFmXolKmpKpsbmhmdJ/AA)

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
+\S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/187Jvj////RZjqmOiY6xjpGOoaxAA) Uses the same technique as my Japt answer: cumulative addition, then sum.

Comment: Oh, of course! :)

Answer (score 7):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>7</s> <s>6</s> 4 bytes

```
å+ x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///BSbYWK//@jzXRMdUx0jHWMdAxjAQ)

#### Explanation

```
å+ x    Implicit: input = digit list
å+      Cumulative reduce by addition. Gives the sum of each prefix.
   x    Sum.
```

---

Old solution:

```
å+ ¬¬x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///BSbYVDaw6tqfj/X8nU2NzQTAkA)

#### Explanation

```
å+ ¬¬x   Implicit: input = string
å+       Cumulative reduce by concatenation. Gives the list of prefixes.
   ¬     Join into a single string of digits.
    ¬    Split back into digits.
     x   Sum.
         Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Comment: Uh sandbox much? Or you read the question, wrote code and posted it all within one minute?!

Comment: @JonathanAllan This was not sandboxed. It is much easier than you might think.

Comment: Uh, well I cant even read the question in the time it took

Comment: @JonathanAllan No sandbox reading, just happened to catch the question just after it was posted and come up with an algorithm almost immediately.

Comment: Welp it took me ~4min to read the question, so +1 for speed-reading/speed-understanding :)

Comment: It's really not as hard as it looks: I just looked at the example and noticed that he was just summing of the digits of each prefix

Comment: Yeah - exactly what I did in my answer.

Answer (score 7):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 28 bytes

```
(([]){[{}]({}<>{})<>([])}{})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X0MjOlazOrq6NlajutbGrrpW08YOJFQLZP3/b6hgpGAMAA)

*14 bytes if we don't need to support zeros (which we do)*

```
({({}<>{})<>})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X6Nao7rWxq66VtPGrlbz/39DBSMFYwA)

DJMcMayhem has a cool answer [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137651/56656) you should check out.  Unfortunately for him I wasn't about to let him win at his own language :P

### How does it work?

Lets start with the simple version.

```
({({}<>{})<>})
```

The main action here is `({}<>{})<>`, that takes the top of the left stack and adds to to the top of the right stack.  By looping this operation we sum up the current stack (until it hits a zero) placing the sum on the off stack.  That's pretty mundane, the interesting part is that we sum up the results of all these runs as our result.  This will calculate the desired value.  Why?  Well lets take a look at an example, `123`.  On the first grab we just get 1 so our value is 1

```
1
```

On the next grab we return 1 plus the 2

```
1
1+2
```

On the last run we have all three together

```
1
1+2
1+2+3
```

Do you see the triangle?  The sum of all the runs is the "triangle" of the list.

---

Ok but now we need it to work for zeros, here I used the same trick as DJMcMayhem, plus some fancy footwork.  Instead of looping until we hit a zero we loop until the stack is empty.

```
([])({<{}>({}<>{})<><([])>}{})
```

I then used [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/95403/tips-for-golfing-in-brain-flak/127942#127942), written by none other than yours truly, to golf off another 2 bytes.

```
(([]){[{}]({}<>{})<>([])}{})
```

And there we have it.  I would be surprised if there was a shorter solution,  but then again stranger things have happened.

Comment: `Unfortunately for him I wasn't about to let him win at his own language :P` I expect nothing less from you. :D

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (ES6), 28 bytes

```
a=>a.map(d=>t+=c+=d,t=c=0)|t
```

Takes input as a list of digits.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 37 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:len(n)and sum(n)+f(n[:-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIc8qJzVPI08zMS9Fobg0F8jSTtPIi7bSNYzV/F9QlJlXopGmEW2mY6pjomOsY6QDFNb8DwA)

Comment: ...Why the downvote?

Comment: I think you could change `len` to `sum` as well, though I don't believe that helps anything.

Comment: @ETHproductions Yeah. I was hoping I could make use of the fact that `sum([])` is 0, but nothing was quite coming together... there might be a way though

Comment: Didn't see this otherwise I'd have given you my improvement.

Comment: @JonathanAllan No worries :P

Comment: Funny that I ended up with a similar one only that it takes string and is longer.. :D

Answer (score 5):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 59 bytes

```cs
using System.Linq;N=>N.Reverse().Select((d,i)=>i*d+d).Sum()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZBBS8QwFITv@RXvmGgsu64KEtuL4En34B48LHuI6bMG2tc1SVck9LfX0LWyXQYC32QYHmP8lWkdDp23VMHmxwdsFDul7NnSl2KkG/R7bRAoMlNr72EfmQ86WANPHZkHS2G7k@ktIDirqaoR8mGdF@vsFQ/oPHKRbbBGEzgvpRV5YS/KyzKZXcPFoKa2Q2tLeNGWuIhsbN3uQLvKQw6E3/BnRfYPcdHLE1rOSV6fs1zNnHuZdJZZTJr5d/JW3shValj2rFeMfaTxtPnk4zdQ17yjS9nx3HT9Y0u@rTF7czZgGhL5NA0/ZoVQrD9q@AU)

Substantially different from the other C# answers. Input is a list of digits. All test cases included in the TIO link.

Could save a bunch of bytes if allowed to take input as a backwards list of digits with leading 0.

Comment: Nice idea! Some fierce codegolfing in C#.

Comment: Nice solution! But isn't the input specified to be a non-negative `number`, not a list of digits?

Comment: @IanH. Rule 2: You may take input and provide output by any allowed mean. When it comes to the format, you can take the input as an integer, as a String representation of the integer or as a list of digits.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 35 bytes

I just noticed that this is only really a slight golf of [Business Cat's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137654/53748) in the end though!

```python
f=lambda a:a>[]and sum(a)+f(a[:-1])
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NUxLCsIwFFzrKd6uCU6haW3FgL1IyOJJDRZsWtq48PQx8cPA/GBmeYX77JsY3eXB03VgYs29sewH2p6TYHlwgo0ulZXRzSuF2xZo9CRMiwYnKHQWZKpMCvVP0GRzRsK3qf7IsUOLY1rXSK96v1vW0QeRn0FF2Rcg90lSxjc)**

Comment: Funny that I ended up with a similar one only that it takes string and is longer.. :D

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
1#.+/\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuo2CgYAXEunrOQTo@bv8NlfW09WP@a3KVJIPkDRSsFQzB2AhKGgNpSzAE8Q3g0FrBTMFUwQQob6RgyMWVmpyRr6BhaKCmrKegEa2jrqBrB7QsVlNNyUohTVPBwU4BaMF/AA) Takes a list of digits, such as `f 6 5 4 3 2 1`.

### Explanation

The current explanation is same as the old, but noting that `1#.x` ⇔ `+/x` (both compute sum).

Old:

```
[:+/+/\    (for explanation, input = 6 5 4 3 2 1)
      \    over the prefixes of the input:
     /         reduce:
    +              addition (summation)
           this gives is the cumulative sum of the input:  6 11 15 18 20 21
[:         apply to the result:
  +/           summation
           this gives the desired result:   90
```

A little more true to the original problem would be `[:+/@,]/`, which is "sum" (`+/`) the flattened (`,`) prefixes of the input (`]\`).

Comment: [6 bytes](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuo2CgYAXEunrOQTo@bv8NlfW09WP@a3KVJIPkDRSsFQzB2AhKGgNpSzAE8Q3g0FrBTMFUwQQob6RgyMWVmpyRr6BhaKCmrKegEa2jrqBrB7QsVlNNyUohTVPBwU4BaMF/AA)

Comment: @south excellent spot

Answer (score 4):

## [Vim](https://vim.sourceforge.io/), <s>60</s> <s>59</s> 32 keystrokes

Thanks a lot @CowsQuack for the tip with the recursive macro and the `h` trick, this saved me 27 bytes!

```
qqYp$xh@qq@qVHJ:s/./&+/g⏎
C<C-r>=<C-r>"0⏎
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/v7AwskClIsOhsNChMMzDy6pYX09fTVs/nctZyFZIyYDr/38zUxNjI0MA)

#### Ungolfed/Explained

This will build the triangle like described (only that it keeps it left-aligned):

```
qq       q    " record the macro q:
  Yp          "   duplicate the line
    $x        "   remove last character
      h       "   move to the left (this is solely that the recursive macro calls stop)
       @q     "   run the macro recursively
          @q  " run the macro
```

The buffer looks now like this:

```
53716
5371
537
53
5
```

Join all lines into one and build an evaluatable expression from it:

```
VH             " mark everything
  J            " join into one line
   :s/./&+/g⏎  " insert a + between all the characters
```

The `"` register now contains the following string (note missing 0):

```
5+3+7+1+6+ +5+3+7+1+ +5+3+7+ +5+3+ +5+ +
```

So all we need to do is append a zero and evaluate it:

```
 C                " delete line and store in " register
  <C-r>=       ⏎  " insert the evaluated expression from
        <C-r>"    " register "
              0   " append the missing 0
```

[image: inside vim]

Comment: You can use `&` (the whole match) instead of `\1` in the substitute command

Comment: `qqYp$xq:exe"norm".col('.')."@q"⏎` can become `qqYp$xh@qq@q`. This recursive macro will encounter a breaking error when there is one character on the line, after which it will stop.

Comment: So the substitution can just become `:s/./&+/g`. Also `:%j⏎` can become `V{J`. And, `Di` can become `C` (I've already commented about this in another one of your Vim answers). [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/v7AwskClIsOhsNChMKzay6pYX09fTVs/nctZyFZIyYDr/38zUxNjI0MA "V – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 19 + 1 (`-p`) = 20 bytes

```perl
s/./$\+=$p+=$&/ge}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YX09fJUbbVqUAiNX001Nrq///NzM1MTYy/JdfUJKZn1f8X9fXVM/A0OC/bgEA)

**How?**

$\ holds the cumulative total, $p holds the total of the digits on the current line.  Each line of the parallelogram is simply the previous line with the next digit of the number appended.  Therefore, it is the sum of the previous line plus the new digit.  This iterates over all of the digits, calculating the sums as it goes.  The actual substitution is irrelevant; it's just a means to iterate over the digits without creating an actual loop.  At the end, $\ is printed implicitly by the `-p` option.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>49</s> 45 bytes

*-4 bytes [thanks to Mr. Xcoder.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39234534#39234534)*

```python
lambda n:sum(-~i*n[~i]for i in range(len(n)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU3NCsIwGLvvKXJs5RO2@QMKe5LaQ8VWC@u3sdaDl716tUVBCEkICZlf6TFxn91wyaMJ15sBn@MziO3qN6xWr920wMMzFsN3K0bLgqWUOdmYIgYo1WqC6ioR@p8SdsWeCAXftP1HyY6EA2H/KddJp3XTzIvnhGBm4Qj1RuY3)

Takes input as a list of digits.

Answer (score 3):

## Bash + GNU utilities, <strike>32</strike> 24

```bash
tac|nl -s*|paste -sd+|bc
```

Input read from STDIN.

Update: I see the input may be given as a list of digits.  My input list is newline-delimited.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vyQxuSYvR0G3WKumILG4JBXIStGuSUr@/9@Uy5jLnMuQy4wLAA).

#### Explanation

```bash
tac                       # reverse digit list
   |nl -s*                # prefix line numbers; separate with "*" operator
          |paste -sd+     # join lines onto one line, separated with "+" operator
                     |bc  # arithmetically evaluate
```

Answer (score 3):

## APL, 4 bytes

```
+/+\
```

This takes the input as a list of digits, e.g.:

```
      (+/+\) 5 3 7 1 6
66
```

Explanation

```
+/    sum of
  +\  partial sums of input
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 20 bytes

Takes the input as a list of digits.

```
a->a*Colrev([1..#a])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D9R1y5Ryzk/pyi1TCPaUE9POTFW839iQUFOpUaigq6dQkFRZl4JkKkE4igppGkkamrqKERHm@ooGOsomOsoGOoomMUCRUDYEEzoKBjBaKAiENNSRwGEoKIGyAgkZqajADTOBGwiUIthLNAJAA)

---

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 15 bytes

Takes the input as a polynomial. For example, `5*x^4 + 3*x^3 + 7*x^2 + x + 6` means `53716`.

```
a->(a+a')%(x-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzBCsIwEER/ZSiISbsBkzSVHOyPiMJeKgWRUDzEr4@bUMHD8nZmdifxtppHKgsuKGxmxQMf9UFlY3XhlJ4fxTAz0ra@3rJ2VXRYFGtNuIY@30cM8EIvPAudMMtMhBPBUhNO0BLXV@kJcT@NzYg1D4RJ3CD6Vzzuxb7/f7c3Xb4)

Answer (score 3):

## [Taxi](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/), 1478 bytes

```
Go to Post Office:w 1 l 1 r 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to Chop Suey.Go to Chop Suey:n 1 r 1 l 4 r 1 l.[a]Switch to plan "b" if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.Go to Zoom Zoom:n 1 l 3 r.1 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.Go to Starchild Numerology:w 4 l 2 r.Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.Go to Addition Alley:w 1 r 3 r 1 r 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.Go to The Babelfishery:n 1 r 1 r.Go to Chop Suey:n 6 r 1 l.Switch to plan "a".[b]Go to Addition Alley:n 1 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.[c]Go to Zoom Zoom:n 1 l 1 r.Go to Cyclone:w.Pickup a passenger going to The Underground.Pickup a passenger going to Multiplication Station.Go to The Babelfishery:s 1 l 2 r 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Multiplication Station.Go to Multiplication Station:n 1 r 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.Go to The Underground:n 2 l 1 r.Switch to plan "d" if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Addition Alley:n 3 l 1 l.Switch to plan "c".[d]Go to Addition Alley:n 3 l 1 l.[e]Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.Go to Zoom Zoom:n 1 l 1 r.Go to Addition Alley:w 1 l 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.Switch to plan "f" if no one is waiting.Switch to plan "e".[f]Go to Zoom Zoom:n 1 l 1 r.Go to Addition Alley:w 1 l 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.Go to The Babelfishery:n 1 r 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Post Office:n 1 l 1 r.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZTNboMwDMdfxeIBkKBdD711O@y0rVK3yxCHNAkQLY1RCGJ9eha@Okb5UCvtABHE/tv@OY4h36IsnxEMwh4zA29RJCjfFuCBtI@uVncv6FeeAoGUZBlXMdcQo1Bx5fWUYAqHnJ/dRuXyvVWdP6xbnYCEh0IYmlSGqSQKnKMDIgKFgIqDyKAgwljl2ZDvCYdHcuQyElnCdRf5E/FUv@rIElagXa@nCcTAwRBNEyEZvOYnrlFi3LmPbVkOa6vkW6W5hHaM2QioYCflBcTfnzVRXeXUUrlDcVj3hbAeYb9pmQ@BE8cNjuFoig02f6nhZypts9yAhuPce/k0pttisZ0finEda8wVm7V9yaURqRSU1HnbnlXrFJ@sLWiZ96zu@GZLfwnXZCd7JVspvwU3bBe7Yz66Dk00eVWHuj4Z1J4MFi44BTy8udrpAzIyI/LW2RiWEU0QG9pxW24U/kuGExfUzPzOqfXuZff6pv5NuCw3D@uV7/0A)

Un-golfed:

```
[ Pickup stdin and split into digits ]
Go to Post Office: west 1st left 1st right 1st left.
Pickup a passenger going to Chop Suey.
Go to Chop Suey: north 1st right 1st left 4th right 1st left.
[a]
[ Count the digits ]
Switch to plan "b" if no one is waiting.
Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.
Go to Zoom Zoom: north 1st left 3rd right.
1 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.
Go to Starchild Numerology: west 4th left 2nd right.
Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
Go to Addition Alley: west 1st right 3rd right 1st right 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
Go to The Babelfishery: north 1st right 1st right.
Go to Chop Suey: north 6th right 1st left.
Switch to plan "a".
[b]
Go to Addition Alley: north 1st left 2nd left.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
[c]
[ Multiply each digits by Len(stdin)-Position(digit) ]
Go to Zoom Zoom: north 1st left 1st right.
Go to Cyclone: west.
Pickup a passenger going to The Underground.
Pickup a passenger going to Multiplication Station.
Go to The Babelfishery: south 1st left 2nd right 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Multiplication Station.
Go to Multiplication Station: north 1st right 2nd left.
Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
Go to The Underground: north 2nd left 1st right.
Switch to plan "d" if no one is waiting.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Go to Addition Alley: north 3rd left 1st left.
Switch to plan "c".
[d]
Go to Addition Alley: north 3rd left 1st left.
[e]
[ Sum all the products ]
Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
Go to Zoom Zoom: north 1st left 1st right.
Go to Addition Alley: west 1st left 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
Switch to plan "f" if no one is waiting.
Switch to plan "e".
[f]
[ Output the results ]
Go to Zoom Zoom: north 1st left 1st right.
Go to Addition Alley: west 1st left 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.
Go to The Babelfishery: north 1st right 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.
Go to Post Office: north 1st left 1st right.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 79 bytes

```
	N =INPUT
D	N LEN(1) . D REM . N	:F(O)
	X =X + D
	Y =Y + X	:(D)
O	OUTPUT =Y
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9NPwdbTLyA0hMsFyPRx9dMw1FTQU3BRCHL1BdJ@nFZuGv6aXJwRCrYRCtoKLlyckQq2kUBWBKeVhosmlz@nf2gIUDtQkMvVz@X/f1Njc0MzAA)

Input from stdin, output to stdout.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 56 bytes

```python
lambda x:sum(i*int(`x`[-i])for i in range(1,1+len(`x`)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHCqrg0VyNTKzOvRCOhIiFaNzNWMy2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw1DHUDsnNQ8kramp@R8uG22gA5QyAiJjHUtLSx1DAxDQMTM1MTYyjLXiUigoApqqkKmjrmunrpOmkan5HwA)

Comment: [54 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHCqrg0V0O3LlMrM69EI6EiIbouM1YzLb9IIVMhM0@hKDEvPVUjJzUPJKWpqfkfLhNtoGOoY2gERMY6lpaWOoYGIKBjZmpibGQYa8WlUFAENFEhU0dd105dJ00jU/M/AA) or [45 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHCqrg0V0O3LlOrIrouMzYtv0ghUyEzT6EoMS89VSMnNU@jQlNT8z9cPNpAx1DH0AiIjHUsLS11DA1AQMfM1MTYyDDWikuhoCgzr0QhU0dd105dJ00jN7FAAyigk5CZADQGAA) with input as lists oft digits.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>5</s>  4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ṛæ.J
```

A monadic link taking a list of decimal digits and returning the triangle of the number that list represents.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzlmHl@l5/f//P9pQxwAGYwE)**

#### How?

```
Ṛæ.J - Link: list of numbers (the decimal digits), d   e.g. [9,4,5,0]
Ṛ    - reverse d                                            [0,5,4,9]
   J - range(length(d))                                     [1,2,3,4]
 æ.  - dot-product            (0*1 + 5*2 + 4*3 + 9*4 = 58)  58
```

Comment: I had thought removing `€` would still work. Pity...

Comment: @ETHproductions ...and yet there's a built-in to help!

Comment: ...okay, wow...

Comment: @ETHproductions ooops had to reverse it >_<

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 53 bytes

I implemented a lambda for each acceptable input type. They each iterate through the number's digits, adding the proper multiple of each to an accumulator.

### Integer as input (53 bytes)

Lambda from `Integer` to `Integer`:

```java
n->{int s=0,i=1;for(;n>0;n/=10)s+=n%10*i++;return s;}
```

### String representation as input (72 bytes)

Lambda from `String` to `Integer`:

```java
s->{int l=s.length(),n=0;for(int b:s.getBytes())n+=(b-48)*l--;return n;}
```

### Digit array as input (54 bytes)

Lambda from `int[]` (of digits, largest place value first) to `Integer`:

```java
a->{int l=a.length,s=0;for(int n:a)s+=n*l--;return s;}
```

- -7 bytes thanks to Olivier Grégoire

Comment: a->{int l=a.length,s=0;for(int n:a)s+=n*l--;return s;} 54 bytes for the array version.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 13 bytes

```
.
$`$&
.
$*
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX49LJUFFjQtIaXEZ/v9vamxuaMZlwGXIZWgERMZclpaWXIYGIMBlZmpibGQIAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation: The first stage generates all the prefixes of the original number, the second stage converts each digit to unary, and the third stage takes the total.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 49 bytes

```
Tr@Array[Tr@s[[;;#]]&,Length[s=IntegerDigits@#]]&
```

Comment: You can take the input as a list of digits. `#.Range[Length@#,1,-1]&`

Comment: Improving @alephalpha 's solution: `#.Range[Tr[1^#],1,-1]&`

Comment: `Tr@*Accumulate`

Answer (score 2):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 3 bytes

Explanation:

```
        Get prefixes of input, including itself
        Implicitly join elements together, and create an array with all the digits
        Sum
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//8PcCdOBuAmI1/z/b2psbmgGAA)

Alternative answer:

Explanation:

```
       Get prefixes of input, including itself
        Join
        Implicitly convert to a digit array, and sum
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//8PcCdOBeDEQr/n/39TY3NAMAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), <s>9</s> 6 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

```
ąĐŁř↔·
```

Explanation:

```
                 Implicit input
ą                Convert to array of digits
 Đ               Duplicate digit array
   Łř↔           Create a new array [len(array),len(array)-1,...,1]
      ·          Dot product with digit array
                 Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp, <s>53</s> 52 bytes

```
(loop as(x . y)on(reverse(read))sum(+(reduce'+ y)x))
```

Input as list of digits.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpLCsAgDEXRrbxZE4RCv/sR60CwKqYWu/rU0T2D62KQolRqSI9SzLnACnXM@Dgnqv71VfyovZil3WSGr@b8ZMbRmZWVThzYsWHFwj8)

-1 byte thanks to @ceilingcat.

Comment: @ceilingcat, some Common Lisp compilers will actually fail when `apply` is applied against very long lists because of the [`call-arguments-limit`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_call_a.htm#call-arguments-limit).

Answer (score 2):

### **Python 3,  <s>94</s>   <s>58</s>   54 bytes**

Thanks to [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder) for helping me save quite some bytes!

```
lambda n:sum(int(v)*(len(n)-i)for i,v in enumerate(n))
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM9ZNBtP/S2xj/uck5ialJCrkWRWX5mpk5pVolGlqaeSk5mnkaepmaqblFylk6pQpZOYppOaV5qYWJZakAmU0/xcUgdSWaCiZmZoYGxkqAYUA)

Takes input as a string. It simply multiplies each digit by the number of times it needs to be added and returns their sum.

Comment: Nice first answer, but please make your submission a serious contender by removing unnecessary whitespace, and making all variable / function names 1 byte long. [69 bytes](https://tio.run/##Lco5CoBADEDR3lMEq4kLuBeCJxEL0VEDEkMYC08/Llh9@Dy53HZwmU5fvZ/tAs5wItgGsBwKBMSgI6/W7JYNI7YSd8QP6mnA6L8pYQBq3akM4kVf4EzY1FVZ5GGSIfob)

Comment: [58 bytes](https://tio.run/##Hco5CoAwEEDRqwSrGU3AvRC8iU3UiAEzhjgKnj4u1S/e9zevO1Vq@hu5H@Km3ThrQdJ3x@nAEsOFKWyGgFBZXPYgrLyEJWHodCZoNq9g5qMP382QtE1dlUUic8T4AA).

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Thanks. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: [You may not assume that it will always be called with `0`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11925/66833). If `p` must always be `0`, you should replace the `p` with `p=0` in the `lambda` declaration. However, you can just remove `p` entirely to get [54 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM9ZNBtP/S2xj/uck5ialJCrkWRWX5mpk5pVolGlqaeSk5mnkaepmaqblFylk6pQpZOYppOaV5qYWJZakAmU0/xcUgdSWaCiZmZoYGxkqAYUA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 13 bytes

Takes a list of digits

```perl6
{[+] [\+] @_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwvzpaO1YhOgZIOMTX/i9OrFRI0zDVMdYx1zHUMdP8/x8A)

Perl 6 has a [produce](https://docs.perl6.org/type/List#routine_produce) routine, which can be more tersely invoked using the 'triangle reduce' meta operator: `[\ ]`. Seems like it was made for this task.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
¦∑
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiwqbiiJEiLCIiLCIxMDAwMDBcbjY1NDMyMSJd)

#### Explained

```
¦∑
¦  # cumulative sum
 ∑ # sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>54</s> <s>48</s> 40 bytes

```powershell
param($a)$a|%{$o+=$_*($a.count-$i++)};$o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVRUyWxRrVaJV/bViVeC8jXS84vzSvRVcnU1tastVbJ////v4OGmY6pjomOsY6RjqEmAA)

Takes input as a list of digits.

Note that the output is just the input digit multiplied by its corresponding negative index in the string and then cumulatively summed. So, that's what we do here.

We loop over each element in the input list, each iteration perform a multiplication, and then sum the results together into the total `$o+=`. That's left on the pipeline, output is implicit.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

#### Code

```
ηSO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3PZg////zUxNjI0MAQ)

#### Explanation

```
η      # Take the prefixes of the number
 S     # Split into single numbers
  O    # Sum all the numbers
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 34 bytes

```js
f=(n,i=1)=>n&&n%10*i+f(n/10|0,i+1)
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=(n,i=1)=>n&&n%10*i+f(n/10|0,i+1)

console.log(f(0)) // -> 0
console.log(f(1)) // -> 1
console.log(f(12)) // -> 4
console.log(f(123)) // -> 10
console.log(f(999)) // -> 54 
console.log(f(100000)) // -> 6
console.log(f(654321)) // -> 91
```

Comment: Literally exactly what I had. However I do also have a 1-byte-shorter solution taking input as a string...

Comment: @ETHproductions Ah, I first tried with a string but ended up with something longer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), <s>4</s> 3 bytes

```
…_Σ
```

Function accepting a list of digits and leaving the result on the stack.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz//1HDsvhzi/@nPmqb@D/aTMFUwUTBWMFIwTAWAA)

#### Explanation

```
…    Prefixes
 _   Flatten
  Σ  Sum
```

Comment: Crossed out 4 is still 4 :(

Comment: What's the footer for?

Comment: @Okx Each line in Gaia is a function (like Jelly), so the footer  is just calling it.

Comment: So, why doesn't it work without the footer?

Comment: @Okx Because I haven't yet made it detect a list from the input format, so I have to eval it (`e`) first

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 80 bytes

```cs
n=>{int v=0,i=0;for(;i<n.Length;)v+=int.Parse(n[i]+"")*(n.Length-i++);return v;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY1NS8NAEIbv@RVDTrumDf1QIWzTi@CpQsGDh9LDsk7SgWa2zG4DUvLbY2pQETzoexiYd56HcWHqvGDPtsFwsg7BJZcEhrijDQG24muxzUcz9teEaCM5aD29wpMlBhWiENe7PVipg/4Cv5Vrnt9CxCZ/PLNbjcIEiOMaKih7LteXYYG2nE2onJnKizK04nyDXMeD0W1WDvd8ayWg4h3tszTVN@oTmFKWaSMYz8LQmq43v/1@8Bz8EfMXoYgbYlSVSueLZar13/miKP7F39/dLhfzH0qXjLPr3wE)

Takes a string as input and outputs the triangled number.

---

Explanation:

For each character in the input string, convert the `char` to an `int` and multiply it by *the length of the string minus the index of the `char`*.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/)**, 58 bytes**

```
lambda n:sum(-~i*int(c)for i,c in enumerate(str(n)[::-1]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPqrg0V0O3LlMrM69EI1kzLb9IIVMnWSEzTyE1rzQ3tSixJFWjuKRII08z2spK1zBWU/N/QRFIbZqGqbG5oZmmJheMb4DENkRmG6FwjJF4lpaWyHIGIIAkYGZqYmwENOo/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>84</s> 68 bytes

```cs
a=>a.Select((x,i)=>a.Take(i+1).Sum(c=>c-48)).Sum()
```

Byte count also includes

```cs
using System.Linq;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU9NT8MwDL37V5hbLLZqWbdBNVoJIXGCC0XiHGUeRKQpNCkfQvvtJVmBsafIjp9fnmPtp7rteOi9cY9Yf/rATXZj3OsawKmG/YvS/MPDF2CEtsp7vNzfRybBBxWMxrfWbPBWGSfor3UQJVz3Tl/40MV5EzQuVLjFclBlpbKaLesgxMfEUKrv1TMLcyopq/tG6LLS08U5jRUN8Yf/fUfLlNZH/PuTsYxCxAaWeNU631rO7lht4posiPCkRNdbS0fPEn7FD50JvFdvkw3RYcIOxrgblvmZXMEMJMh5PDkURQFylgCr5SKfy28)

Explanation:

```cs
a=>                     // Take a string
    a                   // Take the string as collection of chars
    .Select((x,i)=>     // Replace the collection with
        a.Take(i+1)     // Substrings increasing in size
        .Sum(c=>c-48))  // Sum each substring's digits (as ints) together
    .Sum()              // Sum the new collection of sums
```

I know <s>it's a little bigger than</s> there's already posted C# answer, but mine is coming from a different approach so I thought I will post it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

### [TXR Lisp](http://nongnu.org/txr), <s>67</s> 40 bytes

```
(opip digits reverse conses flatten sum)
```

Run:

```
1> (opip digits reverse conses flatten sum)
#<intrinsic fun: 0 param + variadic>
2> [*1 53716]
66
```

Note that if we take advantage of the input being a list of integers representing digits, this reduces to:

```
(opip reverse conses flatten sum)
```

and if the digits may be in reverse order already, then just

```
(opip conses flatten sum)
```

Note also that this is a "useless use of `opip`"; all the terms are function names, and so `[chain digits reverse conses flatten sum]` could be used, and that would be the recommended way to code this; it's just one character longer.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>51</s> 55 bytes

*+4 bytes—original version failed on all inputs with 0 as a digit.*

```php
<?php while($x!=$d=array_pop($argv))$t+=++$p*$d;echo$t;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go0ChPCMzJ1VDpULRViXFNrGoKLEyviC/QEMlsSi9TFNTpUTbVltbpUBLJcU6NTkjX6XE@v///6b/jf@b/zf8bwYA)

EXPLANATION:

```php
<?php
```

The programme takes separate digits as CLI parameter arguments, which arrive in the code as an array, `$argv`.

Each character at a time is popped from the end of the array. When the array is empty `array_pop` returns `null`. Null is detected by comparing the result to an undeclared variable `$x`, a saving of 2 code bytes over using `null` itself. *(Without this comparison any 0 digit evaluates to `false` and the loop ends early.)*

```php
while ($x != $d = array_pop($argv))
```

`$p` is the position from the end *i.e.* the last digit (the first one popped) is in position 1. `$p` is 
undeclared and so equals 0, but is incremented *before* it is used each time, so starts off as 1.

The position is multiplied by the digit and added to the total `$t`.

```php
    $t += ++$p * $d;
```

The final result is printed.

```php
echo $t;
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 46 bytes

- Takes in string, returns integer

```python
f=lambda a:a and sum(map(int,a))+f(a[:-1])or 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIdEKiPNSFIpLczVyEws0MvNKdBI1NbXTNBKjrXQNYzXzixQM/hcUAcUV0jTUzUxNjI0M1TX/AwA)

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 32 bytes

```
->a{b=a.pop;a[0]?b+a.sum+f[a]:b}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6xOsk2Ua8gv8A6Mdog1j5JO1GvuDRXOy06MdYqqfZ/gUJadLSpjrGOuY6hjlls7H8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 56 bytes

```python
lambda a:sum((i+1)*int(a[-i-1])for i in range(0,len(a)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzBCsIwEETvfsXektUEklQLKeiP1B5WbHShTUusB78@Jh4cmMeDgVk/23OJLofzNU803@4E1L3es5R8sLjnuEnqNWs7YFgSMHCERPExSqOmMUpCxPxfemGEErbW/dAUeu@rm5oi7enYOCuGbgdrKv/ASuiLUEEy5i8)

Some edit as suggested by @Mr.Xcoder

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 50 bytes

```python
lambda a:sum(-~i*int(a[~i])for i in range(len(a)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHRqrg0V0O3LlMrM69EIzG6LjNWMy2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1VIyc1TyNRU1PzP1w8Wt1AXUfdEISNwIQxkLS0tASxDUAAyDAzNTE2MlSPteJSKCgCmq2QqaOua6euk6aRqfkfAA)

Comment: [50 bytes (-6 bytes)](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHRqrg0V0O3LlMrM69EIzG6LjNWMy2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1VIyc1TyNRU1PzP1w8Wt1AXUfdEISNwIQxkLS0tASxDUAAyDAzNTE2MlSPteJSKCgCmq2QqaOua6euk6aRqfkfAA). `(i+1)` means bitwise `-~i`, thus requiring no brackets and `-i-1` is just `~i`, again bitwise. `range(0,len(a))` is equivalent to the unary range `range(len(a))`.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA Immediate Window, 60 bytes

```
a=StrReverse([A1]):For i=1 ToLen(a):b=b+i*Mid(a,i,1):Next:?b
```

Input is in cell `A1` of the active sheet. Output is to the VBA immediate window.

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure, 26 bytes

```
#(apply +(reductions + %))
```

There's a built-in, but in standard Clojure fashion, it's a long-ass word. Takes input as a list of digits.

Comment: Can you add a testing link or instructions on how to run it?

Answer (score 1):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), <s>31</s> 21 bytes

```
{i=0{[i]if i+=_}|sum}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzNDsIgEITP8hSbpgeMmkD/Ekzw7jOoaRstSmIpAXpqeXYsuJfZ@TIzZnr1YUE7AWcO97BITpabfEgB8sBbv9p59MGjsZcKtpjVX@mwHTTP4HSBbA8rLPD89MZiqfTsItCbG67KDe/B4DYSgRM3Ujnc5S1wyKfZbfFuDx7EZCCVj/CnyAcS5wmiUSiiRdRq0zIBghhj8asrQJTEi65BTV2VRSox@gM)

Takes the input as a stream of digits.

### 31 bytes

```
{addHead 0|reduceSteps _+_|sum}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzLCoMwEEXXzVdcxEVKW0h8gQW7btfdFjSY2ApVQxJX6rdbY2dz5x7mjBmkWCdyaHAt8FonIeVdCQk2GyXHWj2d0hblqZzt2C3rQjrR9tgEq7@to1bpIsDlhuCIGRPqjzCWtr0enQd6a@rRO/VWhpaeNHTnpu0drcISBcJhdNt5dcSCZjDY5TP@lCwr8@8Z4T444ZHPZMt4B4zkee63NAHhzI9vGcnSJI52Kec/)

Takes the input as a stream of digits.

Explanation:

```
{addHead 0|reduceSteps _+_|sum} /* An anonymous function */
 addHead 0                      /* Append 0 to the beginning of the stream */
          |reduceSteps _+_      /* Create a cumulative sum */
                          |sum  /* Sum all numbers in the stream */
```

The `reduceSteps` function does not return the first item in the stream, so it is necessary to add a zero at the head of the stream.

Answer (score 1):

### TI-BASIC, 4 bytes

```
sum(cumSum(Ans
```

Takes a list of digits as input, and calculates the sum of the cumulative sum (i.e. prefix sum) of the list.

The cumSum( token is 2 bytes large.

Answer (score 1):

## [Math++](https://pastebin.com/mnxZk1cz), 56 bytes

```
?>n
n>g
o+g%10>o
_(g/10)>g
3+3*!g>$
_(n/10)>n
2+6*!n>$
o
```

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 57 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from the range `[A1]`, and outputs the triangle sum described above to the VBE immediate window

```vba
l=[Len(A1)]:For i=1To l:s=s+Mid([A1],i,1)*(l+1-i):Next:?s
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 64 bytes

```
def f(s:String)=s.indices.flatMap(i=>s.take(i+1).map(_-'0')).sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 106 bytes

```
a=input()
c=[]
d=0
b=[int(g) for g in a]
for i in range(1,len(a)+1):
    c+=b[0:i]
for t in c:
    d+=t
print(d)
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##JYwxCoQwEABr9xUps8RCsRP2JcEiJppbONYQ1sLXxwvXDcMw5dHPJUtrgVjKrRYhkt8g0QQ7eRa1Gc15VZMNiwkbdObONUg@7Dx@D7EB3YwrDNHR7qeV/5n2LP50cqRQar8lbO0F)

My original code was:

```
a,c,d=input(),[],0
b=[int(g) for g in a]
for i in range(1,len(a)+1):
    c+=b[0:i]
for t in c:
    d+=t
print(d)
```

But then I realized that by initializing all of my variables on one line, I gained two characters. :P

Comment: Ah Ah Ah! I am not the loser!

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), <s>11</s> 6 bytes

```
L~,¬+s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/9@nTufQGu3i////R5vqKBjrKJjrKBjqKJjFAgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org) 29 bytes

```
f=->n{*a,b=n;b ?n.sum+f[a]:0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcxNDoIwEAXgfU8xgY0/lbQIJMWgB2m6AClaEtFQMDGlZ69Q9O2@9ybTj9XHuaY4nDuzK3FVdKcKLl2kx8e@4aXIiXUccYJhDREYcfoX9Yp/TFYdPam/ZIx5petGlsxFtihLk2M8v2JUIBHJ8nqH@gmTwtBOCEBBASqq1U0NOurlW/ZazvVrHDQEoVE2h9A0XAkLm9C0dhsg2dXuCw)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 75 bytes

```r
function(x,b=nchar(x))sum(sapply(x%/%10^(0:b),function(y)y%/%10^(0:b)%%10))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZqP7P600L7kkMz9Po0InyTYvOSOxSKNCU7O4NFejOLGgIKdSo0JVX9XQIE7DwCpJUweuulKzEklcFcjS1PxfUJSZV6KRpmFqbG5oBuT/BwA)

---

I did not see an R solution yet, so here goes..

Comment: [49 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfZqP7P600L7kkMz9Po0KzuDRXI7k0F0RVqOqrGhrEaRha5SVnJBYBJXUNNVWBQpqa/wuKMvNKNNI0TI3NDc2A/P8A "R – Try It Online") -- I had actually solved this but it was a snippet rather than a full program/function so yours is better.

Comment: @Giuseppe 51 bytes: `sum(cumsum(as.numeric(el(strsplit(scan(,""),"")))))`, but your version is 2 bytes shorter...

Comment: @AndreïKostyrka we can join forces and get to [47 bytes!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7g0VyO5NBdEaVTYFicn5mloaqrqqxoaxGkYWuUlZyQWaVRo6hpqqgKFNDX/mxqbG5r9/w8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$2\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 1.646 bytes

```
Sk
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJTayIsIlsxLCAyLCAzXSJd)

```
Sk # Takes a list of digits as input
 k # Prefixes
S  # Sum of the automagically flattened list
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>10</s> 8 bytes

```
+/+\.'$:
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs9LW147RU1ex4uJKizY1Njc0iwUyzExNjI0MQSxDI2MQZWlpGQsA36wKWw==)

*-2 bytes thanks to ngn*

Pretty basic train.

Explanation:

```
+/+\.'$:    Main function. Takes implicit input with Right (:)
      $     Convert input to string
     '      For each of the characters
    .       Eval them, converting them into a number
  +\        Cumulative sum
+/          Sum
```

Comment: for converting to digits, `.'` works too

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3) `s`, 1 byte

```
@
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyJzIiwiIiwiQCIsIiIsIjY1NDMyMSIsIjMuNC4xIl0=)

yay

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>51</strike> 50 bytes

-1 byte thanks to @ceilingcat

```c
i,r;f(t,l)int*t;{for(;l;)for(i=--l;~i;)r+=t[i--];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdLBaoQwEAbgu08xLCwk3RFMotGS2hdJPYiLS8BuS/Am9tVtjLqtAdccAv/ELyGZJr41zTQZtKolPXbU3PuXXg3tlyWqU3SeTRnHnfoxitpL2WsTx5Uap8/a3AmNhgjc5/6CmumsghKGDAXmyFCOyhdbQmaV1gwho0v2bV1EfIJgXehTWybqz@OaeS8JHY5sz3AEdsiIlWEhI0JGPGNSzRcGeQilyPdQisAPoUyLDUIRUu7u9pS7HnFIyZV6RTdCSoaUfEblWq6nSrYRgjnKPZgjyEOwWEGJGaauI9yjhWARgsUDHKNoyeaVUKM3u2WyW9f55nSBcfskyk1v0Cm4XAz15WXRg2/J6Xw9IdTaVOu2YxT9L0P8Dufrx/20nmH6BQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 97 bytes

```
proc T n {time {incr s [expr [regsub -all (.) $n +\\1]]
regsub .$ $n "" n} [string len $n]
set s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxBCoMwFET3/xSDuGgpFaPVYs/hLmZhJYgQ05BEKEjOnibQYVZvmOcXFaOxnwUjNE6/7RLnphcLBy6/xoJbubrjjfusFC7VFaXGbZqYEPRfqjKzooAO4M7bTa9QUicoyEkPF6LaZ5P91LVP1lNNjFiT2tIwDCBW51DfPdqGUcBpDu/S/8XHbAnxBw)

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 105 bytes

```
proc T n {time {incr s [expr [join $L +]]
set L [lreplace $L e e]} [llength [set L [split $n ""]]]
set s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU29CoMwGNy/pzjErYvRarHP4OgWMkj4aFNiDEkKBfHZ0wgexw3H/SRtc/Zh05jhsCezMnbjdECE5J8PkJ/NONQTbkpR5IQJ0gb2dtF82gxWR7Esu1d6Q16R6K1JqB2qSl3FeGS7Lv78ob57iIEaEiTawo7GcQSJ5gQN/b1rBR3Y/TfFMvKUc1F15D8)

Comment: Failed outgolf: **108 bytes**: https://tio.run/##PU1LCsIwFNy/U8zChSJKX2sr9RzdpV3UGkohjSFJQSg5e0wQHGY1Xz@pGI19T@igsftlldgXPVk4CPkxFsLK2W1PXEalcLyecNA49z0PAznpU0k4bxc9w47ZKiD168JD@OtK6mT80i5EtY4mX1Fd3bmhgpi4TKyobVsQFxnU1LeqZArYzeZd6j9El1dC/AI

Answer (score 0):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 8 bytes

```
IEh@+:@+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/39M1w0HbykH7/39TBWMFcwVDBTMA)

Input format is space-separated digits.

#### How it works

```
IEh@+:@+

I         Take next input as number
 E        If last input was EOF...
  h       Print the top as number and halt
          Otherwise...
          The stack looks like [sum_of_digits triangle digit]
   @      Move 3rd from top (sum_of_digits) to the top
    +     Add top two (update `sum_of_digits`)
     :    Duplicate top
      @+  Add `sum_of_digits` to `triangle`
          Repeat from the beginning
```

Answer (score 0):

## EXCEL, 55 bytes

Using Immediate Window.

```
[A65:A89]="=MID(REPT(CHAR(ROW())&CHAR(ROW()+1),2),1,3)"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 60 bytes

```sh
f(){echo $((${(j:+:)${(@f)$(for i in $@;echo $((x+=i)))}}))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/TUOzOjU5I19BRUNDpVojy0rbShNIO6Rpqmik5RcpZCpk5imoOFjD1FRo22ZqamrW1gLx/zQFMwVTBRMFYwUjBcP/AA)

Takes input as individual parameters

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, 14 bytes

```factor
[ cum-sum Σ ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5BDoIwEEX3PcX3ABBAIEETt8aNG@PKuGhqjV0UkE4XhnAa7@OVKmkRdf5q3puZzJULajp3POz22xU0p1tsiJMypIQJva2VaC4SbSeJHm2naoKRdytrIQ3WjPUMY/VIMMDXAtEGyUTTP5rONJu4x/kPXgYRxj9XKp@vKHLMK8mcIchyUiUK5OO9zD/hVZWygbkThNWRsRqvJ85O8xaxewM)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `S`, 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ƒʂ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0UrBS7IKlpSVpuhZLjk061bSkOCm5GCqwYJmZqYmxkSGEBwA)

##### Explanation

```python
ƒʂ  # implicit input  ->  654321
ƒ   # preƒixes        ->  [[6], [6,5], [6,5,4], [6,5,4,3], [6,5,4,3,2], [6,5,4,3,2,1]]
 ʂ  # ʂum each list   ->  [6, 11, 15, 18, 20, 21]
    # sum this list   ->  91
    # implicit output
```