# Asterisks viral

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, random

Given a positive integer *N* ("virality"), your program should create an ASCII-art drawing of a tree with two branches of length *N* extending downwards and/or rightwards from the top-left corner.

The direction taken by each branch *after the first asterisk* can be either rightwards or downwards, and this choice should be made *randomly*<sup>1</sup> at every next step.

For example, given an input of 5, the output might look like:

```
***
* ***
**
 **
```

The two branches are allowed to touch (be on adjacent cells), but not overlap (be on the same cell), so the following would not be allowed:

```
***
* *
*****
  *
  *
```

### Examples

For input `1`, the only possible output is:

```
**
*
```

(This will be present in all valid outputs, since having the two branches take the same path would cause them to overlap.)

Possible outputs for an input of `3` include:

```
***
* *
**
```

```
**
***
*
*
```

For input `7`:

```
****
*  **
*   **
*
***
  *
```

For input `10`:

```
****
*  *      
*********
  *
  *****
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest valid answer (in bytes) wins.

<sup>1. This should uniformly random (i.e. a 50/50 chance of each direction),
 or as close to uniformly random as you can get on normal hardware.</sup>

Comment: Please comment if you're having any problems with consuming my long post - maybe I can shorten something (I'll try then).

Comment: Just learn to expect that. Sometimes it's busy as all heck. Other times it's quiet like it is now. Don't forget, it's also Easter.

Comment: I am not really sure what is wrong with my post. Would the one who downvoted be so kind to explain, please?

Comment: @EsolangingFruit ok, this makes me think that something in the wording is also unclear, right? As for the name: by looking at the front page, you can see that it looks like he name of my previous question, i.e. rhymes, which was actually intended :)

Comment: @esolang oh and i've edited it too, feel free to dismiss/roll back my edit (i am not editing further not to confuse you again), sorry!

Comment: Thank you very much for spending your time to improve my post, @EsolangingFruit! Are you sure that the illustration is irrelevant and the test case can be interpeted with ease without the image?

Comment: @nicael I didn't find it a problem. It might be helpful to add a similar image after the very first example.

Comment: @EsolangingFruit why did you edit out "Trailing spaces/newlines/whatever invisible are allowed." and "You don't have to handle inputs less than 1."? The former is rather crucial to the spec and the latter was still helpful.

Comment: @O.O.Balance The former is implied by the tag [ascii-art] ([this meta consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5515/61384) establishes that [ascii-art] is intended to produce a certain *appearance*, not necessarily an exact byte stream). The latter is implied by the term "positive integer" at the start.

Comment: @EsolangingFruit thanks for the [ascii-art] link. Still figuring out all the places on this site where rules are specified.

Comment: @O.O.Balance ... Mostly hidden around [meta].

Comment: Both [those versions](https://tio.run/##hY5NDgIxCIX3PcVL3GjixgN4GJziDKZDmxbn5/QjGuPChbIAArzH1xK1gdu27XB@B@4q11xHkIGpG9CMyxGVb9yZZEWjsSTR/qMIYaKKJcQcgAUfh7Siksb8bHpWrmQcUcgGzOIpsfZe9noI8yCJXSsNohMliaFUUXPX8BetWZXOvnGcg8di6@thcBnERydYhjrnCxbgxVijX19W37m/@fgHzbY9AA) can be considered "uniformly random" at each step, while they _may_ produce different resulting distribution. Are they equivalent or which one do you want?

Comment: @user I think they are equivalent, I would accept any

Comment: IMO _N_ is better described as time :P

Comment: FYI, after some discussion in chat we concluded that those 2 methods produces different distribution.

Comment: Because harder challenges receive fewer answers. Don't worry too much about that...

Comment: @user202729 thanks for infotmation! I don't really care about the distribution, if all the theoretically possible outputs are possible in the actual solution.

Comment: Consider editing the challenge to relax the restriction (which is not well-defined as pointed out)... Besides, it appears that many existing answers doesn't satisfy that anyway.

Comment: Can we return a matrix of `0`s and `1`s instead of spaces and asterisks?

Answer (score 5):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>58</s> 51 bytes

```
[TT]{_2_m*\f.+{:-},mR}ri*]ee{~\)S*\{'*t}/}%::a:.+N*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/PzokJLY63ig@VysmTU@72kq3Vic3qLYoUys2NbW6LkYzWCumWl2rpFa/VtXKKtFKT9tP6/9/QwMDAA)

The basic idea is that we start with `[0 0]` and then repeatedly add either 0 or 1 to each element (making sure that they are never equal except at the start to avoid overlap), collecting all intermediate results.

```
[[0 0] [0 1] [0 2] [0 2] [1 3]]
```

We then create a large array of arrays where each subarray contains `*` at indices given by the corresponding pair in the original array and spaces everywhere else.

```
["*"
 "**"
 "* *"
 "* * "
 " * * "]
```

This yields diagonal slices of the output matrix (where moving left to right corresponds to moving top-right to bottom-left in the actual matrix).

We can then use `::a:.+` to "de-diagonalize" and get the resulting lines:

```
[ "**** "
  "*  *"
  "** "
  " *"
  ""     ]
```

Answer (score 3):

## Java 10, <s>273</s> <s>272</s> <s>268</s> 239 bytes

```java
n->{var c=new char[++n][n];for(var d:c)java.util.Arrays.fill(d,' ');for(int i=0,j=0,k=0,l=0,r=0,s=0,t=0,u=0;n-->0;){c[i+=r][j+=s]=c[k+=t][l+=u]=42;do{r=t=2;r*=Math.random();t*=Math.random();s=r^1;u=t^1;}while(i+r==k+t&j+s==l+u);}return c;}
```

Try it online [here](https://tio.run/##nVLBjtMwED2nX@ETtfE2agtcMF6JI4e9sBKXYCTjpK1d11mNJ1lWVb692MnShaWAxGE80vjN8/ObcbrXC1fvT3fdV28NMV7HSG60DeQ4K2zABjbaNOSTBe1zqTA7DZWqFOlziSYICUzMimFWPHJE1JhS39qaHBITvUWwYZtaNGwjG1kmvpGCSHIKi@tjr4EYGZp7Mj7BeVBVUGLTAs1X9VvDXFJbdmh9@R5AP8RyY72n9dWczNkIzGqsXF65FPsUPgWkiCkwRSeXIiwW10vBjqayXIKqHJdRSVPtuURVeS47JV@vRd0eQaJcC3gpbzTuStChbg@UCXxeiBK@rEQnMZ3D/c76hloOUu45vnA8Sul5x8QADXYQiBHDqSiSY8VdsgXpaEI5ubli2cri9iFicyjbDssR4wOdfw5zdrlp/T9Nr/7d9OT2x/GnBNKo8nyeX9ARfvY/oZYipXdklTPn08gviIAyNN/wQ6q@WTL@@Pm/ahqmRQPba2x@2bSJ/bydZnr0gihT@iZscfeztB8wN8FchlVWnZEuITPuN200wyqn/qj8SfVQnL4D).

Thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen%20Kevin%20Cruijssen) for golfing 29 bytes.

Ungolfed version:

```java
n -> { // lambda taking an int as argument
    var c = new char[++n][n]; // the output; increment the virality since the root does not count
    for(var d : c) // for every line
        java.util.Arrays.fill(d,' '); // initialize it with spaces
    for(int i = 0, j = 0, // coordinates of the first branch
            k = 0, l = 0, // coordinates of the second branch
            r = 0, s = 0, // offsets for the first branch, one will be 0 and the other 1 always except for the first '*' where the two branches overlap
            t = 0, u = 0; // offsets for the second branch, one will be 0 and the other 1 always except for the first '*' where the two branches overlap
        n-- > 0; ) { // decrement virality and repeat as many times
        c[i+=r][j+=s] = c[k+=t][l+=u] = 42; // move according to offsets and place an '*' for each branch, 42 is ASCII code
        do { // randomly pick offsets for both branches
            r = t = 2; // Math.random() provides results in [0,1)
            r *= Math.random(); // flip a coin for the first branch
            t *= Math.random(); // flip another coin for the second
            s = r^1; // set s to 0 if r=1, to 1 if r=0
            u = t^1; // set u to 0 if t=1, to 1 if t=0
        } while(i+r==k+t&j+s==l+u); // repeat if the branches overlap
    }
    return c; // return the output
}
```

Comment: [239 bytes](https://tinyurl.com/y6vutzzv) (I've only changed the things inside the `do{}` a bit (and placed the ints in the first part of the for-loop). PS: In your initial answer the `0.5` could have been golfed to `.5` as well.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen looks like I need to work on my math. thanks :-)

Comment: [237 bytes](https://tio.run/##nVLBbhshED3jr@BUQ4hXaze9dEOkHHvIpZF62VKJsmsbjHE0sNtGkb/dHXYTp03dRsphNGjmzePxGKd7PXPN5nDXfffWUON1jPRG20AfJsSG1MJSm5Z@saB9LhGz1lCrWtE@lxhCaODVhOwn5JEjJp0w9Tvb0C0ysdsENqxwRMMq8oFl5BsoqKSHMLt66DVQI0P7gw5XCBFUHVS13AHLreaj4Q7VFl2yvrgG0PexWFrvWXM@pVM@ALMaK8tzh7HB8BiAETESRifLKsxmV2XFM9zUVkhQtRMyKmnqjZBJ1V7ITsmLBU4muaisYHAmb3RaF6BDs9syzqXcCJZeVt85waKEb3Pse8E6mfBY8ZEG2tRBoKbaHwhBv8gdmpLYYEExejnn2Uhyex9Tuy12XSoGjA9s@jVM@emhxVuG3r8@9Oz15@F9FPCj8u@8bLABfnQfUWWF6ZLOcxZi/PATIqAI7c/0CasfSi4eH/9fTftxzcD2OrV/7NnIftxNM156QpQpfBtWaf27tCeYG2Euw2qrjkiHyIz7S1teINwe9U/lz6r35PAL)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>31</s> 24 bytes

```
Ｆ²«Ｊ⁰¦⁰Ｆ⊕θ«¿ι*↓*≔‽²ι¿ＫＫ↗
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY2xDoIwFEVn@hUvTK8GE3SEycRFExNC9ANIeUBjabFUHAzfXkvjes7NuWJorDCN8r4zFvDI4cuS63uc7gbzDHJesiSaixaWRtKOWnzxOEtkByg5VFZqh@ku5SWQmukPirP56AwiD@PTPMteY93o1ozhKAMZ@RapiJ4YojezEBaPqZb94Da7stX7Q@73i/oB) Link is to verbose version of code. Originally I thought it would be easier to make the first step random but it turned out to be golfier to make the first branch predictable. Explanation:

```
Ｆ²«
```

Loop twice, using index variable `i`. (This actually iterates over an implicit list, so it's safe to mutate `i` inside the loop.)

```
Ｊ⁰¦⁰
```

Jump to the origin of the canvas.

```
Ｆ⊕θ«
```

Loop `N+1` times.

```
¿ι*↓*
```

Print a `*`, but leave the cursor either to the right or below the cursor depending on the value of `i`.

```
‽²ι
```

Randomise the value of `i` for the next iteration of the inner loop.

```
¿ＫＫ↗
```

If the current character is a `*`, this means that we're the second branch and we went down instead of right, so move up right to correct that.
 (The first branch always starts downwards so the second branch will always be above it, meaning that we only need to check for a vertical collision.)

Comment: It's almost correct, however it prints not `N`-sized branches, but `N-1` sized :)

Comment: @nicael Sorry, fixed.

Comment: You've probably already seen this too many times, but: [23 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY2xDoIwFEXn9itemF4JJuiIk4mLJiaE6AcQeEBjabFFHAzfXkvjeu7Juc1Q28bUyvvOWMCDgC9n1/c43Q3mGSR5Io6cxe2iG0sj6ZlafIkoMtkBSgGllXrGJA0ykHL0B8XZfHSIpDHCTs7JXmNV69aM4SoDGfkWKYmeGKI3sxAWj6mS/TBv68pX7/e53y3qBw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>208</s> <s>124</s> <s>122</s> 118 bytes

118 bytes without newlines, indentation and comments. Takes *N* from stdin:

```perl
@b=1..2;                            #number of branches is 2
for(1..<>){                         #add length <> (the input) to each branch
  ($x,$y)=@$_                       #get where current branch has its tip now
 ,.5>rand?$x++:$y++                 #increase either x or y
 ,$o[$y][$x]++&&redo                #try again if that place is already occupied
 ,$_=[$x,$y]                        #register new tip of current branch
   for@b                            #...and do all that for each branch 
}
say map$_||!$i++?'*':$",@$_ for@o;  #output the branches
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzdCoIwGEBfxerDn74xUpTANd17jCGKBkE12Sgc2bOv2d25OOfMk7lX/mWn6F3R/MQO1vTPMT1nzIuB55QW7KpNGuDSZJ8UFgIu4wI6QqtmU1tYEGtwiAS0BKckLAoxjs00agIdl/9GhYsYvrZ30aOfoVvXHdwQ2@SY1LAnYRhthmbel@UP)

Comment: Nice, but it prints the branches 1 asterisk shorter than they should be :)

Comment: Please see the examples in my questions again :)

Comment: Oh, I've changed `2..$N` to `1..shift` now and also shaved off a few bytes.

Comment: Now everything seems to be ok!

Comment: Good answer! You can save a few bytes using `<>` and input instead of `shift` and arguments as well as re-orderinf you call to `rand` to avoid the parens. You shouldn't need to wrap your assignment to `@o` either. I tried using `@b=([],[]);` which appears to work, but I didn't experiment too much so I might've missed an edge case there. Hope they help a little!

Comment: Thx @DomHastings I got rid of 2 bytes with your `rand` tip. Also your tip on `<>` worked for me locally, but I couldn't figure out how to get it working in TIO so I kept `shift` for now. I found out for myself before: using `@b=1..2` and getting rid of `@o=...`.

Comment: Yeah, I spotted you'd updated it once I'd added my comments! If using `<>` on TIO you need to use input field instead of arts. I've also replaced `' '` with `$"` for another cheeky byte off! [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzdCoIwGEBfxerDn74xUpTANd17jCGKBkE12Sgc2bOv2d25OOfMk7lX/mWn6F3R/MQO1vTPMT1nzIuB55QW7KpNGuDSZJ8UFgIu4wI6QqtmU1tYEGtwiAS0BKckLAoxjs00agIdl/9GhYsYvrZ30aOfoVvXHdwQ2@SY1LAnYRhthmbel@UP "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: I figured out TIO: needed to click remove on the arg even though it was empty. So now both your `<>` and `$"` tips are added. Still got something to learn in Perl5, and Perl6 is an even bigger bag of tricks I haven't dared to thread too far into yet.

Comment: The [tips for golfing in Perl page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5105/9365) has some good advice, be sure to check it out! Good luck and have fun!

Comment: A couple more tips: you can safely omit the final `;`, and using `map` instead of your first `for` would save another byte.[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcztCoIwFIDhW1l18KMzRoojcE13HyIycUFQTSaFI7v2pf1/32c07s7DazLkzVl2EofJ6eeQnFMRVC8zxnLx0OMngZmCT6WCjjJebU0NM2IJHpGCbcC3DcwtYhQ5M1gKnWz@T3u1TvXfVbpUYtKerBx0y7KDG2IdH@MS9nRlydbZEIriBw "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 204 bytes

```python
from random import*
N=input()
s=eval(`[[' ']*-~N]*-~N`)
s[0][0]='*'
I=x,y=1,0
J=X,Y=0,1
exec"s[y][x]=s[Y][X]='*';i,j,k,l=choice((J+I,I+I,I+J,J+J)[x-2<X:]);x+=i;y+=j;X+=k;Y+=l;"*N
for i in s:print`i`[2::5]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYrLDoIwFET3/YrGDY9eEyRxQ70fQBesIU0TDGK8ii0paMrGX0dCMnNmcWZc5oez@brevXtzf7W3beg9Oj@nrEKy42eOEzZh/70Ocat1xCOTHn/VjnYzOjNbMEojVmKABU@QMYU1NJjBifWh7w6TXowOBifdGF3vZ0nwhBcM2D0cdX0cK1FCuVeBEirR4Zhf6sIkMggkuQh8ylrgSzYCB3lIK3Z3nhMny6di9GTnllqdF8XZrOv5Dw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-a`, <s>97</s> <s>96</s> <s>93</s> 92 bytes

Has no right, down or off diagonal bias.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -a
@;=[1];map{$x=$y=0;map++(.5<rand?$x:$y)*$;[$y][$x]++&&redo,1.."@F"}1,2;say+($","*")[@$_]for@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcbRCsIgFADQf7lcxjadaOFLJvnUW18gEsIWBDXF9aBEv96NztPJS3loImesV8E8Y35jtdis/J@xXuhjiet8wnrANoxoPLbgsQbGuq4sc@JKCHBn@Ci@M1tsrEfgMMLgHV7DLRVHtJfflF/3tG40RZouWigp1A8)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 118 bytes

```php
for($r="*",$w=$argn+2;$argn--;$r[$q+=rand(0,$r[$q+1]<"*")?:$w]=$r)$r[$p+=rand(!$i++,1)?:$w]=$r;echo wordwrap($r,$w-1);
```

requires PHP 5.4 or later for the Elvis operator. Replace `?:` with `?1:` for older PHP.

Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/353a94382205848f7807035ce8ed711fdb5f105a).

Comment: How do I check with different input there?

Comment: @nicael: You can change the argument on the line `$argBak=$argn=`

Comment: Ok! Not sure whether this is a nice way or not to "accept" input this way, but let the community decide by voting

Comment: @nicael In the TiO, simply replace the value for `$argn`. In a real environment, `$argn` comes from STDIN if you run it as a pipe with `-R`. It will then execute the code for each line of input (but I am pretty certain PHP does not unset the variables inbetween; so explicit consecutive runs are more likely to avoid bad surprises.)

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <strike>195</strike> 190 bytes

```
func[n][g: func[s][i: 0 d: s while[i < n][b/(d): #"*"until[r: 1 if 1 = random 2[r: n + 1]b/(d + r) =#" "]d: d + r
i: i + 1]]b:""loop n[loop n[append b" "]append b"^/"]b/1: #"*"g n + 2 g 2 b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY29DoMwDIR3nuIUltIO/IxR@xJdo1SCJqGWwEQBxOPTEKoOts/W3edgzf60RukstGymsZytNeBpKxcabebk7lZ@K9aql0hy1ookKhiJGduHBqsId0RHV15MIZGLq1h5oUEFiRrkYnvgxKM5jowban3YowgFHrmA0BGY9iziKTl0J4UYpsmD1W@03ls26I7AX79KEWn1@bpP@AZ9rE7vPhAvcGiq/Qs)

### Readable:

```
f: func[n][
    g: func[s][
        i: 0
        d: s
        while[i < n][
            b/(d): #"*"
            until[
                r: 1 if 1 = random 2[r: n + 1]
                b/(d + r) = #" "
            ]
            d: d + r
            i: i + 1
        ]
    ]
    b: ""
    loop n[loop n[append b " "]append b "^/"]
    b/1: #"*"
    g n + 2
    g 2
    b
]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>50</s> <s>43</s> 41 bytes

```
2ḶẊ⁸Ð¡+\‘Ṗ
⁸ÇU;Ç¤⁻Q$¿
‘,þ`⁼€þÇS+»þ`Ị$ị⁾*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/o4Y5tD3d1PWrccXjCoYXaMY8aZjzcOY0LxG8PtT7cfmjJo8bdgSqH9nMBZXQO70t41LjnUdOaw/sOtwdrH9oNFHi4u0vl4e7uR437tBT@H26PBJppAAA)

This was a really fun one to write. There could be some much more optimal method. There is probably some golfing to do within this method as well.

Right after I posted this I realized I could use `` ,þ` `` instead of `` aþ,""oþ`Ɗ ``.

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>148</s> 142 bytes

```r
n=scan();`~`=sample;o=r=k=1;l=c(1,n);for(i in 1:n){r=r+l~1;t=l~1;k=k+"if"(k+t-r,t,l[l!=t]);o=c(o,r,k)};write(c(" ","*")[1:n^2%in%o+1],1,n,,"")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fc1BCsIwEEDRq9SBwowZFxHcGOYkpdISWgiJiUwDLsRePdbNX76vrWXZ/JyR3LRPss3PV1pcEZUo1iXxaDmTW4ti6ELu7D3TR0VN2q2r8m@UaCCsgNHUi3LlNKST1JEOxmNh5Uhf99ZQF/QIHTCcgYZDelz7kPti7MjHhRmA2q39AA)

Additionally, although it won't meet the output spec, you can distinguish the two branches: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FczLCsIwEEbhV6lZTegsjOCmw/8kpdASWgi5KNOAgthXj3ZzFmfxaWsFu18KWZmPGfuSn2mVjLxUDW8yneHCxUoe3YSrKCKcJHhy590eSqELpXNDsR@F9ulwUnE2IvYmbIZiXwHlNKYL6sT1xDwpRzvBDbevvDTUlTL/SWZjbLu3Hw)

Explanation:

Starting from index `1`, we randomly select a right or left move for branch `r` by adding `n` or `1`, respectively. Then we select another right or left move for branch `k`, and if it would intersect where `r` is going, we select the other direction. Then we use `r` and `k` as indices into `m`, setting those values as `"*"`. Iterating `n-1` times, we then print the result.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>39</s> 38 bytes

```
ḣ2+\€Ẏ
2Rd¤ṗẊÇ⁻Q$$¿Ç0,0ṭ‘Ṭ€×þ/$€Sị⁾* Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AVIArf9qZWxsef//4bijMitc4oKs4bqOCjJSZMKk4bmX4bqKw4figbtRJCTCv8OHMCww4bmt4oCY4bms4oKsw5fDvi8k4oKsU@G7i@KBviogWf///zEw)

Although seemingly unrelated, `d` is useful here to save a byte (over my previous approach).

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>191</s> <s>187</s> 176 bytes

```python
from random import*
n=input()
p,q=c=1,1j;s={p,q,0}
exec'z=choice(c);q,p=p+[z,1+1j-z][p+z in s],q;s|={q};'*2*~-n
R=range(n+1)
for y in R:print''.join(' *'[y+x*1jin s]for x in R)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc1LCoMwGATgfU6RXTSJpRG6acgl3IqLksYaoX8epuCj9upWXQ0DHzN@Sp2Dctva6N44PuC5h317FxNFoCz4T8py5HlQWgkuejmoZW/8uiIzGk1mpTtntcl0LgP3yrN65oKJvpib2rMZW8BDw4McvmoJqyS0pL8CUKX2s5fJgIkctS7i6ZDV3UcLiZBL7yxkBFNST2ykoj9nDjeeLt@22x8)

Python has native support for complex numbers of the form `a+bj`; this makes some 2-D problems a bit more tractable...