# Minecraft Language Files Updater

Tags: code-golf, game, json

In 1.13, Minecraft language files were switched from being a simple multi-line key=value format to [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

## Challenge

Write a program converting from the original format returning a JSON string. Input can be taken using any standard input method, output must be json from any standard output method

The original format contains lines with key=value pairs, for example

```
tile.dirt.name=Dirt
advMode.nearestPlayer=Use "@p" to target nearest player

build.tooHigh=Height limit for building is %s blocks
```

Should be converted to one large JSON object with key=value

```
{
    "tile.dirt.name": "Dirt",
    "advMode.nearestPlayer": "Use \"@p\" to target nearest player",
    "build.tooHigh": "Height limit for building is %s blocks"
}
```

### Some details

- Any valid JSON is allowed as long as it contains only the correct key/value pairs. Trailing commas are allowed because Minecraft allows them.
- The only things that must be escaped are quotes. (No newlines, backslashes, or other json-breaking things existed in the language file prior to 1.13)
- Empty lines should be ignored
- Lines contain exactly one equals

## Test Cases

Input:

```
tile.dirt.name=Dirt
advMode.nearestPlayer=Use "@p" to target nearest player

build.tooHigh=Height limit for building is %s blocks
```

Output:

```
{
    "tile.dirt.name": "Dirt",
    "advMode.nearestPlayer": "Use \"@p\" to target nearest player",
    "build.tooHigh": "Height limit for building is %s blocks"
}
```

Input:

```
translation.test.none=Hello, world!
translation.test.complex=Prefix, %s%2$s again %s and %1$s lastly %s and also %1$s again!
translation.test.escape=%%s %%%s %%%%s %%%%%s
translation.test.invalid=hi %
translation.test.invalid2=hi %  s
translation.test.args=%s %s
translation.test.world=world
```

Output:

```
{
  "translation.test.none": "Hello, world!",
  "translation.test.complex": "Prefix, %s%2$s again %s and %1$s lastly %s and also %1$s again!",
  "translation.test.escape": "%%s %%%s %%%%s %%%%%s",
  "translation.test.invalid": "hi %",
  "translation.test.invalid2": "hi %  s",
  "translation.test.args": "%s %s",
  "translation.test.world": "world",
}
```

Input:

```
stat.mineBlock=%1$s Mined
stat.craftItem=%1$s Crafted
stat.useItem=%1$s Used
stat.breakItem=%1$s Depleted
```

Output:

```
{
    "stat.mineBlock": "%1$s Mined",
    "stat.craftItem": "%1$s Crafted",
    "stat.useItem": "%1$s Used",
    "stat.breakItem": "%1$s Depleted"
}
```

Comment: How does `tile.dirt.name` become `"block.minecraft.dirt"`?

Comment: @Pavel uuh... whoops. Fixed that. That was unintentional

Comment: Is it guaranteed that each non-empty line contains exactly 1 `=`?

Comment: @user202729 yes

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that you actually need a solution to this problem and intend to use one to convert your files. :)

Comment: What if the input contains `\"`?

Comment: No, Minecraft automatically does that

Comment: I'd know, I'm an Ubernerd of the highest level.

Comment: @ppperry it doesn't contain backslashes

Comment: Do we only need to handle English json?

Comment: @l4m2 english only is fine

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, <s>91</s> 77 bytes

*-14 Bytes thanks to OMᗺ*

I thought that the printout of a Python dictionary would be close enough to JSON to make it a very competitive language for this challenge.  However, the string representation of python dictionaries is different enough from JSON that I had better luck using python's built-in JSON library. I'll bet this can be done more succinctly in JavaScript.

```python
import json
f=lambda x:json.dumps(dict(i.split("=")for i in x.split("\n")if i))
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##ZY8xawMxDIV3/wr1aOAOiiF0Kxg6ZEiHQpdObQdfrMup0dnGUtLcr786oZm6iKenpw8pzzqm@LjQlFNRkFlu8ltSNINjP/XBw/np0ttwnLK0gXbakpXMpG3jmm5IBQgowvlmfsamowGo65ZcKGo7tJVtfdmfPtZf1V2UGG2gojb6Cd2mKuPD6TUFtBF9QdE39jMW9y4IzXNuQBNoJaDCXwDyNWFMfyQOVlPa0n50W6xVgWkihctt1zHFPZDASqDntDuIMVp8FPZK9TOtOBtTxLrNnB7gJxUOd/8zFE@eKbiRYGWMqFfbF/SHF8XJrdb3AhvMjIrhFw)

---

Edit:

## Bash + Sed, <s>68</s> 63 bytes

*Bug fix thanks to OMᗺ and Night 2*
*-5 Bytes thanks to OMᗺ*

I realized that it might be more byte efficient to directly convert the text to JSON without bundling it in an object, as was my approach for the python solution.  Per byte, sed is the most powerful language for regex replacement that I know of.

```
echo {`echo "$1"|sed 's/"/\\\"/g;s/\(.*\)=\(.*\)/"\1":"\2",/'`}
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##LYq7CgIxEEX7/YphUHwgCVoqCxYWNoKNXQqzZtwNZjeSGQVRvz3KanPPhXMqy03OdGoiPI89cDDHF5ODEWvUxhjU9Yq1GaupmZQ/aDRzXKJZ4EyPju@cs/hAyvkkqrMtlZvvK6y776Ij1ZFNxLIP9kGpPDABrq8IEkFsqkngH8C1L4qiuvnglMS49XVTbum7AsG3XuAcE/TadzV4hiFDFeLpwh8)

### Explanation

```
echo {`                                  #  prints the leading curly brace
       echo "$1"|sed                     # feeds the input into sed
       's/"/\\"/g;                       # replaces " with \"
       s/\(.*\)=\(.*\)/"\1":"\2",/'      # surrounds the left and right hand sides of the equals with quotes and joins them with a colon
`}                                       # prints the closing curly brace
```

Comment: If you're answering in two different languages, feel free to post that as two separate answers.

Comment: For the bash+sed answer, try using the `-r` flag for sed (+3 bytes) so that you do not need to escape the capturing groups (-4 bytes) https://tio.run/##LYq7CgIxEEX7/YphUHygCVoqCxYWNoKNXQqzZtwNxo1kRkHUb4@62Jx74ZzKcpMzHZsIz0M32Jvhi8nBNMGANWpjDOp6yXqoxqPyB41mhgs0c5zoweGdcxYfSDmfRLX2QuX6@wrr7tvoSLVkE7Hsgn1QKvdMgKsrgkQQm2oS@Adw7YqiqG4@OCUxbnzdlBv6UiD4ixc4xQSd9m0NnqHPUIV4PPMH

Answer (score 4):

## Vim, 44 bytes

```
O{<Esc>:%s/"/\\"/g|%s/\v(.*)\=(.*)/"\1":"\2",
o}
```

Explanation:

```
O{<Esc>                                           Prepend {
       :%s/"/\\"/g                                Escape all "
                  |%s/\v(.*)\=(.*)/"\1":"\2",     Json-ify lines
o}                                                Append }
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 150 bytes

```rust
|s:String|s.replace('"',"\\\"").split('\n').filter(|l|l.len()>0).map(|l|format!("\"")+&l.replace('=',"\":\"")+"\",").fold(format!("{{"),|r,n|r+&n)+"}"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVDBSsQwEL3nK8YsbhO2BM8rFQ8e9iII4q0g2W1ag9OkTGYFafvtNS2icxiGmfcebx5dEy9tgN76oDSMAnKhY2ihgmVKx1cmH7opGXID2otThSxKWde1lNqkAT2rog6FNq1HdqQmnNCgy2IPd9r0dlg3baTe8o2SK@uwx3@xahWTx22fhzKLthEb9ccYR6nLicow0WEfMmiWy/3mcsjGGMOKmWXZKtpJwR6daTyxCbZ31VOehG2@nmPjTHCWXOIXtN@OqrfkQD4OEjgCW@ryy78AGDaEEOerx8ZwjCfffVQnlzsD@t7ndCLBds7ZgE9wm@CM8fKZhNxlxnvaUlNaazEvPw)

Is it longer than Java?

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 35 bytes

```
"
\"
=
": "
G`.
.+
    "$&",
^
{¶
$
¶}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYpBCsIwEADP7iuWUL0oeYAQ8CDYi@DFm4ipXetimpRkFUT8Vh/Qj8VSvAwDM5GEvc1ZwUmBAbVGBbuLBr2EmSoWagVn@Aw9FDD035yFHemao2hvWzLb0cDWr32oSXuykZIcnH1TNMdEqDadQgkoNjYk@B@wmw6A6smu1hJCyc3dlDRS0HHLgrcQccrsG@SE84SVC9dH@gE) Would be 34 bytes in Retina 1 as you can use `` L$`.+ `` instead of `` G`. `` and `.+`. Explanation:

```
"
\"
```

Escape the quotes.

```
=
": "
```

Fix up the key/value separator. (If the value might contain a `=`, use `` 1`= `` at a cost of 2 bytes.)

```
G`.
```

Remove empty lines.

```
.+
    "$&",
```

Wrap each line in quotes. (The inner quotes were added earlier.)

```
^
{¶
$
¶}
```

Wrap the entire output in `{}`s.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-nl -M5.010`, <s>58</s> 54 bytes

```perl
BEGIN{say'{'}s'"'\"'g;/=/&&say qq|"$`": "$'",|}{say'}'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcpBDwExEAXg@/6KSYNeKA4uZBMRggNxcXPQtWNNVLvaIRH2r6vNxuXl5b2vRG9GMc4Wy/X2HfRLvmUVpJAHIYtJP@13OvUI9/tHtI5iDKIlRfdTNbKSMTIZVDl5VlbfMJ3XLdH5c@NyVBa1x8A7o1/o031AENNSADtg7Qtk@AMoG5Ek2YNMrti5FRWXdIV1Mhi6EcPZeWhusgVQgHaAzLjTNXxdyeRsiL3NSA2Gg9iz5gc)

---

58 byte version:

```perl
BEGIN{say'{'}s'"'\"'g;s/(.*)=(.*)/"$1": "$2",/;END{say'}'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcpBa8JAEIbhe37FsFi2lbpRIRclUIpSezD00puXTTPGoWt22ZkWJOSvd9XQy8sH3xMwuiKl1@3be9WzveheD6yVPijdrjl/NNOn8p5cTRZqBWqyVM/5elttRjzoISUhh6ahKKazZyw3t5XZ5nfvGzQd2ogsH85eMJafjKBeggLxIDa2KPAPIIwiy@ofco0R73fUnsod3irg6EwCRx9hvKlrgRgeGGrnv775zwch33Ga7QszX8whzcIV)

Comment: Both versions add a comma after every key:value pair, which is technically not compliant JSON (the final comma before the closing `}` should be omitted and will fail most strict JSON validators). Here's a quick 58-byte rewrite which produces valid (if uglier for human readers) JSON:

    ``$c||='{';s'"'\"'g;/=/&&say qq|$c"$`":"$'"|;$c=','}{say'}'``

I expect you can find something a bit shorter/more elegant.

Comment: @mousetrapper That's a nice way to avoid the `BEGIN`. OP explicitly allows trailing commas though: "Trailing commas are allowed because Minecraft allows them.". Feel free to post that as a new answer, mentioning the difference.

Comment: Ah, yes, good point, missed that sentence in the original post. The default assignment only makes sense if you're trying to vary the first character, otherwise your `BEGIN` is still shorter in the case where you just want to emit the '{'. I like your `END`-avoiding technique. I knew that `-n` placed an  _effective_ `while(<>){}` loop around your code; I had no idea just how literal that was.

Comment: I was pretty surprised too, when I first found that out. It's one of those Perl features that straddles the line between a weird hack and a brilliant way to do TIMTOWDI. I had forgotten about it though, so credit for it in this instance goes to Dennis in the [Perl 5 golfing tips thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/32884/8774).

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 22 bytes

String manipulation is not really Husk's strength, but it did pretty well:

```
`J"{}"J',mȯJ':msx'=fI¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYoxCsIwFED3nuITkC6SAwgBB4daEFzcOpia3/bTpCnJryjimdw8gJO3iqW4PB68102xT@lcisdTlPnafV9lvnHxlqtm/3mnlASTRWkosBy0Q7WbLdPmevAG5YA6YOSj1XcM6hQRKrEdKwHsgXVokeG/wLg8WVZPZI1k7wtqO1XgTAZLjhgaH2DJNLRAEVYRausvfRQ/)

```
                      ¶  -- split on newlines
                    fI   -- filter by identity (ie. remove empty strings)
         m(        )     -- with each line
                x'=      -- | split on '='
              ms         -- | show each (ie. enclose in quotes and escape quotes)
           J':           -- | join with ':'
      J',                -- join these with ','
`J"{}"                   -- join the string "{}" with the result
```

Comment: Ironically, there is something called a "Husk" in Minecraft!

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>66</s> <s>63</s> 62 bytes

```
s=>JSON.stringify(o=/(.+)=(.+)/g,s.replace(o,(_,a,b)=>o[a]=b))
```

```js
f=
s=>JSON.stringify(o=/(.+)=(.+)/g,s.replace(o,(_,a,b)=>o[a]=b))

console.log(
  f(`tile.dirt.name=Dirt
advMode.nearestPlayer=Use "@p" to target nearest player

build.tooHigh=Height limit for building is %s blocks`)
)
```

*-3 bytes thanks to [@redundancy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/170296/minecraft-language-files-updater/170341?noredirect=1#comment411492_170341)*

*-1 byte thanks to [@l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/170296/minecraft-language-files-updater/170341?noredirect=1#comment421174_170341)*

Comment: [63 bytes on TIO](https://tio.run/##dVLBTt0wELznK7aIiERNjcrdT4hyACQKUtVTQWWTbILB8Ube5cFT1W9/dUIQB14vI3tmduxd@wHXKE10o34J3NK2s1uxq4sfV9@NaHShd92mYPvnbyUm0uixoeKwMJ9LO8FhXxW/K6zq0q74F97auiy3ChYE7AoaDsKejOe@6Aopq4ObcFBmmRZ36hLfuqgm4ED2NK0ybNeX6QomEEYSvfa4oWh/CsHe8bgHyqAYe1JYDDDOjiyrn5xvjTKfuf7enlFCBe8Gp9BxhFlOnYATyAVqz82j3C33iBjEozoORlOmCRwoRXjPFTxz9O2n7IOn4WH09GKvI3XupUqh@dG@APbownQChhbyr4nxKOo3bxR64Vd@du4IJmlwJJungnyBBXP56HZhjd619t5B/l/1aJYBdtSnYYqd8ndoc@t2xmVSoqhmcIFOpvnZuY/LtG2zWWkidnquNLwq36btm/Yk9K6k91zoOhI@vgun6XdRqpnO2/4D "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Comment: https://tio.run/##dVLBTt0wELznK7aIiESkRuXup6rlAJVokRAnQLBJNsHgeCPv8uB9/cMJQRx4vYzsmdmxd@1HXKM00Y36PXBL285uxa7@XP77a0SjC73rNgXbo8IclnaCo74SE2n02FDBVXFXYVWXdsXXeGvrstwqWBCwK2g4CHsynvuiK6SsDm7CQZllWtyrS3zropqAA9mTtMqwXZ@nG5hAGEn0wuOGor0Sgr2f4x4og2LsSWExwDg7sqx@dr41ynzq@gd7SgkVvBucQscRZjk1Ak4gF6g9N09yv9wjYhCP6jgYTZkmcKAU4T1X8MLRt9@yL56Gh9HTq72I1LnXKoXmx/sC2KML0wkYWsh/JMajqN98UOiF3/nZuSOYpMGRbJ4K8gUWzOWr24U1etfaBwf5f9XjWQbYUZ@GKXbK36HNrdsZl0mJoprBBfo1zc/OfZynbZvNShOx0zOl4V35PW0/tGehTyW950LXkfDpUzhJX4pSzXTe9g0

Comment: @l4m2 Stringified RegExp objects? Learned something new today 

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>75</s> 71 bytes

<sup>-4 bytes thanks to [Laikoni](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56433/laikoni) (using do-notation over list-comprehension)!</sup>

Works with multiple `=` on one line:

```hs
f s='{':do{(a,_:b)<-span(/='=')<$>lines s;show a++':':show b++","}++"}"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7BasMwEETv/opFpCjBqXt3o9JDDrkUcsm5rKONvUSWjHbbEkK@3RGml@HBPJgZUK4UwjxfQJy929an@xq332232b3KhHH95qyzm93qI3AkAXmXIf0B1rVtbbtwV9dmax4lH2YekSM44KiU8axwmZUDNZ6zNhFHcvtCFfrfr@SpiYSZRI8Bb5TdSQjM52RAEyjmnhT@BZgWo6q6Hw6@0ZQO3A/uQCUVAo9cllKGpebYlwcvAl1I56s8AQ)

### Explanation

The term `span(/='=')<$>lines s` splits the string on the first `=`, leaving us with `("<initial part>","=<remaining line>")`. Doing a pattern-match `(a,_:b)` ensures that the line was not empty and at the same time removes the leading `=`.

Now we only need to `show` both `a` and `b` (enclosing it in quotes and escaping quotes), do some formatting (`:` and `,` characters) and finally enclose it in `{}`.

Comment: 71 bytes using `do`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7BasMwEETv/opFpCjBqXt3o9JDDrkUcsm5rKONvUSWjHbbEkK@3RGml@HBPJgZUK4UwjxfQJy929an@xq332232b3KhHH95qyzm93qI3AkAXmXIf0B1rVtbbtwV9dmax4lH2YekSM44KiU8axwmZUDNZ6zNhFHcvtCFfrfr@SpiYSZRI8Bb5TdSQjM52RAEyjmnhT@BZgWo6q6Hw6@0ZQO3A/uQCUVAo9cllKGpebYlwcvAl1I56s8AQ "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 56 bytes

```ruby
->x{x.split(?\n).map{|i|i.split(?=)}.to_h.to_json}
```

+6 bytes for `-rjson` interpreter flag.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZFBTwIxEIXv@ytGY7OSQBM5U7lo4sl4V2NGtgslw3TtdHUJ8NvX3QInlstL@r03k8xrqL@3bVVHgZw9rMVzDjWTFYFgf2oXLOSJZgVGBAOzWf78@pRnMSALYXSedbQSNXu25sUS@TH8@UDFzWVm4TcV2ca8BVu6ZgxK1PROAJfouHsAcgHqoSOEEml7RkjijzwlBxZbWWBljeoG1ElOquQy7fgXyRVm5UBddafJBhiYx7AU0@8f8NLpJult1jWVlWDayWOza7RU5OL9/INHeoPVbu/27szM6KCj/1r10td9OP5J@d63/tm2k9DTfw)

Comment: @Piccolo did you pass the -rjson flag?

Comment: @pfg Wow, I really dropped the ball on that haha. I had not only forgotten to use `-rjson`, but also assumed without actually checking that the error was the same one that I had gotten earlier involving `to_h`

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>243</strike> 219 bytes

Thanks to ceilingcat for the suggestion.

I decided to use a state machine to handle the three cases (newline, key, value) and it turned out pretty well. Also, I got to <strike>ab</strike>use the fall-through feature of `switch` and the macro stringizing operator!

Although the challenge didn't require it, I also escaped the `\` character [per the JSON spec.](http://json.org/) If that character will never be in the input, then `&&c-92` can be removed for 5 more bytes.

```c
#define p(s)printf(#s,c)
#define a(i)case i:
c,s;f(){for(p({);(c=getchar())>0;)switch(s){a(0)if(c<11)break;s++,p(\42);a(1)c==61?s++,p(":"):p(%c);break;a(2)c-34&&c-92?c==10?p(\42\54),s=0:p(%c):p(\\%c);}s-2||p(\42);p(});}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDNbsIwDL7zFBksEIuCaMcmjS7juuMeoBcvTSFaSKO6AqbCs3ehHSfYxZa/v9hRs41SbTvKdWGcZl4Q@Mq4uhAjihQMrgQKAwpJM7MaqIjSQkBTlJXwooFUKLnRtdpiJQDeFynQwYQxZDUoFmAKod7iGL4qjd8pTaeRF9kygRRFDErKl3jdg8PVEFZecAVpr0WRgJo9LcdjNXtN1kEbL9adOXteQkRy0ctDzbKL7Uyz5HT6i/fiHJA2XMN2aJzYlyYH1rCwe8rObV2hI4u1Kd281lTPXem0/NDWlhE7lJXNHwY3GlXuvNVH@VmFfzlGjBNPHonhJjwQBoYuZzwOiEWq7c8VQktlj3fKO8GaFHoth5zTkPFQswm/tMllCP3WYdwercnl1jD@L5t0NGN3/FhtSIb97mV358uu/gI)

---

### Original submission: 243 bytes

The original submission kept unneeded spacing as in the provided JSON examples.

```c
#define p(s)printf(s,c)
#define a(i)case i:
c,s;f(){for(p("{\n");(c=getchar())>0;)switch(s){a(0)if(c<11)break;s++,p("  \"");a(1)c==61?s++,p("\": \""):p("%c");break;a(2)c-34&&c-39?c==10?p("\",\n"),s=0:p("%c"):p("\\%c");}s==2&&p("\"\n");p("}");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDNcsIgEL77FDQtGRijk6SdztSUeu2xD5DLlpDIFCHDZtROxmdPEfWkvXyw38@yi1x0Uk7TY6NabRXpGfLeazu0DDPJZ1cemOYSUBG9mskMq5bxsXWe9SwZa5vwiknRqUFuwDPOP/KK416HMrQbgeVct0y@FwX/9gp@KpzPs5AkpE5CFFjBpRCvxfrC18kqKqtwpzI4zilgJZeL55c0Dfi2DpEiX0d7dhohQ5FfE6ezrmP2iEKUaRp9cdJwO574KWxJtqAt2zndcDKSsFRFjtPgwaKBQTu7HBQOS@usEp/KGJeRvfOmeZjdeKTb9kYdxJcPH3bICEVaPiGBLjwQCgK2IbQIjAEczO@VAoPuzEfnncYKJfRK0BCgF7ggxVu3tjswuhEbTei/ahllQu7kwXcoTv3vaHF1EfEP)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 43 bytes

```
¶¶
¶
"
\"
=
": "
m`$|^
"
m`^
    
$
¶}
^
{¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU9LCsJADN3nFLF0diLYpTB7lx5AiqEddSCdKZPBD@q1eoBerI5VV9YQXsj7BBJMtI6Goe/6DlJnsM1AQ7bCDJpdfi/hNUvAVJAnxwNKuPXdMMRATpii9W4RjcSF887otWH2czz7wPUMfjyVb1o2F70JZm8vc1SiilyQDmRdWpBcjWqZGCaJfP1SxOLf/OicOGykotZolQLqAx9U8uu27kRsa320qP6qxSgjTuQpHES/7k9o4@t6xCc)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 66 bytes

```js
s=>`{${s.replace(/"/g,'\\"').replace(/(.*)=(.*)/g,'"$1":"$2",')}}`
```

Assumes there's only one `=` per line

### Testing snippet

```js
f=s=>`{${s.replace(/"/g,'\\"').replace(/(.*)=(.*)/g,'"$1":"$2",')}}`
```

```html
<textarea id="i" onkeyup="o.innerText=f(i.value)"></textarea><pre id="o">
```

Comment: Should be 66 bytes. \\ might've been parsed as \ when counting length.

Comment: @redundancy I really should stop using `"code".length` in the javascript console to count the length

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 48 bytes

```perl6
{to-json %(.lines.grep(?*)>>.split("=",2).flat)}
```

*2 bytes less if we can assume exactly 1 equals sign on a non-empty line.*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVLBTtwwEL3nK4aoQbvV1oggcSgyrVpWogckLpW4ziaTMMWxU89AWVX9KT6BH9s62V0hsYvwYWTPe@N5fp6eojtddUs4bMDC6q@GT78keCgmxrEnMW2kfvLl4/T83EjvWCe5zWfl1DQOdfpvdZZlgktoJr8/azia3xwfTc8yZUem5qjGY0f2Iu0yrB@uQk3GE0YSvXa4pGh/CkH@tc9BAyjGlhQ2BOhHRpYt7tnVRkO45PbWXlKKCo47VmhChBFm3wILFAILF6o7yZKQtbDcblf@Wmo5So3oJT2Fgzea2hofPKUuzoUZ/AnR1Qe7nCp0vaNHex2p4cdZ6luUHwSwRfaDCPQ1FMcp41DULbcpdBLW@ZG552KSCnuyRSooNmETC9lls39Ax7W9ZSjeRMsRBthTn/wWO9y/Bxufbse4C87ZixJ7O08z01XPT8nv8l2/Twa/RVFNlybr2/BRdnTjKh3rNVJFbPSHUrdGvg/HLXYv9IKkwdmkF5Hw7gW4oPQ1Q01quPoP)

Ungolfed:

```perl6
{                   # An anonymous block, taking 1 string which ends in $_.
    to-json         # Convert a Perl 6 number, string, list or hash to JSON and return it.
    %(              # Force to hash (dictionary)
        .lines      # Break $_ (implicitly assumed) into a list of lines.
        .grep(?*)   # Pick only those that are True (non-empty).
        >>.         # For each element in the list, call the following method ... 
        split("=",2) # ... split the string at =, making at most 2 chunks.
        .flat       # That gives a list of 2-element lists. Flatten it.
    )               # List is converted into the hash like this: { first element => second element, third => fourth, ... }
}                   # Implicitly return
```

By the way, the `to-json` routine is deprecated, as the compiler will tell you, but who cares.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 81 bytes

```python
lambda s:'{'+re.sub(r'(.*)=(.*)',r'"\1":"\2",',re.sub('"',r'\"',s))+'}'
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY6xagMxEER7fcWyYHQXG0FcGgQpUrgxBEy6a3TR@iyik8RqHTAh337ROWkeM8wrptzlmtN@udhhiW4evYN60N96y2TqbexYd@aptyv0jjUOz3jAYY@71v4MjeswNNa@3@ofrcJcMgswLWeLiEpCJOMDi0luJvvaknL@65Q9mUSOqcpbdHdi@14J8KUgSAZxPJHAvwDlYSg13kL0RnI@hulqj9QoEMMcBC6Z4TGHNEGosKkwxvzxWdX6QhUOqUnduV9@AQ)

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 59 + 5 = 64

Needs `-rjson` (+5)

```
->c{Hash[*c.split(?\n).map{|l|l.split ?=}.flatten].to_json}
```

Explanation:

```
->c{                                                      } # anonymous function with param c
    Hash[*                                       ]          # converts ["a", "b", "c", "d"] into {"a": "b", "c": "d"}
          c.split(?\n)                                      # splits c into lines
                      .map{|l|          }                   # map lines so each element represents
                              l.split ?=                    # an array of itself but split by =
                                         .flatten           # merges 2d array to 1d (also gets rid of empty elements for newlines
                                                  .to_json  # converts hash to json
```

Answer (score 1):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 30 bytes

```
O{␛Í"/\\"
ggòeÉ"vyf=Plp$pa,òo}
```

Expects one input at a time. The TIO snippet runs all given test cases as a
single input.

I'm new to V's extended mappings, so tips are always welcome!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZGxbsIwEIZ3v0KXa0Q2lKrslqqWgQ6oLN1YDnwJFo6d2kcKqvoAHfoyvEIeLHVCEAPUw8l333@/fOe6bd@@7prf5GG5TERRNEdqfpL6kMuFqUYVjpuj@25b1oYypT1nFkuS03gTqOq5U5RZQk@BFwYP5OV7IEieqgTYAaMviGEQQNUrhFjttFEZOzfTxUbOKEYGo0vNkDsPPda2AB0gDbAybr0NQgj2aINB1s5mHP0y6yzFdmPcGD6dN@r@WrN2ZWVoLxeecr0fR8N0MgqABWrbuaNVkD7GisHA5nAuoQnuVO@VN4wprLEimcaGdAhDTMO1WtsajVZyoyH9l056DHCjPy4yyM7/ButHl32MWwqMnJXa0nO3N9nPMI@pOpG1x5xfmcoTeenSM9sFupD4j0N55Qm3FzCluNCuR4iPnYsvkEl3/gA)

### Explanation

```
O{␛                  # insert { on a new line above
   Í                 # global substitution across all lines
    "/\\"            #   " => \"
gg                   # go to first line
  ò                  # recursively...
   e                 #   forward to end of word; if at end of line, applies to next word below
    É"               #   prepend " to first non-whitespace char
      vy             #   copy current character (i.e. ")
        f=Plp        #   paste " before and after the next =
             $pa,    #   paste " at end of line and append ,
                 ò   # ...end
                  o} # insert } on a new line below
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>172</s> 170 bytes

```c
#define p(s)printf(#s,c)
c,s;f(){for(p({);read(0,&c,1);)s-2?c>10|s&&(s||(s+=p(\42)),c==61?s++,p(":"):p(%c)):c-34&&c-92?c==10?s=!p(\42\54):p(%c):p(\\%c);s-2||p(\42);p(});}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU9BbsIwELzzChPqYAsHkZRWKpbLtcc@IBfLcaglY1veiFIR3p6a0J6Ay4x2dmd2VxU7pYZh1ujWOI0CARqicV1LZsAUnSgGvCX01PpIAjlRHrVsyIrlipWUUyiqrXovVz3kOYG@J7AQgdTrilKmhHgtt7BYsECyTUY3gWBF6UYVz@s8V8VbsgpRrrYgpqOnfln/DSWs68Q85ff9NZAHcqb8PKTj0F4aRw7eNBSdUDqPo/PQRenAys54t@w0dEvnnRYf2lrP0LePtplObmaU3werj@Izpv@PDGHA1RMguUsLUoGkaxAuk2IldPbnX5IW/FUfJ@8Ea1AyaJFhDBnCCes5vtD8UiS@dRh3kNY04ssg/LBbjW2E7vhl3IFI993LHt8XI/4C)

Based on @ErikF's implementation but without `switch/case`.

Slightly ungolfed version

```c
#define p(s)printf(#s,c)
c,s;
f(){
 for(p({);read(0,&c,1);)
  s-2?
   c>10|s&&(
    s||
     (s+=p(\42)),
    c==61?
     s++,
     p(":")
    :
     p(%c)
   )
  :
   c-34&&c-92?
    c==10?
     s=!p(\42\54)
    :
     p(%c)
   :
    p(\\%c);
 s-2||p(\42);
 p(});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## R, 118 bytes

```
function(s){cat(paste("{",gsub("(.*)=(.*)","\"\\1\":\"\\2\",",gsub("\"","\\\\\"",gsub("\n{2,}","\n",s)),perl=T),"}"))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY8xa8QwDIV3/wohOM4ubqA3lgY63HBLoUO7eXESJTX12cFSCiXkt6fJcVTDk/jeg4fK2sPL49pPqZWQk2Yzt1706FlI44x24KnRqKsHU@@CFh069@Twed8nt4F7xuFu7oP/KM0nu@w4oWVj7Egl1h/G4oLGLCtv3XCUEKnqQpEq@SvV5@1Svvt5yx1ViXwhlvfof6nUn0yAryOCZBBfBhK4B2C8JZRqphC7SnK@hOGrvtCmAjFcg0CfC9zskAYIDAeGJub2m49K9dvn6x8)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 119 bytes

```c
#define p(s)printf(#s,c)
s;f(c){for(p({);~(c=getchar())|s;)c<11?s=s&&!p(",�"):c-61?s++||p(\42),p(\\u%04x):p(":");p(});}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU/BbsIwDN2ZrzBlgVgUNBDagS7adcd9AJcoTUukkERxxpgo@/UudNoJdvGT33v2s9WiVarvJ7VujNMQOGGIxqWGT6hUOKKq4QrPjY888DNW31yJVie1l5EjdlShelmtXknQdDoOvCgfCtyqxXOm5vOuC3y3WWOZYffBnjYn3GbPtsAq8AtWlz4nwUEax4/e1AhnaDhWcOlTlI6sTMa7ZdKUls47Ld60tb6ETx9tPR7deJQ/BKtP4j3mZ04lMGLrRwLZ5oDcgHQ1sFVmrKRkv/4oacn/8oPzzmJNSgYtCsaoAJbrbsauMLs2GUe3I8YdpTW12Btg/6rrQQagW4eMLYl8ILujDf@Lof4A)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 87 bytes

```php
preg_match_all("/^(.*)=(.*)$/m",$argn,$m);echo json_encode(array_combine($m[1],$m[2]));
```

Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4d368a114db508924abbc9f55ebd43218311cba1).

Insert `\s` before `$/m` for Windows linebreaks; `\s*` if linebreaks are uncertain.
Insert `U` after `$/m` if values contain `=`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/), <s>142</s> <s>114</s> 108 bytes

```
f(s)=>"""{${s.replaceAll('"','\\"').replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'(.*)=(.*)'),(m)=>'"${m[1]}":"${m[2]}",')}}""";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVLBauMwED2vv2JqYiwvRtAcG7R0d1voHgJlYU9NDxNrnIjKkpGm2ZSQb8/KrguBZn14zMx788YaSWPg06kVsVLf8jw/zA5RBuotNvTdWlHmZV2uVnlZnVWX2PekxW/a3O97EUohv1ZqgLKqRZeMynx26J6un4/5zRjNU1SX1fGYJixOOwzAoOApZRkbS1KbwNJhR@ouRRnq3dJrko4wUORHi28U1J9IkN/2ObAHxrAhhkkA/ajI0rd@NVZL9v7BbLbqgRIyWNMZhtYHGGnjNmAiFBHW1jcvMRv@ox6RA7pokY13kpOzdN5RsrHW1/DXB6uvPmsa3/WW9uoxUGv2dTIu5qtZBNygccMYdBqK66FkMbJ9@6ihjX4iRu0Fb4oN9qSK1FFMMGERP6uN26E1Wm0NFP9l5yMNcKE/bTWqwf8CN55ejXi2sMjIsjOOfgyrVO@HWaZcv1NNwJZ/MXUT9XPIP8jXSGdUut@pvg6EL2fMXXp5NHQNE58XWbbzRkOXNiaqQ/aFZbrae2y2Quj0@PpgHIs2xVW1yI6nfw)

-28 bytes by getting rid of the json.encode function and using regular string building

-6 bytes by removing the 'new' keyword and a few spaces