# Convert JSON object of directories to list of paths

Tags: code-golf, json

### Task

The input consists of a JSON object, where every value is an object (eventually empty), representing a directory structure.  The output must be a list of the corresponding root-to-leaf paths.

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71479690/turn-dictionary-values-into-paths/71480973?noredirect=1#comment126341789_71480973) comment on StackOverflow.

#### Input specifications

- You can assume that that the input always contains a JSON object.
- The input can be a empty JSON object (`{}`); in this case the output must be a empty list.
- You can assume that the names/keys contain only printable ASCII characters, and they do not contain `\0`, `\`, `/`, `"`, `'`, nor `` ` ``.
- You can assume each JSON object does not contain duplicate names/keys.

#### Input format

The input can be:

- a string;
- a dictionary or an associative array in a language of your choice;
- a list or array of tuples, where each tuples contains the name/key and the value (which is itself a list of tuples).

#### Output specifications

- There is no need to escape any character.
- You can use as directory separator either `/` or `\`, but you cannot have a mixed use of both (e.g. `a/b/c` and `a\b\c` are both valid, but `a/b\c` and `a\b/c` are not).
- Each path *can* have a leading and/or trailing directory separator (e.g. `a/b`, `/a/b`, `a/b/`, and `/a/b/` are equally valid).
- If you output a newline-separated list, the output can have a trailing newline.
- <s>The paths must be in the same order of the input.</s>

### Test cases

Input 1:

```
{
    "animal": {
        "cat": {"Persian": {}, "British_Shorthair": {}},
        "dog": {"Pug": {}, "Pitbull": {}}
    },
    "vehicle": {
        "car": {"Mercedes": {}, "BMW": {}}
    }
}
```

Output 1:

```
animal/cat/Persian
animal/cat/British_Shorthair
animal/dog/Pug
animal/dog/Pitbull
vehicle/car/Mercedes
vehicle/car/BMW
```

Input 2

```
{
    "bin": {
        "ls": {}
    },
    "home": {},
    "usr": {
        "bin": {
            "ls": {}
        },
        "include": {
            "sys": {}
        },
        "share": {}
    }
}
```

Output 2:

```
/bin/ls
/home
/usr/bin/ls
/usr/include/sys
/usr/share
```

Sandbox: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24594/73593

Comment: Not sure why this has JSON in the title, but "The paths must be in the same order of the input." conflicts with "JSON" as the members of a JSON object are inherently unordered, as are dictionaries and associative arrays — at least in principle.

Answer (score 4):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), <s>42</s> 40 bytes (+11 penalty for "-r --stream" options)

```
select(.[1]=={})[0]|join("/")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY07D4MwDIR3fgXyBBL0sVZi6Y6E1KEDQlUaLGIUQCShC81vT0voS/Vkn@@7a0fnNErkJtqU@yrLZhuXu@reDtRHsIXYuTkInwOsp45JOITr7TXOzCJAgUoT65fdJiEcFRnS4nISgzKCkfIPm3zBemhWcGreUEHmOkm5Wr3zBcANBXGJ/9U@FXJUHGvUn@78/BsRWJcql6baKGTdAw)

The `--stream` option converts JSON to an alternate format where each leaf node is an element in a list.  Those entries are also lists, with two fields, the first of which is a list of the keys representing the path.  The second entry (for out test cases) is an empty dictionary.

So the code selects every list entry where the second entry is a an empty dictionary, them assembles the list of keys in the first entry into the output we want.

```
select(.[1]=={})[0]            - pick "leaf" node entries only (1st field only)
                   |join("/")  - join the list of string w/ a "/" separator
```

Comment: `select(.[1]=={})[0]` saves 2 bytes. And it seems like `select(.[1])[0]` works, as only leafs have 2 elements.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 55 bytes

*Thanks to @pxeger for suggesting to use `for(k in o)`*

Expects an object. Prints the results with a leading `/`.

```javascript
f=(o,p,q)=>{for(k in o)f(o[q=k],[p]+'/'+k);q||print(p)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY/Pb8IgFIDv/SsaLkJk8bps6Q67m5js4MGYBSmVtyJQoE0W7d/eKWyu1UROvB/f9977Yh3z3IENT93zMFQFNtTShhRvx8o4XOegc0MqbDZNUW/pxm7ns8VsXpPX5nSyDnTAlvRDhY9Zfn6IaTgwhV7yFMccZ@GSQCvhPDB9@fc0R@8OAnj5@SGNC5KBi4We/oOl2Sew3f9BKwi7VqnUGjt/AdQJCVyJ29HRipbCcVEKf529XI8VWU@ydAzJsustO9BTm0r8ZKw0B5GsKW69m0K3ljvTyBZroLlqS3EP@e8HlJfMidF655OGHw)

---

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 63 bytes

Expects an object. Prints the results with a leading `/`.

```javascript
f=(o,p)=>Object.keys(o).map(k=>f(o[k],[p]+'/'+k))+''||~print(p)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY89b4MwEEB3fgXygq3QdK0qkaF71EgdOkRRZcwRXzDYsg1S1NC/ThPcppBI9eT7eO/uDrzjTlg0/qF7GoYyozo1LFu95gcQflnB0VHNljU3tMpWJdXbapduzW6RPCaLirFFkpxOX8Zi46lhQ0k/o/j8CG@w5oo8xyEec4L7S4JswDrkzeXfpzF5sejRyY83qa2XHO1Y6NM/sND7ALb7X2iDPm@VCq1j5w9AOpAoFNyOHq1kDVZAAe46e/0@VUQ9i8ItLIqut@TYzG0q8LOxUtcQrCFunZ1Dt5Y708Q21rARqi3gHnLHfygnuYXJeueThm8)

Comment: The `~` isn't needed

Comment: 57 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY9NawMhEEDv/grxEiWW0FsppIfeA4EecgihGNeN0zUq6i6UZn/7NtE23U2gnpyP92bmQ3QiygA@PXRPw1AvqeOeLV9UJwwltQu0wWCxYzV122bHt343ny1m84bxR8JOJx/AJurZUNMvhM@PCAtHYcgzLnHOSZEuCbJWIYKwl3/PMXkNkCDq9zftQtICQi70/A@s3KGA7eEXWkPat8aU1tz5A5BOaZBG3Y7OVrJSQapKxevs1WasQD1D5RaG0PWWPdipzRR@Mla7oyrWErcxTKFby51pZMs1sNK0lbqH4uc/VNQiqNF655OGbw "JavaScript (V8) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 67 bytes

```perl
map/}/?/{/&&say($s)..$s=~s|[^/]+/$||:($s.=s/"//gr."/"),/{?}|".+?"/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY9Ba4MwFMfvfgp5SFmp5m2HXgpF2GE3obDDDmMbqQYTiFESLRTNPvqy1nSbtrCc8v7v/X4vaZiWa@cq2qDFFHtcLAw93kVmSUhktp9meH3HtxVGw7A5pWRrEBBLTQBhGWOf2gHIKgUsneuD8HSAKlFRCZvQ12OW0/YcwI5pI6g6320cwqMWrTD845nXuuVU6LFh4z@wqEsPduUPtBPtvpPSj46TFwAOjItcsuvVoxUypnNWMPO7O3uZKgIbBJcP7IWaK6SHZrt4XTGv8nVn9By6ttyYJraxJ1Quu4LdQub4D2U41WzyvMB@1U0ramVc8gTgkuywJg/3LlHyGw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 52 bytes

```
def f(d,s=""):[f(d[x],s+"/"+x)for x in d]or print(s)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3TVJS0xTSNFJ0im2VlDStooHM6IpYnWJtJX0l7QrNtPwihQqFzDyFlFggq6AoM69Eo1gTqvdkmkY1lwIQKCVl5ilZKUA4YIGcYhC_FixQqwNRlJGfmwoWhfJLi4tQNaGbgmESkmlgucy85JzSlFRMTcWVeHQVZyQWpSI5j6sW6iFYoAAA)

Takes input as a dictionary, and outputs to STDOUT.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
;”/;ⱮßW⁹?}ʋ/€Ẏ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of lists where each is a key-value pair where the key is a list of characters and the value is a, possibly empty, list of the same type* and yields a list of lists of characters - the paths.

* i.e. uses the option *a list or array of tuples, where each tuples contains the name/key and the value (which is itself a list of tuples)*.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/6UcNcfetHG9cdnh/@qHGnfe2pbv1HTWse7ur7f7g98v//6GilxLzM3MQcJR0FIDs5sQTCCEgtKs5MzANxYmOBhJJTUWZJZnFGfHBGflFJRmJmEUQKIpmSnw7VVpqO0BKQWZJUmpMDUwgRLEvNyEzOSYVZVwRh@KYWJaempBYj2ecbjtAYCwA)**

#### How?

```
;”/;ⱮßW⁹?}ʋ/€Ẏ - (recursive) Link: list, J
            €  - for each key-value pair in J:
           /   -   reduce by:
          ʋ    -     last four links as a dyad - f(Key, Value)
 ”/            -       '/' character
;              -       (Key) concatenate ('/')
         }     -     use right argument, Value with:
        ?      -       if...
       ⁹       -       ...condition: chain's right argument, Value
     ß         -       ...then: call this recursive Link with that (non-empty) Value
      W        -       ...else: wrap that (empty) Value in a list -> [[]]
    Ɱ          -     map across the recursive call result (or the [[]]) with:
   ;           -       concatenate
             Ẏ - tighten
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-M5.10.0 -n0175`, 36 bytes

```perl
pop@;;push@;,/\w+/g;$,="/";/{/&&say@
```

[Try it online!](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#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)

### Explanation

A different approach to the other Perl answer. This uses the `-0175` command line flag to split the input on `}`. For each closing curly brace, `@;` is `pop`ped removing any previous path keys that aren't needed. Next all the keys (`/\w+/g` - this might be too lenient?) are `push`ed onto `@;`. Finally `$,` (which is printed between records when a list - `@...` - is `print`ed) is set to `"/"` and if `{` exists in the input, `say` is used to output `@;` (with `$,` printed between each index).

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 96 bytes

```
+1`"([^"]+)":{("[^"]+":{(({)|(?<-4>})|[^{}])*(?(4)^)},)*"(?!\1/)
$&$1/
M!`"[^"]+":{}
%`^.|....$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY1Ba8MgGIbv/ot@pEPbriXQUxkL9B4o7LBD1yw2kfqBTUDNYBh/exa122Fe/Hy/533UwmLHp2md10DPFVzWDA6OQhzDRB0bafHyvH/1bDxXzl/YihZ0zyrmN2wFtFh85DtGsqcs35FyUf9VPVnW1Xbczicj0@SAd3jnat5Aw224TkIb5F1gN3DUaNHIzzfZays56hDPedvfIjvcEndCex2Uitv5@SUkNkoka@hAKXQjWmEe2vI9oZ44uGL4DJR5uGV/FwkbTOz@B7Br1NBGu/n@DY3kWiTpDw) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
+1`"([^"]+)":{("[^"]+":{(({)|(?<-4>})|[^{}])*(?(4)^)},)*"(?!\1/)
$&$1/
```

Replace each key in turn with its path.

```
M!`"[^"]+":{}
```

List the entries whose values are empty objects.

```
%`^.|....$
```

Keep just the keys.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>79</s> 73 bytes

```r
f=function(L)"if"(length(L),unlist(Map(paste0,names(L),"/",Map(f,L))),"")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY69CsMwDIT3PoYnCwztC2TpnECgQ8eiOnIscJxiy319N2l@tvt0d5xSra5xJVrhOeoWFDulA8VR/EKmxMBZdIcf/cEsdDMRJ8qrpa7KrHdnWoAFFdS2@acx8oRh0xZlEz2lzBg3AHNPLJz96@HnJB457QaYYR73RhmPdM/yLiEcGTBf8mwDHRt7u6NkaaB8jnTPswIXt3xdfw)

Takes input as a named R `list`, i.e., `list(name=value)`, and returns a `character` (string) vector of directories.

-3 bytes thanks to pajonk.

Comment: Why the `lapply`? :) [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY@9CsMwDIT3PoYnGwTtC2TpnECgQ8eiOnIscJTgn76@mzY/2530HcfFWl3jitjMs@gWpBGcKOnWGMVO6UAyZr9aKBI4Zd3hohdMmW4goK4KfgcHK29ATG2bP4XCE4ZNW8yb6CkmRtmMgXvkzMm/Hn6O2SPH/WFgmMc9UcaD7jm/SwgHY@BDnm2go2NPdxQtDZTOku55RszFrUPqFw "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @pajonk I was so incredibly proud I remembered to use `Map` instead of `mapply`, too...

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>103</s> 88 bytes

```powershell
function f($o,$p){($x=$o.keys|%{f $o.$_ $p/$_})
if(!$x){$p}}f($args|ConvertFrom-Json -a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVFNT8MwDL3nV4Qo0FXa4A7aBQQHpEmTQOI4Za3bRKRJlaT7UJffXrJkoG6TyCl@9nv2s1u9BWM5SDkrtIGBbuf9UHWqcEIrXE2ontI27yd0N6f6/hv29nDbVzj86QrT9oGufI5ENbmhu7ynrfeBwkxtDy9abcC4N6Ob2bsNWjOWDx4hRFvmuMVznPUIh0fWQpFHnIIISHuMfQT8NBVx3UBET3FnzTnpUuVKaaQWc0IVsivhmmT3/7AsZwZG4yGfPQVPjgtVj00xJRomz0csmDsCZBk2LphKdjB5NsIJy1cfXBvHmYjG/LhpqetE7Opf0lK4dSdlKj3b1Aa4KCRcto6qZAGmgBLsX@/F11giuSHL44UIuqNbnK4VMILIZzR5wpNjlDKvTev2KZH1PkNo@AE)

Takes a string as a parameter
Returns a list of string with a leading `/`

Thanks [mazzy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80745/mazzy) for shaving 15 bytes off!

Comment: nice! The cmdlet `ConvertFrom-Json' with the paramater `-asHashtable' will allow you to use `$o.Keys`  instead `Get-Members` and member names.

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVFNT8MwDL3nV4Qo0FXa4A7aBQQHpEmTQOI4Za3bRKRJlaT7UJffXrJkoG6TyCl@9nv2s1u9BWM5SDkrtIGBbuf9UHWqcEIrXE2ontI27yd0N6f6/hv29nDbVzj86QrT9oGufI5ENbmhu7ynrfeBwkxtDy9abcC4N6Ob2bsNWjOWDx4hRFvmuMVznPUIh0fWQpFHnIIISHuMfQT8NBVx3UBET3FnzTnpUuVKaaQWc0IVsivhmmT3/7AsZwZG4yGfPQVPjgtVj00xJRomz0csmDsCZBk2LphKdjB5NsIJy1cfXBvHmYjG/LhpqetE7Opf0lK4dSdlKj3b1Aa4KCRcto6qZAGmgBLsX@/F11giuSHL44UIuqNbnK4VMILIZzR5wpNjlDKvTev2KZH1PkNo@AE "PowerShell Core – Try It Online")?

Comment: I thought the `get-member` was the crux to make it shorter :) Nice one!

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin 1.6.21](https://kotlinlang.org/), 118 bytes

```
{fun f(m:Map<*,*>,s:(Any?)->Any){for((k,v)in m)if((v as Map<*,*>).size==0)s(k)else f(v){s("$k/$it")}};f(it,::println)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVNdT4MwFH3nVzTNHtqFqdsjCkbfF5cY46OprMANpZC2kEzCb5@FfYEytA8t7Tncc@5tb5obAXIflRJlDCShqHaQHRUTiGeF2XlozYqHJ7lzkZ0C5B@O7SGhZ2bGiqVF7PISke60HZhJyJjAyOQ/oQ4OmbmGdfiGKw1MdpxO1P3NeVZgQCcfr0muTMJAXdgDMh3@i7d5PK1dxpO6GzCfpRDX1JwRXVzxBELBJ@qhJj2tuQr5luvpgqzf/zblXObj9a1Gru8TZM8PFj3hflpJnvExS7jUV/P5Z@yOCjIU5bZfNqx3E3ydMMVHanDK2jnnHXuItK977qJ5QNEiQG8SDPL3ddsPEcm8AzoPXO0R@/wf6SKwC62jXBGSuhUF2zcUIkIqxDQ60emNhi/u@3dUk5RyobmNVtFaEzxLb2dgMG2a@4iAcT2vUCCNkLTZt76OO4JtLLT08MF1TNoWO3yfGMNdx18N@CvqNPtv)

An anonymous function of type `(Map<*, *>) -> Unit` that takes in a recursive map of `String` to `Map<String, ...>` and prints the answer without leading or trailing slashes.

**Ungolfed code:**

```
{
    // Define function f that iterates a map recursively and
    // outputs its keys' paths to a sink function
    fun f(m: Map<*, *>, s: (Any?) -> Any) {
        for ((k, v) in m)
            // Note: .size==0 is 2 bytes shorter than .isEmpty()
            if ((v as Map<*,*>).size == 0)
                // For an empty map, call the sink with the key
                s(k)
            else
                // Call f again on the inner map with a wrapped sink that
                // that appends the current key + "/" to the input
                f(v) { s("$k/$it") }
    }

    // Run f for the input map, using ::println as the sink
    f(it, ::println)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) [1.1.0-alpha](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip/commit/f9abeb2a7055e4140017d99dbfd01bc18be303d8) `-xp`, 23 bytes

```
@_.{a@1?'/.(\fa@1)x}MFa
```

Takes a list of tuples (i.e. two-element lists) as a command-line argument. Outputs a list of strings.

Pip 1.1 (required for both `\f` and `MF`) is not on Attempt This Online at the time of writing, but you can try it on [Replit](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/pip). The easiest way is to exit out of the Pip REPL with `;quit` and then:

```
> ./pip.py -xpe "@_.{a@1?'/.(\fa@1)x}MFa" '[["bin"; [["ls"; []]]]; ["home"; []]; ["usr"; [["bin"; [["ls"; []]]]; ["include"; [["sys"; []]]]; ["share"; []]]]]'
["bin/ls";"home";"usr/bin/ls";"usr/include/sys";"usr/share"]
```

#### Explanation

A recursive full program:

```
@_.{a@1?'/.(\fa@1)x}MFa
                      a  Program argument (a list of pairs)
                    MF   Map this function to each and flatten the results:
@_                         The first element of the pair
  .{               }       Concatenated (itemwise if necessary) to:
    a@1?                   Is the second element of the pair (a list) nonempty?
        '/.                If so, concatenate / (itemwise) to
           (\f   )         a recursive call of the main function
              a@1          with the second element of the pair as the argument
                  x        If it is empty, empty string
```

Answer (score 0):

## Bash (sed + [ShellShoccar-jpn/Parsrs parsrj.sh](https://github.com/ShellShoccar-jpn/Parsrs/blob/master/parsrj.sh)), <s>31</s> 29 bytes

Assumes parsrj.sh is on a directory specified by PATH environment variable.
Tested with parsrj.sh `Version : 2020-05-06 22:42:19 JST`.

```bash
parsrj.sh -rt -kd/|sed s,/$,,
```

### Example runs on my Termux

[image: ran with parsrj.sh and sed]

### Explained

```bash
parsrj.sh -rt -kd/|
# default output for {"foo":{"bar":{}},"baz":{}}:
#   $.foo.bar.
#   $.baz.
# -rt to replace $ with ""
# -kd/ to replace . with /
# thus output is:
#   /foo/bar/
#   /baz/
sed s,/$,,
# trailing slash is removed
```