# Build a file/directory tree

Tags: code-golf, string, tree-traversal

### Task

In this challenge, your task is to write a program or function which takes an array of paths with an additional boolean indicating it is a file or directory and outputs a file/directory tree in **any** reasonable format.

### Remarks

- Some directories can end with a forward slash (**"/"**) but this is not always the case
- A parent directory is not always explicitly defined but should be in the tree
- **"."** and **".."** as file name or directory name are not allowed
- Standard loopholes are not allowed

### Input

An unsorted array of paths. Each item is a tuple of path and a boolean which is True for a file and False for a directory.

```
[
    ['Root Folder/Sub Folder/', False],
    ['Root Folder/Sub Folder/hello.txt', True],
    ['Root Folder/Sub Folder/SubSub Folder/SubSubSub Folder/', False],
    ['Root Folder/Sub Folder/world.txt', True],
    ['Root Folder/Sub Folder 2', False],
]
```

### Output

#### Text formatted example

```
[D] Root Folder
    [D] Sub Folder
        [D] SubSub Folder
            [D] SubSubSub Folder
        [F] hello.txt
        [F] world.txt
    [D] Sub Folder 2
```

#### Data structure formatted example

```
[
    'Root Folder',
    [
        [
            'Sub Folder',
            [
                [
                    'SubSub Folder',
                    [
                        [
                            'SubSubSub Folder', [], []
                        ]
                    ],
                    []
                ]
            ],
            ['hello.txt', 'world.txt']
        ],
        [
            'Sub Folder 2',
            [],
            []
        ]
    ],
    []
]
```

This is a code golf. Shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/246845).

Comment: What does “can but should not” mean

Comment: @tsh i rephrased that remark. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: The distinction between files and directories, as well as the backslash rule, seem needlessly complex

Comment: @mousetail i agree that the backslash rule makes it more complex. And is even disallowed on many file systems. Thus i dropped the requirement!

However the distinction between files an directories still stands.. IMO there is a 'reason' for this distinction..

Comment: May I assume the path don't contain `/../` or `/./` in it?

Comment: What is expected output? Should I output exactly match the given ascii art? Or which part is necessary?

Comment: I suggest using our [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=active) in the future, so the issues like in the above comments are resolved there.

Comment: @tsh . and .. are not allowed names. Output is in any reasonable format..